# Draw an hourglass

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

Again inspired by a task for Programming 101 here's another challenge.

**Input:**

- A positive integer `n >= 3`. (has to be odd)

**Output:**

- `n` lines of asterisks, where the first line has `n` asterisks and every new line has two asterisks less than the line before. Until hitting 1 asterisk. From there every new line has two asterisks more than the line before until getting back to `n` asterisks. Spaces or something like spaces have to used to align the asterisks so that it really will look like an hourglass.

**General rules:**

- Trailing newlines are allowed but do not have to be used.
- indentation is a must.
- This is code-golf, so shortest answer in bytes wins.
- Since the course is taught in C++, I'm eager to see solutions in C++.

**Test case (n=5):**

```
*****
 ***
  *
 ***
*****
```

Comment: I don't see how this is the duplicate of "Draw an asterisk triangle". This has indentation and a down-up sequence where the triangle is only upwards.

Comment: @KarlNapf: Before the last edit you had the option of printing it without indentation meaning it was just a triangle from the other question printed as in that question and once in reverse.

Comment: @Emigna Yes i know, already answered like that. But now it isnt anymore, so it should be open again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Draw an asterisk triangle](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/95780/draw-an-asterisk-triangle)

Comment: @Oliver Considering OP *wrote* "Draw an asterisk triangle", I'm not entirely sure that calling this challenge a duplicate is fair. It is definitely related, though.

Comment: Can we assume the input is always `>=3` and always odd?

Comment: Since not everyone here knows the full context, OP originally posted the "Draw an asterisk triangle" and edited this challenge in as an additional challenge. We told them to remove that part and make it a different challenge (which they did). This challenge is *not* a duplicate. OP is doing what *many* high rep users, and even a few mods have recommended.

Comment: @closevoters could you remove your dupe votes? This question is no longer a duplicate of that question

Comment: Is it necessary to have enough trailing spaces to make the output square, or is "*****\n ***\n  *\n ***\n*****" acceptable output? (With two spaces before the single asterisk, which SO edits to a single space!)

Comment: @JDL: As outlined in the rules, it has to be "square" (i.e. has to use indentation).

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ: yes, you don't have to check the input as this would lengthen the code unnecessarily.

Comment: @Sickboy I get that the stars have to align, but do we need any spaces to the *right* of the stars?

Comment: @JDL: No, why would you? Ah, now I understand what you meant by square... :-D

Answer (score 24):

### [Charcoal](http://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 6 bytes

```
Ｇ↘←↗Ｎ*
```

Dead simple. Draw a poly**G**on of `*`, with side length taken from an input **N**umber, where the sides go down-and-right, horizontally left, and up-and-right:

```
*   *
 * *
  *
 * *
*****
```

Then autocomplete the outline and fill it.

```
*****
 ***
  *
 ***
*****
```

[Try it online!](http://charcoal.tryitonline.net/#code=77yn4oaY4oaQ4oaX77yuKg&input=NQ)

Comment: Hah, that's pretty bonkers!

Comment: This language is very interesting! I'll be watching this very closely from now on :p.

Comment: Haven't seen this language before... Looks interesting! I wonder what you'd get if you combined it with Jelly somehow...

Answer (score 14):

### Python 2, 57 bytes

```python
N=n=input()
exec"print('*'*max(n,2-n)).center(N);n-=2;"*n
```

A full program. Goes line by line, printing the right number of asterisks centered.

A recursive function was longer (67 bytes):

```python
f=lambda n,p='':p+n*'*'+'\n'+(1%n*' 'and f(n-2,p+' ')+p+n*'*'+'\n')
```

or

```python
f=lambda n,p='':1/n*(p+'*\n')or f(n-2,p+' ').join([p+n*'*'+'\n']*2)
```

Comment: I wanted to suggest trying to replace the `max` with an `abs`,  but all I got is `abs(n-1)+1`, which is worse because the addition requires parenthesis

Comment: @njzk2 You can cut the parens by doing `'*'*-~abs(n-1)`, but then it's the same length as `'*'*max(n,2-n)`.

Comment: There's `def f(n,s=''):r=s+'*'*n+'\n';return 1/n*r or r+f(n-2,s+' ')+r` for 61 bytes, but it's still longer. Even with a leading newline, `def f(n,s='\n'):r=s+'*'*n;return 1/n*r or r+f(n-2,s+' ')+r` is still 58 bytes...

Comment: +1 for teaching me about `center`. Never knew that existed till now.

Answer (score 13):

## C++ Metatemplates, 186 bytes

With the explicit formula from [my C answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/97401/53667) the Metatemplates are competing!

```c++
template<int N,int X=N*N+N-1>struct H{enum{I=X/(N+1)-N/2,J=X%(N+1)-N/2-1};S s{(J==-N/2-1?'\n':((I>=J&I>=-J)|(I<=J&I<=-J)?'*':' '))+H<N,X-1>().s};};template<int N>struct H<N,-1>{S s="";};
```

Ungolfed:

```c++
using S=std::string;

template <int N, int X=N*N+N-1>
struct H{
 enum{I=X/(N+1)-N/2,J=X%(N+1)-N/2-1};
 S s{(J==-N/2-1 ? '\n' : ( (I>=J&I>=-J)|(I<=J&I<=-J) ?'*':' '))+H<N,X-1>().s};
};

template <int N> struct H<N,-1> {S s="";};
```

usage:

```c++
std::cout << H<5>().s;
```

#### non-competing

Just for the sake of fun:

```c++
//T: Tuple of chars
template <char C, char...Tail> struct T { S r=S(1,C)+T<Tail...>().r; };

//specialization for single char
template <char C> struct T<C> { S r=S(1,C); };

//M: Repeated char
template <int N, char C> struct M { S r=S(N,C); };

//U: concatenates T and M
template <class Head, class...Tail> struct U { S r=Head().r+U<Tail...>().r; };

//specialization for Tail=M
template <int N, char C> struct U<M<N,C>> { S r{M<N,C>().r}; };

//specialization for Tail=T
template <char...C> struct U<T<C...>> { S r=T<C...>().r; };

//finally the Hourglass
template <int N, int I=0> struct H {
 S s=U<
       M<I,' '>,
       M<N,'*'>,
       T<'\n'>
      >().r;
 S r{s + H<N-2,I+1>().r + s};
};

//specialization for recursion end
template <int I> struct H<1,I> {
 S r=U<
       M<I,' '>,
       T<'*','\n'>
      >().r;
};
```

Usage:

```c++
std::cout << H<5>().r;
```

Comment: +1 for beating PHP with the most long-winded part of C++

Answer (score 11):

## [V](http://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 12 bytes

```
Àé*hòl3Äjxx>
```

[Try it online!](http://v.tryitonline.net/#code=w4DDqSpow7JsM8OEanh4Pg&input=&args=NQ)

I like challenges like this because I get to show off the advantages of V's 2D nature. Explanation. First, we need to create a string of *n* asterisks. So, we do this:

```
À           " Arg1 times:
 é          " Insert the following single character:
  *         " '*'
```

As a side note, this is directly equivalent to `@ai*<esc>` in vim, and register `@a` is pre-initialized to "arg1". This makes numeric input much more convenient.

Then, we move on character to the right with `h`. Here is the fun part:

```
ò           " Until an error is thrown:
 l          "   Move one character to the right. This will throw an error on anyline with only one asterisk in it
  3Ä        "   Make 3 copies of this line
    j       "   Move down one line
     xx     "   Delete two characters
       >    "   Indent this line once.
```

Now technically, this last part is

```
òl3Äjxx>>ò
```

Because the indent command is actually `>>`. V conveniently assumes incomplete commands apply to the current line, and also implicitly fills in the second `ò` character for looping.

Answer (score 8):

## Python, 78 bytes

So only with indentation:

```python
f=lambda n,i=0:n>1and' '*i+'*'*n+'\n'+f(n-2,i+1)+' '*i+'*'*n+'\n'or' '*i+'*\n'
```

Usage:

```python
print f(5)
```

Answer (score 7):

### PowerShell v2+, 54 bytes

```
param($n)$n..1+2..$n|?{$_%2}|%{" "*(($n-$_)/2)+"*"*$_}
```

Takes input `$n` (guaranteed to be an odd integer), constructs two ranges with `$n..1` and `2..$n` and concatenates them together, then uses `Where-Object` to select only the odd ones with `|?{$_%2}`. Those are fed into a loop. Each iteration, we construct the appropriate number of spaces, string-concatenated with the appropriate number of asterisks. Those strings are left on the pipeline, and output via implicit `Write-Output` inserts newlines between them at program completion.

#### Examples

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> 3,5,7|%{.\draw-an-hourglass.ps1 $_;""}
***
 *
***

*****
 ***
  *
 ***
*****

*******
 *****
  ***
   *
  ***
 *****
*******
```

Answer (score 6):

## C, <s>114</s> 109 bytes

```c++
i,j;k(n){for(i=-n/2;i<=n/2;++i)for(j=-n/2;j<=n/2+1;++j)putchar(j==n/2+1?10:(i>=j&i>=-j)|(i<=j&i<=-j)?42:32);}
```

ungolfed:

```c++
i,j;
k(n){
 for(i=-n/2;i<=n/2;++i)
  for(j=-n/2;j<=n/2+1;++j)
   putchar(j==n/2+1?10:(i>=j&i>=-j)|(i<=j&i<=-j)?42:32);
}
```

Previous recursive solution:

```c++
p(a,c){while(a--)putchar(c);}
f(n,i){p(i,32);p(n,42);p(1,10);}
g(n,i){if(n>1)f(n,i),g(n-2,i+1);f(n,i);}
h(n){g(n,0);}
```

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), 66 bytes

```
f=(n,s="*".repeat(n))=>n>1?s+`
`+f(n-2).replace(/^/gm," ")+`
`+s:s
```

The idea here is to generate each hourglass from the previous: add a space at the beginning of every line, and both prepend and append `n` asterisks.

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>21</s> <s>20</s> <s>19</s> 17 bytes

Saved 2 bytes thanks to *carusocomputing*

```
;ƒ'*¹N·-×Nð×ì})û»
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=O8aSJyrCuU7Cty3Dl07DsMOXw6x9KcO7wrs&input=OQ)

**Explanation**

```
;ƒ                   # for N in [0 ... floor(input/2)+1]
  '*                 # push an asterisk
    ¹N·-×            # repeat the asterisk input-N*2 times
         Nð×ì        # prepend N spaces
             }       # end loop
              )      # wrap stack in a list
               û     # palendromize
                »    # join with newlines
```

Comment: `Ir"*"×.pRû` - Got this far, face palmed when I realized how far off I was, saw you had answered, going to go try to learn iteration in this language now using this example. Thanks!

Comment: I can actually help for once: `;ƒ'*¹N·-×Nð×ì})û»` use the new palindromize command. -2 bytes.

Comment: @carusocomputing: Thanks! I didn't know about the palendromize command (I hadn't refreshed the docs). Very useful. Have needed it several times before :)

Comment: [9 bytes](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//cOvhziB1rcPTD@/WS/7/3xIA), even in the legacy. Although I'm pretty sure the builtins `ÅÉ` and `.c` probably weren't available yet at the time you posted this. :)

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 12 bytes

```
Q2/Zv&<~42*c
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=UTIvWnYmPH40Mipj&input=NQ)

#### Explanation

This makes use of the [recently added](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL/releases/tag/19.3.0) *symmetric range* function.

```
Q     % Input n implicitly. Add 1
      % STACK: 6
2/    % Divide by 2
      % STACK: 3
Zv    % Symmetric range
      % STACK: [1 2 3 2 1]
&<~   % Matrix of all pairwise "greater than or or equal to" comparisons
      % STACK: [1 1 1 1 1
                0 1 1 1 0
                0 0 1 0 0
                0 1 1 1 0
                1 1 1 1 1]
42*   % Multiply by 42 (ASCII code of '*')
      % STACK: [42 42 42 42 42
                 0 42 42 42  0
                 0  0 42  0  0
                 0 42 42 42  0
                42 42 42 42 42]
c     % Convert to char. Implicitly display, with char 0 shown as space
      % STACK: ['*****'
                ' *** '
                '  *  '
                ' *** '
                '*****']
```

Comment: Nice! That's a cool feature. This is the only answer that came close to my V answer, so now I'm going to obsess on taking off one or two bytes. :D

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Heh, I don't think I will be able to reduce the byte count on this one

Comment: Yeah, I don't think I can either. There'll probably be a 4-byte Jelly answer in a couple minutes anyway, hahaha...

Answer (score 4):

## PHP, 95 bytes

```
for($c=str_pad,$m=$n=$argv[1];$n<=$m;$n+=$d=$d>0||$n<2?2:-2)echo$c($c('',$n,'*'),$m,' ',2)."
";
```

Instead of storing the rows in an array and then outputting everything, the for loop goes down until 1, and then goes back up to the original number.

Answer (score 3):

## C++11,  93 bytes

```c++
#include<string>
using S=std::string;S f(int n,int i=0){S s=S(i,32)+S(n,42)+'\n';return n>1?s+f(n-2,i+1)+s:s;}
```

Slightly ungolfed:

```c++
std::string f(int n,int i=0){
 auto s=std::string(i,' ') + std::string(n,'*') + '\n';
 return n>1 ? s+f(n-2,i+1)+s : s;
}
```

Usage:

```c++
std::cout << f(5);
```

Comment: Nice! one byte can be saved by assuming ASCII and replacing `'\n'` with `10` :)

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 20 bytes

```
XyY>t1X!*t2X!+ZS42*c
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=WHlZPnQxWCEqdDJYIStaUzQyKmM&input=NQ)

Comment: You can save a few bytes with the recently introduced symmetric range function: Q2/Zv&<~42*c

Comment: @LuisMendo That's cool! Since it's a *completely* different approach, I'll let you have it.

Comment: Ok, I'll post it!

Answer (score 3):

## C, 79 bytes

```
h(m,n,k){for(n=m++,k=n*m;--k;putchar(k%m?abs(k%m-m/2)>abs(k/m-n/2)?32:42:10));}
```

It splits the countdown variable `k` into row and column indices.
If the column index is 0 (last char in a row), it outputs a newline character (10). Then it adjusts the row and column indices to be around the center asterisk. Then, `abs(x) < abs(y)` is a short condition for outputting a space.

Answer (score 3):

## Java 7, <del>170 165</del> 164 bytes

*Thanks to @Hypino for saving 5 bytes.*
*Thanks to Kevin for saving 1 byte.*

```java
String c(int n,int x){String s,c,t=c=s=" ";int i=0;for(;i++<n;s+="*");for(i=x;i-->=0;c+=" ");for(i=x;i-->0;t+=" ");return(n=n-2)>=0?s+"\n"+c+c(n,++x)+"\n"+t+s:"*";}
```

Comment: You can save 2 bytes by removing `s=` from `s=s+"\n"`and 2 more bytes by changing `return(n=--n-1)` to `return(n=n-2)` for a total of 4 bytes.

Comment: Hi. You can golf two parts: `String s="",c="",t="";` to `String s,c,t=s=c="";` (**-2 bytes**), and `return(n=n-2)>=0?s+"\n"+c+c(n,++x)+` to `return n-1>0?s+"\n"+c+c(n-2,++x)+` (**-2 bytes** again)

Comment: But @KevinCruijssen pattern not as expected after changing `n=n-2`->`n-1>0` because n should be used in other argument of a function.

Comment: @Numberknot I know, but I also changed `n` to `n-2` at that part. `return(n=n-2)>=0 ... n` being changed to `return n-1>0 ... n-2` is still shorter. PS: You've thanked me for saving bytes, but haven't changed your code in your edit. ;)

Comment: @Numberknot Umm.. you still forgot my second tip. Anyway, here is a shorter variant: `String c(int n,int x){String s,c=s="";int i=0;for(;i++<n;s+="*");for(i=x;i-->0;c+=" ");return n>1?s+"\n "+c+c(n-2,x+1)+"\n"+c+s:"*";}` without the `t` ([ideone test](https://ideone.com/hyLeth) - **133 bytes**)

Answer (score 3):

## R, 77 bytes

```
M=matrix(" ",n<-scan(),n);for(i in 1:n)M[i:(n-i+1),i]="*";cat(M,sep="",fill=n)
```

Creates a character matrix, which it then prints out via `cat`, with `fill=n` making sure the lines align properly. Note that elements are stored in a matrix column-first (i.e the first two elements are `M[1,1]` and `M[2,1]`, not `M[1,2]`.)

Answer (score 3):

### PHP - 95 bytes

```
$c=2;for($i=$a=$argv[1];$i<=$a;$i-=$c*=$i<2?-1:1)echo str_pad(str_repeat("*",$i),$a," ",2)."
";
```

Saved a byte by using an actual new line instead of an `"\r"`

Answer (score 3):

## APL, 19 bytes

```
' *'[1+∘.≤⍨(⊢⌊⌽)⍳⎕]
```

Test:

```
      ' *'[1+∘.≤⍨(⊢⌊⌽)⍳⎕]
⎕:
      5
*****
 *** 
  *  
 *** 
*****
```

Explanation:

```
                 ⎕   ⍝ read number  
                ⍳    ⍝ 1..N
           ( ⌊ )     ⍝ at each position, minimum of
            ⊢        ⍝ 1..N
              ⌽      ⍝ and N..1 (this gives 1..N/2..1)
       ∘.≤⍨          ⍝ outer product with ≤
     1+              ⍝ add 1 to each value
' *'[             ]  ⍝ 1→space, 2→asterisk
```

Comment: Just remove `1+` and use an APL that has `⎕IO←0`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
⇵｛*×］⤢┼
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXUyMUY1JXVGRjVCKiVENyV1RkYzRCV1MjkyMiV1MjUzQw__,i=NQ__,v=0)

Explanation:

```
⇵｛*×］⤢┼
⇵         ceiling divide by 2
 ｛  ］    map over [1..pop]
   *         push *
    ×        repeat by the counter
       ⤢  transpose
        ┼  quad-palindromize with 1 overlap
```

[+1 byte](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXUyMUY1JXVGRjVCKiVENyV1RkYzRCV1MjkyMiV1MjUzQyV1MjU2Qw__,i=Ng__,v=0) with support for even numbers

Comment: [An alternate (similar) 7-byter](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXUyMUY1KiVENyV1RkYzQiV1RkYzRCV1MjkyMiV1MjUzQw__,i=NQ__,v=8)

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>54</s> 50 bytes

```powershell
filter f{if($_-1){'*'*$_;($_-2)|f|%{" $_"}}'*'*$_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/Py0zpyS1SCGtOjNNQyVe11CzWl1LXUsl3hrEM9KsSatRrVZSUIlXqq2FSNT@N9Yx1TEHCnMpAIFKfE0amKGuzlX7HwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <s>30</s> <s>28</s> <s>26</s> 25 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to FrownyFrog!

-3 bytes thanks to Jonah!

```
' *'#~](],.(-+:))i.@-<.i.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/1RW01JXrYjVidfQ0dLWtNDUz9Rx0bfQy9f5rcilwpSZn5CukKZhCGOrqMAFDw/8A)

### Previous version:

```
' *'{~[:(>.|.)@(*|."1)]\@#&1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/1RW01Kvroq007PRq9DQdNLRq9JQMNWNjHJTVDP9rcilwpSZn5CukKZhCGOrqMAFDw/8A)

Comment: `]\@#&1` is 2 shorter

Comment: @FrownyFrog Yes, of course! Thank you!

Comment: 26 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/1RW01JXrYjVidfQ0dLWtNDVr9Bwy9Wz0MvX@a3IpcKUmZ@QrpCmYQhjq6jABQ8P/AA "J – Try It Online")

Comment: @Jonah Thank you! I have almost forgotten I solved this one :)

Comment: Got one more byte off, 25: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/1RW01JXrYjVidfQ0dLWtNDUz9Rx0bfQy9f5rcilwpSZn5CukKZhCGOrqMAFDw/8A "J – Try It Online")

Comment: @Jonah Great! You don't give up :)

Answer (score 3):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <del>104</del> 88 bytes

```php
for(;$i++<$argn;$a.='**',$i++>1?$o=$s.$o:1)$o.=$s=str_pad("*$a",$argn,' ',2)."
";echo$o;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRoKCSWJSeZ5uWnlpSrBEc4uLpp2n9Py2/SMNaJVNb2wYsa62SqGerrqWlrgMSszO0V8m3VSnWU8m3MtRUydcDsm2LS4riCxJTNJS0VBKVdMC6dNQV1HWMNPWUuJSsU5Mz8lXyrf//NwcA)

<del>This doesn't beat the lowest scores for PHP on this challenge, but it's just too crazy for me to throw away.</del>

Okay, so I've golfed now it to be the (not for long) lowest score for PHP on this challenge, but it doesn't change the fact that it's still crazy.

```php
$ echo 7|php -nF hour.php
*******
 *****
  ***
   *
  ***
 *****
*******
```

Comment: [83?](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRoKCSWJSeZ5uWnlpSrBEc4uLpp2n9Py2/SMNaJVNb2wYsa62ZmpyRr1BcUhRfkJiiAaKLUgtSE0s01LXUdQy1E5OKNcAKdVUytYy0DTU1dcBcHXUFdR0jTT11LnXr///NAQ) also huh, php has barewords too, although it's not useful here

Comment: @ASCII-only rats! Looks like I've got some more work to do! lol

Comment: [82?](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRoKCSWJSeZ5uWnlpSrBEc4uLpp2n9Py2/SMNaJdMGLGetmZqcka9QXFIUX5CYogGii1ILUhNLNNS11HUMtROTijXACnVVMrW1gYSmpg6Yr6OuoK5jpKmnzqVu/f@/OQA) [alternative 82](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRoKCSWJSeZ5uWnlpSrBEc4uLpp2n9Py2/SMNaJdMGLGetmZqcka9QXFIUX5CYogGj1dV1DLUTk4o1wIp0VTK1tYGEpo66lrqmDlhMR11BXcdIU0@dS936/39zAA)

Comment: [with proper flags :P](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLNKxVMm1UEovS86w1U5Mz8hWKS4riCxJTNGC0urqOoXZiUrEGWJGuSqa2NpDQ1FHXUtfUAYvpqCuo6xhp6qlzqVv//2/@L7@gJDM/r/i/bp4bAA) [sadly, this is longer](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLNKxVMm1UEovS86w1U5Mz8jVUCmzVi0uK4gsSU9Q1gTwNdXUdQ@3EpGINsCpdlUxtbSChqaOupa6pAxbTUVdQ1zHS1FPnUrf@/9/8X35BSWZ@XvF/3Tw3AA)

Comment: @ASCII-only yep, nicely done! That's for sure the right approach!

Comment: [ouch, that didn't work :/](https://tio.run/##TcmhDoAgFEDR7lcY3gao6GYxgLP5Gw4dKgR4A75fZCbLDffgjVkuWHr6QAXYWe2RggqX42DatoR1YOT8LcH0cfs6prAFjVolSmrSfTSMHOwwsv6PTUHLetJUROQ8PR6T8S5m7tYX)

Answer (score 3):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 90 bytes

```
+?
Fx,`i,j:i,-1,*" ",o,`j,x-,+1,+j,-1,*"a",O
x-1
Fx,`i,+1,j:i,x-,+1,*" ",o,`j,*2,-1,*"a",O
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/1/bnsutQichUyfLKlNH11BHS0lBSSdfJyFLp0JXR9tQRzsLIpqopOPPVaFrCFUNlAFpgKhB6NEyQqj@//@/KQA)

Just two for loops.

My first Add++ answer!

Comment: Nice, congrats :-)

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `C`, <s>14</s> <s>13</s> 11 bytes

-2 thanks to @Lyxal

```
½ʀƛd⁰ε×*;øm
```

Port of [Emigna's 05AB1E solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/97414/80050).

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=C&code=%C2%BD%CA%80%C6%9Bd%E2%81%B0%CE%B5%C3%97*%3B%C3%B8m&inputs=7&header=&footer=)

```
½ʀƛd⁰ε×*;øm    # Full program
  ƛ     ;      # Map each n
½ʀ             # in range(0, input / 2 + 1):
       *        # Repeat...
      ×         # the character `*`...
   d⁰ε          # abs(2 * n - input) times
          øm   # Palindromize
               # Implicit output (`C' flag): join the array on newlines and center each line
```

Comment: [Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=C&code=%C2%BD%CA%80%C6%9Bd%E2%81%B0%CE%B5%C3%97*%3B%C3%B8m&inputs=7&header=&footer=) for 11 bytes

Answer (score 3):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org) <sup>[SBCS](http://tinyurl.com/Uiua-SBCS-Feb-17)</sup>, 16 bytes

```
≡&p⊏:" *"⊞≤.↥⇌.⇡
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_10_0-dev_1__RiDihpAg4omhJnDiio86IiAqIuKKnuKJpC7ihqXih4wu4oehCgpGIDUKJnAiIgpGIDExCg==)

Assumes the output must be a string or printed. If a character matrix is acceptable, remove the `≡&p` for -3 bytes.

- `↥⇌.⇡` Range, duplicate, reverse, max. If the input is 5, this would create `[4 3 2 3 4]` from it.
- `⊞≤.` Table with itself by less than or equal to. This creates the binary hourglass matrix.
- The rest is just converting to characters and printing.

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal 3](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-3) `j`, 11 bytes

```
zU•×ᵂ½ṚᶻḊVṅ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#WyJqIiwiIiwielXigKLDl+G1gsK94bma4ba74biKVuG5hSIsIiIsIjciLCIzLjQuMiJd)

Answer (score 3):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-l`, 16 bytes

```
QP("* "_>BMCHUa)
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCIiLCJRUChcIiogXCJfPkJNQ0hVYSkiLCIiLCIiLCItbCA1Il0=)

#### Explanation

```lisp
QP("* "_>BMCHUa)
              a  ; Command-line argument
            HU   ; Halve and round up
          MC     ; Map this function to a square coordinate grid of that size:
       _>B       ;   1 if x coord is greater than y coord, 0 otherwise
                 ; This results in a matrix which is 1 below the main diagonal and
                 ; 0 on or above it
  ("* "        ) ; Use that as an index into this string: 0 -> "*", 1 -> " "
QP               ; Quad-palindromize
                 ; Print each element of the top-level list on a separate line (-l flag)
```

#### Alternate 16-byte solution

```lisp
QP" *"@\$|*EYHUa
             HUa ; Halve argument and round up
           EY    ; Identity matrix of that size
       \$        ; Scan
          *      ; each row
         |       ; on logical OR
                 ; This results in a matrix which is 0 below the main diagonal and
                 ; 1 on or above it
QP" *"@          ; Index into a string and quad-palindromize, as before
```

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 22 bytes

```
j+J.e+*dk*b\*_:1hQ2_PJ
```

A program that takes input of an integer on STDIN and prints the result.

[Try it online](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=j%2BJ.e%2B%2adk%2ab%5C%2a_%3A1hQ2_PJ&input=9&debug=0)

**How it works**

```
j+J.e+*dk*b\*_:1hQ2_PJ  Program. Input: Q
              :1hQ2     Range from 1 to Q+1 in steps of 2. Yields [1, 3, 5, ..., Q]
             _          Reverse
   .e                   Enumnerated map with b as elements and k as indices:
      *dk                 k spaces
         *b\*             b asterisks
     +                    Concatenate the spaces and asterisks
  J                     Store in J
                    PJ  All of J except the last element
                   _    Reverse
 +                      Concatenate J and its modified reverse
j                       Join on newlines
                        Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 2):

## C, <s>195</s> 191 Bytes

Should golf down a bit smaller

```
x,y,i;f(n){for(i=0;i<n;i+=2,puts("")){for(y=n-i;y<n;y+=2,putchar(32));for(x=i;x++<n;putchar(42));}for(i=n-2;~i;i-=2,puts("")){for(y=n-i+2;y<n;y+=2,putchar(32));for(x=i-1;x++<n;putchar(42));}}
```

We can test it [here](http://ideone.com/cV2Oh1) on ideone

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, <s>55</s> 54 bytes

```
f=->n,s=0{puts a=' '*s+?**n;(f[n-2,s+1];puts a)if n>1}
```

Comment: `?**n` works; you don't need the space there.

Answer (score 2):

### Java 7, 156 bytes

Fairly simple. Keeps track of lines with `n`, stars with `j`, spaces with `s`, and direction with `d`. I really just wanted a non-recursive Java answer on the board, but it doesn't hurt that it's also a bit shorter :)

```java
String f(int n){String o="";int j=n,s=0,i,d=0;for(;n-->0;o+="\n"){for(i=0;i++<s;)o+=" ";for(i=0;i++<j;)o+="*";d+=j<2?1:0;j+=d<1?-2:2;s+=d<1?1:-1;}return o;}
```

With line breaks:

```java
String f(int n){
    String o="";
    int j=n,s=0,i,d=0;
    for(;n-->0;o+="\n"){
        for(i=0;i++<s;)
            o+=" ";
        for(i=0;i++<j;)
            o+="*";
        d+=j<2?1:0;
        j+=d<1?-2:2;
        s+=d<1?1:-1;
    }
    return o;
}
```

Comment: [146 bytes](https://tio.run/##LY7BDoIwEAV/pemppaBi9LTWxG/wqB4qBbMVt4QWE0P4dgTxOPPeYZx5m8w3JTn7HIvahMBOfYgmYjGeY4v0YJVAioxk/2evOYdZOU1p0JsUU6tzqHwrgLLsuAGvNL8Sl/3sUAfAn5azZ/z3tErnawdK4cEtQ8LBKb3N8rVNdhDm3SYTwtCWsWuJeRjGprvXWLAlkL09WvYySGJJu9zCVPkJsXytfBdXzSSjqMReShiG8Qs "Java (OpenJDK 8) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, 84 bytes

```
f n|l<-div n 2,k<-[-l..l]=putStr$unlines[[" *"!!(fromEnum$abs x<=abs y)|x<-k]|y<-k]
```

Comment: Nice solution! But I'm pretty sure you don't need the `putStr` and you can get rid of the `fromEnum` like [this](https://tio.run/##FcSxDsIgFAXQX7mDCYmRDm4acHF1cyQMmFIlPJ9NeTVtwr@jHc55hZIjUWsDuJLRffqCcTxko52mriNvZ6bEsThHochO7dXZKagaHgXLZXv1dTE6@7put3dIDItxlrtMN0aH4W@KoYc1Bs8o1w9LZCnt9AM "Haskell – Try It Online").

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>80</s> 74 bytes

Thank ceilingcat for 6 bytes

```c
-Du(x,k)=for(x=~n;x+=2,x<n;putchar(k))

i;j;f(n){u(i,10)u(j,i*i<j*j?32:42);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcdBCoMwEADA7@xqBJP21DX04kfCQuzGGkUbCIg@3UjnNtwMzKUIBfIQcU8gSreYICippAtVeD/M62mQjjI5iYC7B63/vdh/3bCVpk@Q1YjWzytke0bKtTUqd5GW9OOPW2FEvAE)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 15 bytes

```
HŻżḂƇṚ$⁾ *xⱮŒḄY
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASkA1v9qZWxsef//SMW7xbzhuILGh@G5miTigb4gKnjisa7FkuG4hFn///8xNQ)

I'm surprised there wasn't a Jelly answer yet. Jelly is not good at strings.

### Explanation

```
HŻżḂƇṚ$⁾ *xⱮŒḄY   Main monadic link
H                 Halve: n/2
 Ż                Range from 0 to floor(n/2)
  ż               Zip with
      $           (
                    Range from 1 to n
    Ƈ               Filter by
   Ḃ                  parity [to get the odd numbers]
     Ṛ              Reverse
      $           )
           Ɱ      For each pair of numbers
          x         repeat
       ⁾ *            the characters ' ' and '*' that many times
            ŒḄ    Bounce (palindromize)
              Y   Join with newlines
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-2) `CRM`, 5 bytes

```
y×ẋṘ∞
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyJDUk0iLCIiLCJ5w5fhuovhuZjiiJ4iLCIiLCI3Il0=)

Newer Vyxal 2 version with a ton of flags but hey 5 bytes

Comment: [4.375 with vyncode](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyJDUk09IiwiIiwieeG5mMOXKuKIniIsIiIsIjciXQ==)

Answer (score 1):

#### PHP, 191 bytes

```
$b=[];for($i=$a=$argv[1]+1;$i>0;$i--){$i--;if($i<=1){$c=str_pad("*",$a," ",2)."\n";break;}$b[]=str_pad(str_repeat("*",$i),$a," ",2)."\n";}echo implode("",$b).$c.implode("",array_reverse($b));
```

Run like `php -f golf_hourglass.php 15`

```
# php -f golf_hourglass.php 15
***************
 *************
  ***********
   *********
    *******
     *****
      ***
       *
      ***
     *****
    *******
   *********
  ***********
 *************
***************
```

The idea behind it is to create the top half (the part before the single `*`), then just echo the top part twice, but the second time in reverse order.

Comment: I think this is a better start for this task `for(;$i<$a=$argv[1];$i+=2){$t=str_pad(str_pad("",$i+1,"*"),$a," ",2)."\n";$i?$s.=$t:$r=$t;}echo strrev($s)."\n".$r.$s;`

Comment: `for(;$i<$a=$argv[1];$i++){$t=str_pad(str_pad("",$i+1+$i%2,"*"),$a," ",2)."\n";$i%2?$s.=$t:$s=$t.$s;}echo$s;` this is better

Comment: Replace implode() with join() to save 6 bytes.

Comment: Replace `\n` with an actual new line to save a byte.

Answer (score 1):

## Groovy, 66 Bytes

```
{n->((n..1)+(2..n)).each{if(it%2>0){println(("*"*it).center(n))}}}
```

Try it: https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5145735624392704

### Explained:

`((n..1)+(2..n))` - Reverse palindromize to n `[n,..,1,..,n]`

`.each{if(it%2>0){...}` - Iterate through odd elements.

`println(("*"*it).center(n))` - Center n stars and print each on newline.

Comment: `.each`'s code block could be `{it%2&&println(("*"*it).center(n))}`.

Answer (score 1):

### Pyke, <s>22</s> 19 bytes

```
F-ed*ih\**+)2%'X_OX
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=F-ed%2aih%5C%2a%2a%2B%292%25%27X_OX&input=5)

```
F          )        -    for i in range(input)
 -                  -        Q-i
  e                 -       floor(^/2)
   d*               -      ^*" "
          +         -     ^+V
     ih             -       i+1
       \**          -      ^*"*"
            2%      -   ^[::2]
              'X_   - splat(^),
                       reversed(^)
                 OX - splat(^[:-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

## C, 117 bytes

```
void p(c,n){while(n--)putchar(c);}void h(n){for(int i=n;i>=-n;i-=i==1?4:2){p(32,(n-abs(i))/2);p(42,abs(i));p(10,1);}}
```

Ungolfed

```
void printNum(c, n) {
  while (n--)
    putchar(c);
}

void hourGlass(n) {
  for (int i = n; i >= -n; i-=i==1?4:2) {
    printNum(32, (n - abs(i)) / 2);
    printNum(42, abs(i));
    printNum(10, 1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 158 bytes

(-2 if I can omit the start tag)

```
<?$v=$argv[1]/2;while($c++<$v){$a="";$b=$v+.5;while(--$b)$a.=$b<$c?" ":"*";$z[]=strrev($a)."*$a";}$c=array_pop($z);$a=join($z,"
");echo"$a
$c
".strrev($a);
```

A similar approach to the one @hd took but uses manual concatenation instead of built-in string functions with overly long names. I wish I could call $z->pop()

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 22 bytes

```
VQ+*d-J/Q2aJN*\*hatQyN
```

[Try online.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=VQ%2B%2ad-J%2FQ2aJN%2a%5C%2ahatQyN&input=5&debug=0)

Lame attempt at explaining:

```
VQ+*d-J/Q2aJN*\*hatQyN   The whole thing.
VQ                       For N in [0,1,2, ... ,Q-1]; Q takes the input.
      J/Q2               Integer division Q/2, store in J
          aJN            Absolute difference between N and J
     -                   Subtract the above numbers...
   *d                    ...and repeat whitespace that many times
  +                      Concatenate that with output from the next block
                 atQyN   Absolute difference between Q-1 and 2*N
             *\*h        Repeat an asterisk the above number of times + 1
```

Interestingly I matched TheBikingViking's score on the same language using a different approach... O:

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, <s>191</s> 154 bytes

```
@echo off
set s=*
set l=for /l %%i in (2,1,%1)do call:
%l%s
%l%s
%l%u
%l%l
:l
echo %s%
:s
set s=%s:~1%**
exit/b
:u
echo %s%
set s= %s:~0,-2%
```

The `u` subroutine generates the top half of the hourglass by prepending a space and removing two trailing stars each time. The `l` subroutine generates the bottom half of the hourglass by removing a space and appending two trailing stars each time. The code falls through into the `l` subroutine at the end to save bytes. The second half of the `l` subroutine is also used to build up the initial string, although it has to be called twice as many times as the string doesn't have its spaces yet.

Edit: Saved 37 bytes by using an idea by @ConorO'Brien.

Answer (score 1):

### Racket 177 bytes

```
(let p((n N)(d #t))(for((i(/(- N n)2)))(display" "))(for((i n))(display #\*))(displayln"")
(cond[(and(not d)(= n N))][(= n 1)(set! d #f)(p(+ 2 n)d)][d(p(- n 2)d)][(p(+ 2 n)d)]))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(define (f N)
  (let loop ((n N)
             (d #t))                      ; descending
    (for ((i (/(- N n)2)))
          (display " "))
    (for ((i n))
      (display #\*))
    (displayln "")
    (cond
      [(and (not d) (= n N))]             ; end
      [(= n 1) (set! d #f)
               (loop (+ 2 n) d)]
      [d (loop (- n 2) d)]
      [(loop (+ 2 n) d)]))
  )
```

Testing:

```
(f 9)
```

Output:

```
*********
 *******
  *****
   ***
    *
   ***
  *****
 *******
*********
#t
```

Answer (score 1):

## Swift 3, <del>139</del> 130

```
let c={String(repeating:$0,count:$1)};func d(_ n:Int,_ i:Int=0)->String{let b=c(" ",i)+c("*",n)+"\n";return n>1 ?b+d(n-2,i+1)+b:b}
```

[On-line test](http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/5816c377586da353fafab504)

<del>[`let c={(s,i)in(0..<i).reduce(""){(b,_)in b+s}};func d(_ n:Int,_ i:Int=0)->String{let b=c(" ",i)+c("*",n)+"\n";return n>1 ?b+d(n-2,i+1)+b:b}`](http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/58160e2e1503df5a9307a0c7)</del>

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cjam/), 26 bytes

```
ri:A,_W%.e<{_S*A@2*-'**N}/
```

[Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=cmk6QSxfVyUuZTx7X1MqQUAyKi0nKipOfS8&input=OQ)

```
ri:A     e# read integer, save as A
,_W%     e# make range and mirror (e.g.[0,1,2,3,4],[4,3,2,1,0])
.e<      e# take minimums (e.g.[0,1,2,1,0])
{        e# for each minimum "m"
  _S*    e#   push m spaces
  A@2*-  e#   calculate A-2m (rotates to spare m)
  '**    e#   push A-2m asterisks
  N      e#   push a newline
}/       e# end, prints stack
```

Answer (score 1):

## T-SQL, 93 bytes

This will also provide an answer when an even number is used - the bottom row will be missing.

**Golfed:**

```
DECLARE @ INT=5

,@i INT=0z:PRINT SPACE(@/2-abs(@/2-@i))+REPLICATE('*',abs(@/2-@i)*2+1)SET
@i+=1IF @i<@ GOTO z
```

**Ungolfed:**

```
DECLARE @ INT=5

,@i INT=0
z:
PRINT SPACE(@/2-abs(@/2-@i))+REPLICATE('*',abs(@/2-@i)*2+1)
SET @i+=1
IF @i<@ GOTO z
```

A bit longer alternative solution without looping

```
USE master
DECLARE @ INT=5
SELECT top(@)SPACE(@/2-abs(@/2-number))+REPLICATE('*',abs(@/2-number)*2+1)
FROM spt_values
WHERE'P'=type
```

**[Fiddle](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/567792/draw-an-hourglass)**

Answer (score 1):

## [Actually](http://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 34 bytes

```
;╗R`1&`░`'**╜kd#"{:^%d}"%f`M;pXR+i
```

[Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=O-KVl1JgMSZg4paRYCcqKuKVnGtkIyJ7Ol4lZH0iJWZgTTtwWFIraQ&input=NQ)

Explanation:

```
;╗R`1&`░`'**╜kd#"{:^%d}"%f`M;pXR+i
;╗                                  store a copy of n in register 0
  R                                 range(1, n+1) ([1, n])
   `1&`░                            filter: keep only odd values
        `'**╜kd#"{:^%d}"%f`M        for each value:
         '**                          push a string containing that many asterisks
            ╜                         push n
             kd#                      list from stack, dequeue, listify (make both stack elements singleton lists)
                "{:^%d}"%             format string to center string in n-wide field
                         f            do the formatting
                            ;pXR+   duplicate list, discard the extra "*" element, reverse, and append original list (vertical mirroring)
                                 i  flatten and implicitly print
```

Answer (score 1):

## Common Lisp, 101 bytes

```
(dotimes(i(1+(set'x(read))))(format t"~v:@<~v{*~}~>~&"x(set'b(abs(- x(* i 2))))1)(if(= 1 b)(incf i)))
```

Answer (score 1):

## Excel VBA, <sub><s>68</s></sub> 67 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes input from `[A1]` and outputs to the VBE immediate window

```vb
n=[Int(A1/2)]:For i=-n To n:j=abs(i):?Spc(n-j)String(2*j+1,42):Next
```

Answer (score 1):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGLOnline), 12 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
.↔∫ **}⁰№§╬3
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=LiV1MjE5NCV1MjIyQiUyMCoqJTdEJXUyMDcwJXUyMTE2JUE3JXUyNTZDMw__,inputs=NQ__,v=0.12)

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 66 bytes

```
->n{(-n..n).each{|x|x.abs>1?(puts"*"*x.abs):(puts"*"*x if x>0)}}
```

Probably a shorter way of doing this, but this is the most straight forward one i came up with.

Answer (score 1):

### Japt, 11 bytes

```
õ_î*ÃÔë ê û
```

[Try it online](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=9V/uKsPU6yDqIPs=&input=OQoKLVI=)

Answer (score 1):

## Japt `-R`, 11 bytes

```
1õU2_ç*Ãê û
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=MfVVMl/nKsPqIPs=&input=NQotUg==)

```
                :Implicit input of integer U
1õU2            :Range [U,1] in increments of 2
    _           :Map each Z
     ç*         :  Repeat "*" Z times
       Ã        :End map
        ê       :Palindromise
          û     :Centre pad each element with spaces to the length of the longest
                :Implicitly join with newlines and output
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python 3, 79 bytes

```
def f(i):[print(' '*(i//2-abs(j-i//2))+'*'*2*abs(j-i//2)+'*')for j in range(i)]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Oracle SQL, 119 bytes

```
SQL> select lpad(' ',ceil(n/2)-x-1,' ')||rpad('*',x*2+1,'*')from(select n,abs(ceil(n/2)-rownum)x from t connect by level<=n)
  2  /

LPAD('',CEIL(N/2)-X-1,'')||RPAD('*',X*2+1,'*')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*******
 *****
  ***
   *
  ***
 *****
*******

7 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [sed 4.2.2](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), <s>54</s> 42 bytes

```
:
H
s/00/ /
t
:a
s/ 0/000/
H
//ba
g
y/0/*/
```

Takes input in unary (e.g. `3` is `000`), allowed as per [meta consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5349/58834).
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N@f/fisuDq1jfwEBfQZ@rhMsqEchRMADyDfSBEvr6SYlc6VyV@gb6Wvr//xvAwL/8gpLM/Lzi/7pFAA)

Code with comments:

```
#Create an unnamed branch label (sed 4.2 only)
:
#Append pattern buffer to hold buffer
H
#Replace first two zeroes with a space
s/00/ /
#If we did the previous replacement, branch back to the unnamed label
t
#Create a label a
:a
#Replace last space with two zeroes
s/ 0/000/
#Append pattern buffer to the hold buffer
H
#Check if there is still something to replace (// refers to the previous pattern)
#If so, branch to label a
//ba
#Replace the pattern buffer with the hold buffer
g
#Replace zeroes with asterisks
y/0/*/
```

-12 bytes thanks to Xcali

Comment: You can cut that down to [42 bytes](https://tio.run/##K05N@f/fisuDq1jfwEBfQZ@rhMsqEchRMADyDfSBEvr6SYlc6VyV@gb6Wvr//xtAwL/8gpLM/Lzi/7pFAA "sed 4.2.2 – Try It Online") since the trailing spaces are not needed.

Comment: @Xcali Ah yes, cutting those off makes this much easier. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-a`, 51 bytes

```perl
$_%2&&say$"x(("@F"-abs)/2),'*'x abs for-$_..0,2..$_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lXtVITa04sVJFqUJDQ8nBTUk3MalYU99IU0ddS71CAchRSMsv0lWJ19Mz0DHS01OJ///f0PBffkFJZn5e8X9dX1M9A0OD/7qJAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Rockstar](https://codewithrockstar.com/), 141 bytes

```
listen to N
let X be N--2
F takes X
let Y be N-X
let Y be/2
say " "*Y+"*"*X

while X-1
let X be-2
F taking X

while N-X
let X be+2
F taking X
```

[Try it here](https://codewithrockstar.com/online) (Code will need to be pasted in)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OI65pLrIfdk&ab_channel=FearlessRecords

Comment: horrible music if you'd ask me but fitting very good, also nice language @Shaggy