# Operator ASCII art

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art

#### Challenge

Given an [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) operator from the list below and a number n, draw an ASCII representation of the operator using that operator as the character with the line segments of the operator having length *n*.

#### Input

An ASCII character from the list `= + - x /` and an integer `n` where `n >= 1`.  (I'm using `x` instead of `*` and `/` instead of `÷`, but you could use either one, whichever is easier). For `+` and `x`, you only have to handle odd numbers to avoid issues with alignment.

#### Output

An ASCII drawing of the operator composed of the character with segments of length n. Horizontal portions should have spaces between the characters to offset vertical/horizontal distance differences.

#### Rules

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes wins. Standard loopholes are forbidden.

#### Examples

Input: `+ 3`

```
  +
+ + +
  +
```

Input: `= 4`

```
= = = =
= = = =
```

Input: `= 10`

```
= = = = = = = = = =
= = = = = = = = = =
```

Input: `- 2`

```
- -
```

Input: `/ 10`

```
         /
        /
       /
      /
     /
    /
   /
  /
 /
/
```

Input: `x 7`

```
x     x
 x   x
  x x
   x
  x x
 x   x
x     x
```

Comment: can you add the test case for `= 10`?

Comment: I assume "x" and "+" imply odd numbers? (I just saw DrMcMoylex asked nearly the same question.)

Comment: @MartinRosenau Yes, from the Input section: **"For + and x, you only have to handle odd numbers to avoid issues with alignment."**

Comment: Why are X and / not spaced out?

Comment: is leading whitespace allowed?

Comment: @Adám As long as the output looks correct.

Comment: @Adám Oh and to answer your first question, because they technically don't have horizontal bits that are right next to each other like =, -, and +.  I considered specifying that they be spaced similarly, but decided against it.

Comment: To clarify: if we use `÷` for the division input, the output can be a diagonal line of `÷`?

Comment: @DLosc Hmm, I had not considered what the output would be for ÷.  I guess you could do what you said, since the circles in ÷ would be kinda difficult to express.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### [Pip](http://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), <s>62</s> <s>59</s> 56 bytes

55 bytes of code, +1 for `-S` flag.

```
[sXbRA_AEv-_aM,b(Y^aWR_Xb/2s)MyRVsX,b.aYaXbJsxyRL2x]@Aa
```

Note that this solution works with input of `÷` for division and `*` for multiplication, though it uses those characters to draw ASCII-art `/` and `x`, respectively. OP has [clarified](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/98890/operator-ascii-art#comment240883_98890) that this is okay. [Try it online!](http://pip.tryitonline.net/#code=W3NYYlJBX0FFdi1fYU0sYihZXmFXUl9YYi8ycylNeVJWc1gsYi5hWWFYYkpzeHlSTDJ4XUBBYQ&input=&args=w7c+NQ+LVM)

#### How?

Here's a [partially spaced and commented version](http://pip.tryitonline.net/#code=WyAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgQnVpbGQgYSBsaXN0IG9mIGFsbCBwb3NzaWJsZSBmaWd1cmVzOgogc1hiUkFfQUV2LV9hTSxiICAgMCAtIE11bHRpcGxpY2F0aW9uCiAoWV5hV1JfWGIvMnMpTXkgICAxIC0gQWRkaXRpb24KIFJWc1gsYi5hICAgICAgICAgIDIgLSBEaXZpc2lvbgogWWFYYkpzICAgICAgICAgICAgMyAtIFN1YnRyYWN0aW9uCiB4ICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA0IC0gRW1wdHkKIHlSTDIgICAgICAgICAgICAgIDUgLSBFcXVhbHMKIHggICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIDYgLSBFbXB0eQpdIEAgQWEgICAgICAgICAgICBJbmRleCwgbW9kIDcsIHdpdGggQVNDSUkgdmFsdWUgb2YgYQ&input=&args=w7c+NQ+LVM). Note that `a` and `b` are the command-line args, i.e. the operator and the size respectively. The `-S` flag controls how lists are output: it joins on newlines first, but joins any nested lists on spaces.

```
[                 Build a list of all possible figures:
 sXbRA_AEv-_aM,b   0 - Multiplication
 (Y^aWR_Xb/2s)My   1 - Addition
 RVsX,b.a          2 - Division
 YaXbJs            3 - Subtraction
 x                 4 - Empty
 yRL2              5 - Equals
 x                 6 - Empty
] @ Aa            Index, mod 7, with ASCII value of a
```

And here are the individual sections:

**Multiplication**

For each row in the figure, we generate a string of spaces and then replace two of them with the input character. For row `i`, we want to replace the spaces at index `i` and `b-1-i`; but note that the latter can use the negative index `-1-i`. (It's even shorter because the variable `v` is preinitialized to negati**v**e 1.)

```
sXbRA_AEv-_aM,b
            M,b  Map this function to range(b):
sXb                Space, repeated b times
     _             Function arg
      AE           (Implicitly) convert to list and append element...
        v-_        -1 minus function arg
   RA              Replace the characters at those indices...
           a       ... with input character
                 The resulting list is output with one item per line
```

**Addition**

Using the strategy from my [Draw a hollow square](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/98936/16766) answer, we define a function that wraps a `+` in `b/2` copies of its argument and returns the result as a list of characters. (Integer division `//` isn't necessary because the string repetition operator `X` automatically truncates to integer.) First, we call this function on a space, giving `[" ";" ";"+";" ";" "]`; then, we map the same function to that result, giving `[" ";" ";"+";" ";" "]` on most lines but `["+";"+";"+";"+";"+"]` on the center line. This nested list is then output, because of the `-S` flag, with spaces between all characters on a row and newlines between rows.

```
(Y^aWR_Xb/2s)My
                 Anonymous function:
      _Xb/2        Function arg, repeated b/2 times (implicitly rounded down)
   aWR             Wrap a in two copies of the above
  ^                Split resulting string into list of chars
 Y               Yank that function into y
(          s)    Apply function y to space
             My  Map y to that result
```

**Division**

Each row has between `b-1` and `0` spaces, followed by the input character `a`.

```
RVsX,b.a
    ,b    Range(b)
  sX      Space, repeated that many times (works itemwise)
      .a  Concatenate a (itemwise)
RV        Reverse (puts the larger number of spaces at the beginning)
          Outputs newline-separated
```

**Subtraction**

Make a space-separated row of the input character. Save a copy for later.

```
YaXbJs
 aXb    b copies of a
    Js  Join on space
Y       Yank into y (overwrites the function from earlier, but we're done using it anyway)
        This is a string, so it just gets output
```

**Equals**

The subtraction step stored half of what we need in `y`--just double it.

```
yRL2  (Implicitly) convert y to list and repeat it twice
      Outputs newline-separated
```

The dummy `x` values are there to pad the main list so that the modular indexing gives a unique index for each input character in `+-*÷=`.

Answer (score 13):

## [V](http://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), <s>78, 72, 71, 68, 65, 63, 62</s>, 61 bytes

```
Ç=ü-/Àé X
ç^Ó/é Àä$
ç+/ÀÄM|ÀR+ 
ç=/Ä
ç¯/lòhYpX
çx/rxòl3Äjxlrx
```

[Try it online!](http://v.tryitonline.net/#code=w4c9w7wtL8OAw6kgWArDp17Dky_DqSDDgMOkJArDpysvw4DDhE18w4BSKyAKw6c9L8OECsOnwq8vbMOyaFlwWArDp3gvcnjDsmwzw4RqeGxyeA&input=PQ&args=NQ)

As always, the neck-and-neck battle with 05AB1E is really fun!

Since this contains non-ASCII characters, here is a hexdump:

```
0000000: c73d fc2d 2fc0 e920 580a e75e d32f e920  .=.-/.. X..^./. 
0000010: c0e4 240a e72b 2fc0 c44d 7cc0 522b 200a  ..$..+/..M|.R+ .
0000020: e73d 2fc4 0ae7 af2f 6cf2 6859 7058 0ae7  .=/..../l.hYpX..
0000030: 782f 7278 f26c 33c4 6a78 6c72 78         x/rx.l3.jxlrx
```

This does create leading spaces in the output for `=` and `-`, but [this seems to be allowed](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/98890/operator-ascii-art/98902#comment240335_98890). If this is not allowed, feel free to comment and I'll roll it back.

## Explanation

The "global command" (e.g. `ç`) applies a certain set of commands to every line that matches a certain regex. The syntax is

```
ç<compressed regex>/<commands>
```

This is the easiest way of simulating a conditional/switch statement. In my original answer, I simply created the entire ASCII-art on the right-hand side for each different character we need to search for. However, a lot of these outputs require similar commands. So I combined them. The first command ('Ç') is actually the inverse of the global command, it applies the command to every line *not* matching the regex. So the first command is:

```
Ç=ü-        " On every line not containing an '=' or an '-' (e.g. inputs '/', '+', and 'x'):
    /Àé     "   Insert *n* spaces
        X   "   Delete one of them
```

The following command is for inputs '=' and '-'. These two are conveniently easy and similar. After this command, we need no more processing for `-`.

```
ç^Ó         " On every line that starts with non-whitespace (e.g. every line not affected by our previous command):
   /é       "   Insert one space
            "   Move back a character
      À     "   Make *n* copies
       ä$   "   Of every character on this line
```

From here we just do some extra commands for each individual possible input. For `+`:

```
ç+/         " On every line containing a '+':
   ÀÄ       "   Make *n* copies of this line
     M|     "   Move to the first character of the middle line
       À    "   *n* times:
        R+  "   Replace the next two characters with '+ '
```

The command for equals is very straightforward. We just duplicate it with `Ä`. For `/`:

```
ç¯          " On every line containing a '/':
  /l        "   Move one character to the right
    ò       "   Recursively:
     h      "     Move one character to the left
      Yp    "     Make a copy of this line
        X   "     Delete one character
         ò  "   End loop (implicit)
```

The last one is the most complicated. It is basically a port of [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/97402/31716).

```
çx              " On every line containing a 'x':
  /rx           "   Replace the first character with an 'x'
     ò          "   Recursively:
      l         "     Move one char to the right
       3Ä       "     Make 3 copies of this line
         j      "     Move down one line
          x     "     Delete one char
           l    "     Move one char to the right
            rx  "     Replace this char with an 'x'
```

Comment: so is that what multiple lines are used for?

Comment: @Conorobrien Yes. The `ç` command (as well as search and replace, `/` and `?`) all simulate part of vim's command line, where you have to hit enter to actually run the command

Answer (score 13):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>81</s> <s>76</s> <s>74</s> <s>73</s> <s>70</s> <s>69</s> <s>68</s> <s>65</s> <s>64</s> <s>62</s> <s>60</s> <s>59</s> <s>57</s> 56 bytes

Currently **in war** with the [*V answer*](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/98902/34388). I'm coming for you Dr. McMoylex :p.

Also **in war** with the [*Pip answer*](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99231/34388). I'll be watching you Mr. DLosc.

---

Code:

```
Ç6&"¹s<ú.s.Bívy¹'xQiÂðñ}, ¹×S)»¹'=Qƒ= ;ƒ¹})D¦»»Rû.c"#è.V
```

Or in a more readable form:

```
  Ç6&
"¹s<ú.s.Bívy¹'xQiÂðñ},
 ¹×S)»¹'=Qƒ=
 ;ƒ¹})D¦»»Rû.c"
#è.V
```

Uses the **CP-1252** encoding. [Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=w4c2JiLCuXM8w7oucy5Cw612ecK5J3hRacOCw7DDsX0sIMK5w5dTKcK7wrknPVHGkj0gO8aSwrl9KUTCpsK7wrtSw7suYyIjw6guVg&input=eAo3)

Comment: Here we go again... :P

Comment: @DrMcMoylex Hahaha, good old times :).

Comment: More readable... totally...

Comment: For a given definition of "readable".

Comment: [I'm coming for you, Adnan](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99231/16766) :P

Comment: @DLosc I'll be watching you closely from now on haha :p.

Answer (score 7):

## Python 3, <s>304</s> <s>283</s> 278 bytes

Simple enough, just makes a matrix of chars and applies the different operations based on which one it is. The `=` and `-` have trailing spaces if that's not too bad.

EDIT: Thanks to @Shebang and @Rod for their suggestions which ended up saving 21 bytes!

EDIT2: Thanks to @Artyer for saving 5 bytes!

```
t,s=input().split()
s=int(s)
r=range(s)
b=[[' ']*s for x in r]
exec(['for x in r:b[s//2][x]=b[x][s//2]=t','b=[t*s]'+'*2'*(t=='='),'for x in r:b[x][s-x-1]='+'b[x][x]='*(t=='x')+'t'][(t>'+')+(t in'x/')])
if t in'-=+':b=[[x+' 'for x in l]for l in b]
print(*map(''.join,b),sep='\n')
```

Comment: You can save 8 bytes by removing the `if'-'==t` condition line and replacing the one above it with `if t in'=-':b=[[t+' ']*s]*(2*(t>'-'))` (I think).

Comment: you can wrap the functions inside a list and run using exec: `exec(['+ block','/ block','x block','= block','- block']['+/x=-'.find(t)])` to save ~18 bytes

Comment: Yes, trailing spaces/newlines are acceptable.

Comment: For the first line, do `.split()` (No args splits on whitespace). On line 6, you missed a space (`b=[[x+' 'for`). You can make the last line `print(*map(''.join,b),sep='\n')` for 1 less bytes.

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>238</s> <s>225</s> <s>215</s> <s>202</s> 196 bytes

```
(c,n)=>[...Array(i=n*(c=="="?4:c+1-1?2:c<"-"?n+n:n+1))].map(_=>--i%(n+(c=='/'|c>'w'||n))?c>'w'?i%n&&~-i%(n+2)?" ":c:c<'-'?i%(n*2)-n&&(~i&1|(n/2^i/n/2))?" ":c:c=="/"?i%n?" ":c:i%2?c:" ":`
`).join``
```

Could probably be golfed, but it's a start.

Answer (score 6):

## Scala, 275 bytes

```
(i,c)=>if(c<44){val b=(" "*(i-1)+"+\n")*((i-1)/2)
b+"+ "*i+"\n"+b}else
if(c<46)"- "*i else
if(c<48)i-1 to(0,-1)map(" "*_+"/\n")mkString else
if(c<62)"= "*i+"\n"+"= "*i
else{val a=0 to i/2-1 map(x=>" "*x+"x"+" "*((i/2-x)*2-1)+"x"+" "*x+"\n")mkString;a+" "*(i/2)+"x"+a.reverse}
```

Usage:

```
val f:((Int,Char)=>String)=...
print(f(10, '/'))
```

Explanation:

The code tests for the ascii value of the char to choose the right way of generating the image. The ascii values of the operators in question are:
`('+' -> 43), ('-' ->45), ('/' -> 47), ('=' -> 61), ('x' -> 120)`

```
(i,c)=>                              //define a function
  if(c<44){                            //if c is a plus
    val b=(" "*(i-1)+"+\n")*((i-1)/2)    //define the top/bottom part b as (i-1)/2 times (i-1) spaces, a plus sign and a newlineine
    b+"+ "*i+"\n"+b                      //return b, i times a plus and a space, a newline and b
  }else if(c<46)                       //if c is a '-'
    "- "*i                               //return "- " repeated i times
  else if(c<48)                        //if c is a '/'
    i-1 to(0,-1)                         //create a range from i-1 to 0 in steps of -1
    map(" "*_+"/\n")                     //map each number to that number of spaces plus a "/" and a newline
    mkString                             //join them together
  else if(c<62)                        //if c is '='
    "= "*i+"\n"+"= "*i                   //return "= " repeated i times, a newline and "= " repeated i times again
  else{                                //if c if 'x'
    val a=                               //define a, which will be the top part, as...
      0 to i/2-1                         //a range from 0 to i/2-1
      map(n=>                            //map each number n to
        " "*n                              //n spaces
        +"x"                               //plus an "x"
        +" "*((i/2-n)*2-1)                 //plus ((i/2)-n)*2-1 spaces
        +"x"                               //plus an "x"
        +" "*n                             //plus n spaces
        +"\n"                              //and a newline
      )mkString;                         //join them
    a+" "*(i/2)+"x"+a.reverse          //return a, i/2 spaces, "x" and the reverse of a 
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

### JavaScript (ES6), 156 bytes

```
(c,n)=>[...Array(n--)].map((_,i,a)=>a.map((_,j)=>({'/':a=i+j-n,x:a&&i-j,'-':a=i+i-n,'+':a&&j+j-n,'=':a+2&&a-2}[c]?' ':c)).join(c=='='|c<'/'?' ':'')).join`\n`
```

Where `\n` represents the literal newline character.

Comment: In Firefox 49, I get `SyntaxError: invalid property id` as it's currently written, but changing the backticks around the slash to apostrophes fixed that. (Why do you have backticks there instead of apostrophes?)

Comment: Also, the outputs for `+`, `-` and `=` look different than the challenge calls for: "Horizontal portions should have spaces between the characters to offset vertical/horizontal distance differences."

Comment: @ETHproductions a) typo b) sorry, I overlooked that, will fix later.

Comment: This is ridiculously short though. I hope fixing it doesn't add too many bytes.

Comment: @ETHproductions Thanks. I think this does at a cost of 19 bytes.

Comment: An cool alternate to `c<'/'` would be `c+1-0`, not that it saves any bytes...

Answer (score 4):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), <s>91</s> 86 [bytes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

Needs `⎕IO←0`, which is default on many systems. Takes **n** as left argument, and one of **+ - × ÷ =** as right argument.

```apl
{s←⌈⍎⍕3⍵2
t←' '⍵
d←⌽∘.=⍨⍺
s∊2 6:t[d∨⌽d∧6=s]
5=s:t[↑,/2↑¨∨/¨(⌊⍺÷2)=⍳⍺ ⍺]
(2-s)(2×⍺)⍴t}
```

#### Explanation

```apl
{
    s ← ⌈ ⍎ ⍕ 3 ⍵ 2             ⍝ calculate ceil(3 f 2), where f is the given symbol
    t ← ' '⍵                    ⍝ create a string with a space before the symbol
    d ← ⌽ ∘.=⍨ ⍺                ⍝ Boolean \ diagonal
    s ∊ 2 6: t[d ∨ ⌽ d ∧ 6 = s] ⍝ if ÷ or × index t with one or both diagonals
⍝ find coordinates that are in the middle of at least one dimension
⍝ pad with zeros for spacing
⍝ use that to index into t
    5 = s: t[ ↑ ,/ 2↑¨ ∨/¨ (⌊ ⍺ ÷ 2) = ⍳ ⍺ ⍺]
⍝ - or =:
    (2 - s) (2 × ⍺) ⍴ t       ⍝ one or two rows of double-spaced symbols
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 191 bytes

```
e=#~Mod~2==1&;StringRiffle[Normal@SparseArray[{a_,b_}/;(a+b==d+1||a==b)[e@b&&a<3,,e@b&&(a==⌈d/2⌉||b==d),,e@b&&a<2,,a+b==d+1][[Last@ToCharacterCode@#~Mod~10]]:>#,{d=#2,2d-1}," "],"
"," "]&
```

Anonymous function. Takes a string and a number as input, and returns a string as output. Not the shortest by far, but still fun to write.

Answer (score 3):

## C, 396 bytes

```
#define p(x) printf(x);
i,j,k,m;f(char s,int n){i=k=0;if(s==45)for(;i<n;++i)p("- ")m=n/2;if(s==43)for(;i<n;++i)for(j=0;j<=m;++j)if(i-m)p(j-m?"  ":"+\n")else{for(;k<n;++k)p("+ ")p("\n")j+=m;}if(s==61)for(;i<2;++i){for(k=0;k<n;++k)p("= ")p("\n")}j=n;if(s==47)for(;i<n;++i){--j;for(k=0;k<j;++k)p(" ")p("/\n")}if(s==120)for(;i<n;++i){k=m-abs(m-i);for(j=0;j<n-k;++j)p(j-k?" ":"x")p(i-m?"\bx\n":"\n")}}
```

Call with:

```
int main()
{
   f('x', 5);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [SOML](https://github.com/dzaima/SOML), <s>104</s> 100 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOML/blob/master/chartable.md) (non-competing)

```
    Cd³³b»E +=?ce*d+e{t}bd*Oe{t}} ==?b*tt} -=?b*t} /=?bc*b{j:d+p}} x=?"”cb*e{jj⁴⁴d;d+++tGG;c+;}XOdoe{O
```

This is kind-of competing as I'm pretty sure that everything I used here has docs on github before this questions posting date but the parser doesn't have support for some functions I used so idk.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, <s>306</s> <s>292</s> <s>281</s> <s>282</s> <s>281</s> <s>275</s> 270 bytes

```
$r=str_pad("",2*$n=$argv[2],($c=$argv[1])." ")."\n";if(",">$c)$r=($m=str_repeat(str_pad($c,$n," ",0)."\n",$n/2))."$r$m";if(9<$c)$r.=$r;if(w<$c)for($r=$c;$i<$n;$r[$i*(2+$n)]=$r[++$i*$n-1]=x)$r[$i*$n+$i+$n]="\n";if("/"==$c)for($r=$s="";$i++<$n;$s.=" ")$r="$s/\n$r";echo$r;
```

Ooh this is bulky ... needs further golfing.
I could save 4 bytes with physical linebreaks or one byte with putting "\n" into a variable.

Comment: Nice.for the "+", I think you need to match the height and not always 3. Also you should be able golf more to use if() instead of case/break;

Answer (score 2):

## C#, 744 Bytes

*It's like 1 million characters long, I think, but I don't care, I am just so happy that I solved this...*

Golfed:

```
string A(string s,int n){string O="";Func<string,int,string>R=(a,b)=>{return string.Join("",Enumerable.Repeat(a,b))+"\r\n";};switch(s){case"+":for(int i=0;i<n;i++){if(i==n/2){O+=R("+",n);}else{O+="+".PadLeft(n-n/2,' ').PadRight(n-n/2,' ')+"\r\n";}}return O;case"=":return R("=",n)+R("=",n);case "-":return R("-",n);case "/":for(int i=n;i>0;i--){O+="/".PadLeft(i)+"\r\n";}return O;case "x":int x=0;string[]r=new string[n];for(int i=n;i>0;i--){if(n-x-x<0){O+="x".PadLeft(x+1)+"\r\n";break;}string row=string.Join("",Enumerable.Repeat(" ",x))+"x"+string.Join("",Enumerable.Repeat(" ",n-x-x))+"x"+"\r\n";O+=row;x++;r[x]=row;if(i==n/2)break;}for(int i=r.Length-1;i>0;i--){if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(r[i]))continue;O+=r[i];}return O;default:return "";}}
```

Ungolfed:

```
public string A(string s, int n)
{
  string O = "";

  Func<string, int, string> R = (a, b) =>
  {
    return string.Join("", Enumerable.Repeat(a, b)) + "\r\n";
  };

  switch (s)
  {
    case "+":
      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      {
        if (i == n / 2)
        {
          O += R("+", n);
        }
        else
        {
          O += "+".PadLeft(n - n / 2, ' ').PadRight(n - n / 2, ' ') + "\r\n";
        }
      }
      return O;
    case "=":
      return R("=", n) + R("=", n);
    case "-":
      return R("-", n);
    case "/":
      for (int i = n; i > 0; i--)
      {
        O += "/".PadLeft(i) + "\r\n";
      }
      return O;
    case "x":
      int x = 0;
      string[] r = new string[n];
      for (int i = n; i > 0; i--)
      {
        if (n - x - x < 0)
        {
          O += "x".PadLeft(x + 1) + "\r\n";
          break;
        }
        string row = string.Join("", Enumerable.Repeat(" ", x))
          + "x"
          + string.Join("", Enumerable.Repeat(" ", n - x - x)) + "x" + "\r\n";
        O += row;
        x++;
        r[x] = row;
        if (i == n / 2)
          break;
      }
      for (int i = r.Length - 1; i > 0; i--)
      {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(r[i]))
          continue;
        O += r[i];
      }
      return O;
    default:
      return "";
  }
}
```

Testing:

```
+: 3, 5, 7, 9, 11
/: 7, 8, 9, 10
-: 3, 4, 5, 6
=: 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
x: 5, 7, 9, 11
```

Too much to paste and format here, I created a pastebin:

[Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/iSeSAPmm)

Comment: Please golf it and provide a byte count.

Answer (score 2):

### C, 331 Bytes

```
i,j;f(o,n){if(47==o)for(i=n;i;puts("")){for(j=i--;j--;putchar(j?32:o)){}}
if(43==o)for(i=n;i--;puts("")){for(j=n;j--;printf(i==n/2||!j?"+ ":" ")){}}
if(45==o)for(i=n;i--;putchar(o)){}
if(61==o)for(i=3;i--;puts("")){for(j=n;j--;putchar(i&1?32:o)){}}
if(120==o)for(i=n;i;puts("")){for(j=0;j++<n;putchar(j==i||j==n-i+1?o:32)){}i--;}}
```

The operator is passed as ASCII code into `o` and the character count into `n`. I only added spaces between horizontally consecutive characters into the plus sign, since this was the only one where the output would have been distorted if I hadn't and in the task it only said "should". I use two nested loops counting down (except for `-` where I only need one line).

`=` Three Lines, one of them empty, straight forward

`+` using `printf` because of the spaces

`-` straight forward

`/` have the inner loop print at zero and start at the outer loop's counter

`x` have the inner loop print at the outer loop's counter and its "inverse" `n-i`. Still need to look at why I'am off-by-one here.

Sample call:

```
#include <stdio.h>
/*  =       61
    +       43
    -       45
    /       47
    Space   32
    x       120
*/
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    printf("%s\n%s\n",argv[1], argv[2]);
    f(*argv[1],strtol(argv[2],NULL,10));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Lua, <s>402</s> <s>344</s> 312 bytes

312:

```
r,p,b,x=string.rep,print,' ','x'function d(s,n)h,l=(n+1)/2,s..b;e=r(l,n)if s=='-'then p(e)elseif s=='='then p(e)p(e)else for f=1,n do p(s=='/'and(r(b,n-f)..s)or s=='+'and(f~=h and r(' ',n-1)..'+'or r('+ ',n))or f<h and r(b,f-1)..x..r(b,n-2*f)..x or f>h and r(b,n-f)..x..r(b,2*f-2-n)..x or r(b,f-1)..x)end end end
```

344:

```
r,p,b,x=string.rep,print,' ','x'function d(s,n)h,l=(n+1)/2,s..b;e=r(l,n)if s=='-'then p(e)elseif s=='='then p(e)p(e)else for f=1,n do if s=='/'then p(r(b,n-f)..s)elseif s=='+'then p(f~=h and r(' ',n-1)..'+'or r('+ ',n))elseif s=='x'then p(f<h and r(b,f-1)..x..r(b,n-2*f)..x or f>h and r(b,n-f)..x..r(b,2*f-2-n)..x or r(b,f-1)..x)end end end end
```

402:

```
r,p,b,x=string.rep,print,' ','x'function d(s,n)h=(n+1)/2;if s=='-'then p(r(s..b,n))end;if s=='='then p(r(s..b,n))p(r(s..b,n))end;if s=='/'then for i=1,n do p(r(b,n-i)..s)end end;if s=='+'then for i=1,n do p(i~=h and r(' ',n-1)..'+'or r('+ ',n))end end;if s=='x'then for i=1,n do if i<h then p(r(b,i-1)..x..r(b,n-2*i)..x)elseif i>h then p(r(b,n-i)..x..r(b,-n+2*i-2)..x)else p(r(b,i-1)..x)end end end end
```

90 characters reduced and it's now painful to look at even when expanded. :|

Comment: "Also looks like this is an old challenge. Oops" [There's nothing wrong with answering old challenges.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11309/anything-wrong-with-necro-bumping)