# This challenge uses the '+' character

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

Your task: given a number `n`, generate a '+' sign that is `n` characters  away from its center. If this is confusing, check out the test cases.

Standard methods of input: output must be a string or printed. Standard loopholes apply.

```
Input: 1
Output: +           ] 1 away from center `+`.

Input: 2
Output:  +          ] 2 away from center `+`.
        +++         ] 1 away from center `+`.  
         +

Input: 3
Output:   +         ] 3 away from center `+`.
          +
        +++++
          +
          +
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code wins!

Comment: I assume trailing spaces on each line are allowed so that the result is square, right?

Comment: @LuisMendo Yes, that is fine.

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/98890).

Comment: "generate a '+' sign that is n characters away from its center" -- I don't understand this part.  What center are you referring to?  How can something be eccentric to itself?  Please clarify.

Comment: @Wossname The length of each 'spoke' of the plus sign is equal to n. The + in the middle is the center, but it is considered 1 away from the center. If something is next to it, it is 2 away from the center. Anything next to that is 3 away. And so on. Try running some existing programs.

Comment: It would have been a lot less confusing if the centre were 0 away from itself.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 5 bytes

```
Ｐ+×+Ｎ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/charcoal#@/9@zwbtw9O13@9Z9/@/MQA)

Comment: What even is this language?

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Basically you can do turtle graphics ASCII art with it. It has a lot of handy builtins for rendering different kind of ASCII shapes (like `Ｐ+` = cross).

Comment: Are those not multibyte characters?

Comment: @Petah Charcoal uses a [custom codepage](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal/wiki/Code-page).

Comment: @fergusq You might be mixing Charcoal up with [Turtlèd](https://github.com/Destructible-Watermelon/Turtl-d) :P, Charcoal isn't really a turtle graphics language

Answer (score 29):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 53 bytes

```python
n=2*input()-1;C='+'.center
for c in C(n):print C(n,c)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@59na6SVmVdQWqKhqWto7Wyrrq2ul5yaV5JaxJWWX6SQrJCZp@CskadpVVCUmVcCYuoka/7/bwwA)

Answer (score 14):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>67</s> <s>65</s> <s>63</s> <s>60</s> 59 bytes

```js
x=>(v=(` `[r=`repeat`](--x)+`+
`)[r](x))+`+`[r](x*2)+`+
`+v;
```

- 2 bytes saved by replacing two occurrences of `x-1`, the first with `--x` and the second with `x`.
- 2 bytes saved thanks to [Kritixi Lithos](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41805/kritixi-lithos), replacing `"\n"` with `` `[newline]` ``.
- 3 bytes saved thanks to [user2428118](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/13486/user2428118), finally helping me to figure out a way to alias the `repeat` in a way that reduced the size. (With honourable mention to [Marie](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67066/marie) for her efforts, too)
- 1 byte saved indirectly thanks to Herman.

---

### Try It

```js
f=
x=>(v=(` `[r=`repeat`](--x)+`+
`)[r](x))+`+`[r](x*2)+`+
`+v;
oninput=_=>o.innerText=f(+i.value)
o.innerText=f(i.value=3)
```

```html
<input id=i min=1 type=number><pre id=o>
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I think you can replace the `"\n"` with two backticks and a literal newline between them

Comment: Thanks, @KritixiLithos; don't know why I didn't think of that sooner myself.

Comment: It looks like you could probably save a byte by aliasing repeat, e.g. `a='repeat',v=.....` and `\` \`[a]`

Comment: Thanks, @Marie; I had tried aliasing `repeat()` but my first few attempts came out 2 or 3 bytes bigger so I abandoned it! I'll have another look at it when I get back in front of a computer.

Comment: I see. I did think it would save a bit more but it looks like one byte. An easy comparison is basically `a='repeat',[a][a][a]` vs `.repeat.repeat.repeat`, 20 vs 21 respectively.

Comment: Just tried it myself now quickly, @Marie, but the best I could manage was to match the current byte count. I've included them as alternatives above in case someone can see something I might have missed.

Comment: This was how I did it, minus the line breaks ```x=>(a='repeat',v=(` `[a](--x)+`+`)[a](x))+`+`[a](x*2+1)+``+v```

Comment: ````x=>(v=(` `[r='repeat'](--x)+`+<newline>`)[r](x))+`+`[r](x*2+1)+`<newline>`+v````

Comment: Sweet! Thanks, @user2428118. Guess I couldn't see the wood for the trees!

Comment: @Shaggy I'm very new in this community. How do you event count generated bytes?

Answer (score 12):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 11 bytes

```
tZv=&+g43*c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@18SVWarpp1uYqyV/P@/MQA)

#### Explanation with example

Consider `n = 3`.

```
t     % Implicitly input n. Duplicate
      % STACK: 3, 3
Zv    % Symmetric range
      % STACK: 3, [1 2 3 2 1]
=     % Equal, element-wise
      % STACK: [0 0 1 0 0]
&+    % All pair-wise additions. Gives a 2D array
      % STACK: [0 0 1 0 0;
                0 0 1 0 0;
                1 1 2 1 1;
                0 0 1 0 0;
                0 0 1 0 0]
g     % Logical: convert non-zero to one
      % STACK: [0 0 1 0 0;
                0 0 1 0 0;
                1 1 1 1 1;
                0 0 1 0 0;
                0 0 1 0 0]
43*   % Multiply by 43 (ASCII for '+'), element-wise
      % STACK: [ 0  0 43  0  0;
                 0  0 43  0  0;
                43 43 43 43 43;
                 0  0 43  0  0;
                 0  0 43  0  0]
c     % Convert to char. Char 0 is displayed as space. Implicitly display.
      % STACK: ['  +  ';
                '  +  ';
                '+++++';
                '  +  ';
                '  +  ']
```

Answer (score 8):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>16</s> 13 bytes

```
Ｎα×+α←↑×+α‖Ｏ↘
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/charcoal#@/9@z7pzGw9P1z638VHbhEdtEyHMhmnv96x/1Dbj/39jAA)

Uses a different approach from the other Charcoal answer.

#### Explanation

```
Ｎα                       # Take input and store it in variable α
×+α                       # α times write a +
←                         # Go left
↑×+α                      # α times write a + upwards
```

Now the top left corner is complete, it will look something like this:

```
  +
  +
+++

‖Ｏ↘                      # Reflect-overlap it in a SE direction
```

The last step is the key to this program, it uses the top-left part of the plus to generate the rest of the plus by reflecting it in the southeast direction (rightwards and downwards).

Comment: Does Charcoal have its own code page? Many of those characters are multiple bytes in UTF-8.

Comment: @TRiG Yes, [it does](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal/wiki/Code-page)!

Comment: This can be simplified to `×+Ｎ‖Ｏ<`.

Answer (score 8):

## [Shakespeare Programming Language](https://github.com/TryItOnline/spl), <s>749</s> <s>743</s> <s>666</s> 625 bytes

```
N.Puck,.Page,.Ford,.Ajax,.Act I:.Scene I:.[Enter Puck and Ford]Puck:Listen tothy!Ford:You is the difference betweena cat I.Scene V:.[Exeunt][Enter Page and Ajax]Ajax:You is the difference betweena cat Ford.Scene X:.Page:You is the product ofPuck I.Is you as big as zero?If soyou is the sum oftwice the sum oftwice twice the sum ofa big big cat a cat a cat a cat.If notyou big big big big big cat.Speak thy!Ajax:You is the sum ofyou a cat.Is you worse Ford?If soLet usScene X.Page:You is twice the sum ofa big big cat a cat.Speak thy![Exit Page][Enter Puck]Ajax:You is the sum ofyou a cat.Is you worse Ford?If soLet usScene V.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVHBasMwDP0V7R582S2XsUMHgTIKhbJRfHAdpfXa2cGWSbOfzywnZVl22A47WLZk6b0nKbSXYXgWm6jPhdioIxbiyfm6EI9v6pqsJqhKsdVokR/7lSX0wOmgbA2cK9kr1yYQWiBHp/6Ow@Wri2AC0AmhNk2DHq1GOCB1iFaBVgl6Qt4x8hWjJXljSFIyA@uQbP6Cx7wT5EuZ25lXtd7VMTXkmqy/ElWAPn2rAAdz5OsDvXuoGgiu/yoL8T2VUGcS2w9/EVUZiQ/LUUsrErZ1xOC3vPnhjG2L6gw8xGXTI0MWPGKN6jvnA@bOR@VrJIhhGsL3GfwudkafFmIo70HOti7/QdVODMP9Jw)

With added newlines:

```
N.
Puck,.
Page,.
Ford,.
Ajax,.
Act I:.
Scene I:.
[Enter Puck and Ford]
Puck:Listen tothy!
Ford:You is the difference betweena cat I.
Scene V:.
[Exeunt]
[Enter Page and Ajax]
Ajax:You is the difference betweena cat Ford.
Scene X:.
Page:You is the product ofPuck I.Is you as big as zero?
If soYou is the sum ofTwice the sum ofTwice twice the sum ofA big big cat a cat a cat a cat.
If notyou big big big big big cat.Speak thy!
Ajax:You is the sum ofyou a cat.Is you worse Ford?If soLet usScene X.
Page:You is twice the sum ofa big big cat a cat.Speak thy!
[Exit Page]
[Enter Puck]
Ajax:You is the sum ofyou a cat.Is you worse Ford?If soLet usScene V.
```

Golfed 6 bytes because scene numbers don't have to be consecutive. Golfed some more bytes by applying the tips in the new answers to the [Shakespeare tips question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/48855/), **though these golfs aren't reflected in the explanation**.

### (Slightly outdated) explaination

SPL is an esolang designed to look like Shakespeare plays. Positive nouns have the value of 1 (here **cat** is used) and negative nouns have the value of -1 (none were used but **pig** is one of them). Adjectives modify a constant by multiplying it by 2.

```
N.
```

Everything until the first dot is the title and doesn't matter.

```
Puck,.                           row counter
Page,.                           column counter
Ford,.                           input
Ajax,.                           temp
```

The characters are integer variables, each of them also has a stack but I did not need to use that feature.

```
Act I:.
Scene I:.
```

Acts and scenes are used as goto labels

```
[Enter Puck and Ford]
```

It's only useful if exactly two characters are on the stage at the same time.

```
Puck:Listen to thy heart!
```

Reads a number and makes Ford remember it.

```
Ford:You is the difference between a cat and I.
```

As you can see Engrish is valid in SPL. This makes Puck's value "the different between a cat and I". But what does it mean? `cat` is a positive noun, so it's `Puck = 1 - Ford`.

```
Scene II:.
[Exeunt]
```

Exeunt is just a plural of "exit", and without arguments means that everyone on the stage exits.

```
[Enter Page and Ajax]
Ajax:You is the difference between a cat and Ford.
```

It's also `Page = 1 - Ford` but it's spoken by a different actor so `I` would be wrong. Since it's a loop, I can't just copy the value of `Puck`.

```
Scene III:.
Page:You is the product of Puck and I.
```

Pretty straightforward by now. `Ajax = Puck * Page`.

```
Is you as big as zero?
```

"as [adj] as" is the `==` operator.

```
If so,you is the sum of the sum of the sum of a big big big big big cat and a big big big cat and a big cat and a cat.
```

If Ajax == 0... "cat" is 1, "big cat" is 2, "big big cat" is 4 and so on. After substituting the simple constants we get "the sum of the sum of the sum of 32 and 8 and 2 and 1" -> "the sum of the sum of 40 and 2 and 1" -> "the sum of 42 and 1" -> "43", which is the ASCII for +.

```
If not,you fat fat fat fat fat cat.
```

else it's just "fat fat fat fat fat cat", so Ajax gets the value of 32, the ASCII for a space.

```
Speak thy mind!
```

This is the command for outputting a character.

```
Ajax:
You sum you and cat.Is you as big as Ford?If not,let us return to Scene III.
```

This is a loop construct. "You sum you and cat" increments Page, and `if(Page != Ford) goto Scene III`. The rest of the program uses the same components, so here is a more readable pseudocode version:

```
Scene1:
    input = [input number];
    row = 0 - input + 1;
Scene2:
    col = 0 - input + 1;
Scene3:
    temp = row * col;
    if(temp == 0){
        temp = '+';
    }else{
        temp = ' ';
    }

    putchar(temp);
    Page = Page + 1;
    if(Page != Ford) goto Scene3;
    Ajax = 10;
    putchar(Ajax);
    Puck = Puck + 1;
    if(Puck != Ford) goto Scene2;
```

Comment: "`If not,let us return to Scene III.`" -1; breaks fourth wall :P

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 bytes

```
ṬŒB»þ`ị⁾+ Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#ARkA5v//4bmsxZJCwrvDvmDhu4vigb4rIFn///8z)

Comment: _fingers crossed_ :-P

Answer (score 6):

### Mathematica, 39 bytes

```
Print@@@(CrossMatrix[#-1]"+"/. 0->" ")&
```

`CrossMatrix` is a built-in that generates a matrix of the required shape with `1`s instead of `+`s and `0`s instead of spaces. If we multiply that matrix by `"+"`, that replaces the `1`s with `+`s while leaving the `0`s unchanged (obviously... `0*x = 0` and `1*x = x`, right?). Then we replace the zeros manually with spaces using `/. 0->" "`. Finally, we print each line of the matrix with `Print@@@(...)`.

Comment: Didn't know `Print` could be used like that.

Answer (score 5):

## C, 69 bytes

Not very interesting... Loops over the square, printing out the appropriate character.

```
r,c;f(n){for(r=-n;++r<n;puts(""))for(c=-n;++c<n;putchar(r*c?32:43));}
```

Answer (score 5):

## [GNU sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), <s>104</s> 99 bytes

-5 thanks to [seshoumara](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59010/seshoumara)
Includes +1 for `-r`

```
s/1//;h;:;s/(.*)1/ \12/;t;s/( *2)2(2*)/\1\n\1\2/
t;G;s/1+/&&1/;s/(.*)(\n1*)/&\n\1/;/1/!c+
y/12/++/
```

Takes input in [unary.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5343/can-numeric-input-output-be-in-unary?answertab=votes#tab-top)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/sed#LYw7DoMwEER7TgEN8kdkNFtmD5BLWDQ0UMRE2A2Xj7MRFFOM5s1rBQR01acWuEfwRJ8o0Gp9dn0QL06CR2LKFsG7q/qykRHjSNw3lzIvSv4c1LTDErsTJosRrZH87p@67bm06fgB)

```
s/1//                    # Subtract 1 from input
h                        # Hold onto input
:                        # Start loop
s/(.*)1/ \12/            #   Remove a 1, prepend a space, and append a 2
t                        # Loop until all 1s are 2s
                         # Start Loop (uses the previous label)
s/( *2)2(2*)/\1\n\1\2/   #   Shift all but the first 2 from the last line to a new line 
                         #   E.g.  "  2"      "  2"
                         #         "  222" -> "  2"
                         #                    "  22"
t                        # Loop until all 2s are on their own line
G                        # Append a newline and input
s/1+/&&1/                # Double the number of 1s and append an extra
s/(.*)(\n1*)/&\n\1/      # Copy all of the lines with 2s to the end
/1/!c+                   # If there aren't any 1s print a '+'
y/12/++/                 # Convert all 1s and 2s to +s
```

Comment: +1 You can save 5 bytes by using `s/( *2)2(2*)/\1\n\1\2/` and `s/(.*)(\n1*)/&\n\1/` as shown [here](https://tio.run/nexus/sed#LYw7DoAwDEN3TlGWqh@BlYzkAFyiGwssBdEuXJ6SSljyYPnZrYAA2WWRAjcHTzCJGFJ7NoE9Ow4eiVJWM4Yqq1YUYS3hH7mUSSHbGYg@jlscHuhPjGiNut7zqseZS5vuDw), for a total score of 99.

Answer (score 5):

## Ruby, <del>41</del> 40 bytes

```ruby
->x{puts k=[?\s*(r=x-1)+?+]*r,?+*r+=x,k}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#S7ON@a9rV1FdUFpSrJBtG20fU6ylUWRboWuoqW2vHatVpGOvrVWkbVuhk137X8NQT89UUy83sUBBLe0/AA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 52 bytes

```python
n=input()-1
p=(' '*n+'+\n')*n
print p+'++'*n+'+\n'+p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@59nm5lXUFqioalryFVgq6GuoK6Vp62uHZOnrqmVx1VQlJlXolAAFNCGi2sX/P9vDAA)

A 53-byte alternative ([TIO](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@59nm5lXUFqioalryJWWX6SQrJCZp66grpWnrQ6CIJZVQVFmXolCMlQMSP//bwwA)):

```python
n=input()-1
for c in' '*n+'+'+' '*n:print c*n+'+'+c*n
```

Answer (score 5):

**R, 54 bytes**

Shaving off 7 bytes thanks to @Jarko Dubbeldam:

```
function(n){a=matrix("",y<-n*2-1,y);a[n,]=a[,n]="x";a}
```

previous answer:

```
f=function(n){a=matrix("",n*2-1,n*2-1);a[n,]="x";a[,n]="x";a}
```

Comment: You don't have to name functions, so `function(n){a=matrix("",n*2-1,n*2-1);a[n,]="x";a[,n]="x";a}` would be 59 bytes!

Comment: Also, you can save a byte using `matrix("",y<-n*2-1,y)`

Comment: `a[n,]=a[,n]="x"` works too, saving some more bytes.

Comment: You can save another 4 bytes by using `scan()` and making it a program rather than a function: `n=scan();a=matrix("",y<-n*2-1,y);a[n,]=a[,n]="+";a`

Answer (score 4):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 48 bytes

```powershell
param($n)($x=,(" "*--$n+"+")*$n);'+'*(1+2*$n);$x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/powershell#@1@QWJSYq6GSp6mhUmGro6GkoKSlq6uSp62kraSpBRS2VtdW19Iw1DYCc1Qq/v//bwIA)

Takes input `$n`. Starts by constructing a string of `--$n` spaces, concatenated with `+`. That's converted into an array using the comma operator, (newly-decremented) `$n` times. That array is stored in `$x` and encapsulated in parens to place a copy on the pipeline.

We then do the middle section, which is `+` string multiplied out the appropriate number of times. That's left on the pipeline. Finally, we put `$x` on the pipeline again.

Those are all left on the pipeline at program completion, and the implicit `Write-Output` inserts a newline between elements.

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2, 65 bytes

```py
lambda n:('g+\n'*~-n+'+'*~-(2*n)+'\ng+'*~-n).replace('g',' '*~-n)
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#S7ON@Z@TmJuUkqiQZ6Whnq4dk6euVaebp62uDaI1jLTyNLXVY/LSwdw8Tb2i1IKcxORUoFJ1HXUFiOD/gqLMvBKFNA1jTS4Y01TzPwA)

Answer (score 4):

### [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 23 bytes

```
ri_(S*'++a\2*(*_z..e>N*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@1@UGa8RrKWurZ0YY6SloRVfpaeXauen9f@/KQA)

#### Explanation

This feels a bit suboptimal, but the idea is to superimpose the following two grids:

```
  +
  +
  +
  +
  +
```

```
+++++
```

Which gives the desired result.

```
ri    e# Read input and convert to integer N.
_(    e# Duplicate and decrement.
S*    e# Get a string of N-1 spaces (indentation of the vertical bar).
'++   e# Append a + (the vertical bar).
a     e# Wrap the line in an array.
\2*(  e# Swap with the other copy of N and compute 2N-1.
*     e# Repeat the line that many times.
_z    e# Duplicate the grid and transpose it.
..e>  e# Pairwise maximum between the two grids. This superimposes them.
N*    e# Join with linefeeds.
```

Answer (score 4):

## Lua <s>113</s>, 90 bytes

```
r,w,p=string.rep,io.read(),io.write;s=r(' ',w-1)p(r(s..'+'..'\n',w-1))p(r('+',w*2-1)..'\n')p(r(s..'+'..'\n',w-1))
```

```
r,w=string.rep,io.read()d=w*2-1;for a=1,d do print(a~=w and r(' ',w-1)..'+'or r('+',d))end
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>60,</s>56 bytes

```python
n=input()-1
z=(' '*n+'+\n')*n
print z+'+'*(2*n+1)+'\n'+z
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@59nm5lXUFqioalryFVlq6GuoK6Vp62uHZOnrqmVx1VQlJlXolAFFFDX0jACyhhqaqsD5bSr/v83BgA)

- -4 bytes - thanks to math junkie!

Comment: Save 4 bytes like this: [TIO](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@59nm5lXUFqioalryFVlq6GuoK6Vp62uHZOnrqmVx1VQlJlXolAFFFDX0jACyhhqaqsD5bSr/v83AwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 45 bytes

44 bytes of code + `-p` flag.

```perl
$_=join"+
",@%=($"x--$_)x$_,"+"x($_*2),@%,""
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/perl5#U1YsSC3KUdAt@K8Sb5uVn5mnpM2lpOOgaquholShq6sSr1mhEq@jpK1UoaESr2WkCZTSUVL6/9@Qy5jLlMsSAA)

---

Some similar (but still different) approaches:

48 bytes (47+`-p`):

```perl
$_=join"+"x($_*2-1).$/,(~~($"x--$_."+\n")x$_)x2
```

50 bytes (49+`-n`):

```perl
$,="+"x($_*2-1).$/;print+(~~($"x--$_."+\n")x$_)x2
```

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>15</s> <s>14</s> 12 bytes

```
F'+}¹·<×)û.c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@@@mrl17aOeh7TaHp2se3q2X/P@/MQA)

**-2 thanks to Emigna.**

Comment: You could do `F'+}¹·<×)û.c` for 12.

Comment: Your try it online link is bad - it doesn't link to the current revision of the post so it shows "bad output" that doesn't match the test cases above.

Comment: @ThomasWard: Good catch! I corrected the link.

Comment: `F'+}¹×û)û.c` for [11 bytes](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fTV279tDOw9MP79Y8vFsv@f9/YwA).

Answer (score 3):

## CJam, 17

```
ri(S*_]'+*_ffe>N*
```

[Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=ri(S*_%5D'%2B*_ffe%3EN*&input=3)

**Explanation:**

```
ri(      read n, convert to int and decrement
S*       make a string of n-1 spaces
_]       duplicate it and put the 2 strings in an array
'+*_     join the strings with a '+' and duplicate the result
ffe>     for each pair of characters from the 2 (identical) strings,
          get the larger character (results in a matrix)
N*       join the rows with newlines
```

Answer (score 3):

## Octave, <s>36</s> 31 bytes

Inspired by @LuisMendo 's MATL answer.

```
@(n)' +'(((a=1:n*2-1==n)|a')+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/octave#@@@gkaeprqCtrqGhkWhraJWnZaRraGubp1mTqK6pbaj5PzGvWMNU8z8A)

Previous answer:

```
@(n)' +'(1+((a=padarray(1,n-1))|a'))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/octave#@@@gkaeprqCtrmGoraGRaFuQmJJYVJRYqWGok6drqKlZk6iuqfk/Ma9Yw1TzPwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), <s>19</s> <s>18</s> 15 bytes

*Golfed 3 bytes thanks to @nmjcman101 by using `.` and `Ò+`*

```
Àé r+À«Ä.MgJxÒ+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@3@44fBKhSLtww2HVh9u0fNN96o4PEn7////xgA)

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@3@44fBKhSLtww2HVh9u0fNN96o4PEn7////pgA "V – TIO Nexus")

Answer (score 2):

## JS (ES6), <s>88</s> <s>74</s> 73 bytes

```
x=>(x--,y=y=>(" ".repeat(x)+`+
`).repeat(x),y``+"+".repeat(x+x+1)+"\n"+y``)
```

Probably can be golfed more.

```js
Snippetify(x=>(x--,y=y=>(" ".repeat(x)+`+
`).repeat(x),y``+"+".repeat(x+x+1)+"\n"+y``))
```

```html
<script src="https://programmer5000.com/snippetify.min.js"></script>
<input type = "number">
<pre data-output></pre>
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I think you can replace the `"\n"` with two backticks and a literal newline between them

Comment: Only seeing this solution now, you beat me by a few minutes. What's the etiquette around here on similar solutions in the same language that are posted within a small window of time?

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 68 Bytes

```
for(;$i<$c=-1+2*$m=$argn;)echo"\n".str_pad("+",$c," +"[$m==++$i],2);
```

83 Bytes

```
for(;$i<($c=($n=$argn)*2-1)**2;)echo$i%$c?"":"\n".!++$k," +"[$k==$n|$i++%$c==$n-1];
```

Comment: You can save a few bytes by using `$m=$argn` and pre-incrementing `$i` rather than post incrementing it. you can also save a byte by moving the `$m` assignment ot the end and dropping the brackets.

Comment: @user59178 I could not understand what you exactly mean

Comment: `for(;$i<$c=-1+2*$m=$argn;)echo"\n".str_pad("+",$c," +"[$m==++$i],2);`

Comment: `while(++$y<2*$n=$argn)echo"\n",str_pad("+",$n*2-1," +"[$y==$n],2);` 66 bytes (and save one more with a physical linebreak)

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), 60 bytes

```js
f=
n=>(r=([s,t])=>(s=s.repeat(n-1))+t+s+`
`)([r(` +`),r(`++`)])
```

```html
<input type=number min=1 oninput=o.textContent=f(this.value)><pre id=o>
```

Outputs two trailing newlines. Alternative formulation, also 60 bytes:

```
n=>(r=a=>(s=a[0].repeat(n-1))+a[1]+s+`
`)([r(` +`),r(`++`)])
```

Answer (score 2):

### Batch, 108 bytes

```
@set p=+
@set l=@for /l %%i in (2,1,%1)do @
%l%call set p= %%p%% 
%l%echo %p%
@echo %p: =+%
%l%echo %p%
```

Note: Line 3 ends in a space.

Answer (score 2):

## MUMPS, 48 <s>50</s> <s>53</s> bytes

```
F i=1-n:1:n-1 W ! F j=1-n:1:n-1 W $C(i&j*-11+43)
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Answer (score 2):

## PowerShell, 48

Doesn't seem to get shorter than that (and pretty much the same approach as the other solution):

```
($a=,(' '*($n="$args"-1)+'+')*$n)
'+'+'++'*$n
$a
```

or

```
($a=(' '*($n="$args"-1)+'+
')*$n)+'++'*$n+"+
$a"
```

Answer (score 2):

### REXX, 81 bytes

```
arg a
b=a*2-1
do i=1 to b
  if i=a then say copies('+',b)
  else say right('+',a)
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 216 + 1 = 217 bytes

*+1 bytes from the `-A` flag*

```
([{}]())(()()){<>(((((()()()()()){})){}()){}())<>(({}[()])<({}<(({})){({}()<(({}<<>(({}<(({})<>)>)<>)<>>)<{({}()<(((((()()){}){}){}){})>)}{}>)>)}{}>){(<{}(({}<<>({}<({}<>)>)>)<(({}){}){({}()<(({}))>)}{}>)>)}{}>)}{}{}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#XU3JDcAwCFvHfvTVL0LqHFEmQcxOIVelhtgJsjGBZt5BAkw2UYzDXTQvYFHp5g3slPxIdSmhxNHIdExBlFokmjimlV/J5yrdXPdjkPSutApLlKhzx5j5VvI3nWQeccf1vA)

### Explanation to come

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <strike>30 26</strike> 24 bytes

23 bytes of code, +1 for the `-R` flag.

Saved 4 bytes thanks to @ETHproductions!

```
V=U+´UVÇ¦U?SpU +'+:'+pV
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@x9mG6p9aEto2OH2Q8tC7YMLQhW01bWt1LULwv7/N1bQDQIA)

Comment: I think you can save a bunch by doing `V=U+´U` at the beginning and removing all those pesky `-1`s ;-)

Comment: @ETHproductions Great idea, thanks! I saved another byte by using `Ç`

Comment: And another byte by switching to `¦`

Answer (score 2):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 27 bytes

```
~.(." "*"+"n++*.@2*("+"*n+\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v05PQ09JQUlLSVspT1tbS8/BSEsDyNbK0475/98YAA)

Explanation and Example Execution:

```
                              # Input: 3
~.(.                          # Eval input, duplicate twice, decrement duplicates
                              # Stack: 3 2 2
    " "*                      # That many spaces
                              # Stack: 3 2 "  "
        "+"n++                # Followed by a + and a newline
                              # Stack: 3 2 "  +\n"
              *.              # Create n of those strings and duplicate it
                              # Stack: 3 "  +\n  +\n" "  +\n  +\n"
                @2*(          # Pull bottom to top, double it, decrement
                              # Stack: "  +\n  +\n" "  +\n  +\n" 5
                    "+"*n+    # That many +s followed by a newline
                              # Stack: "  +\n  +\n" "  +\n  +\n" "+++++\n"
                          \   # Swap last 2 items and implicityly print
                              # Stack: "  +\n  +\n" "+++++\n" "  +\n  +\n"
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vim](https://www.vim.org), 36 bytes

```
<C-x>D@-i <esc>Y@-pVGy:1s/ /+/g
P:%s/.*/&+&
```

The byte-count includes a trailing newline. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/38ZZt8LOxUE3U8EmtTjZLtJBtyDMvdLKsFhfQV9bP50rwEq1WF9PS19NW43r/3@T/7plAA)

#### Explanation

```
<C-x>D
```

Decrement the input number `n` and delete it. The deleted text is stored in the "small deletion" register `"-`.

```
@-i <esc>
```

Insert a space `"-` times.

```
Y@-p
```

Yank that line, and then paste it `"-` times. We now have `n` lines of `n-1` spaces each, with the cursor at the beginning of line 2.

```
VGy
```

Select all lines till the end of the file (i.e. `n-1` lines, all but the first one) and yank them.

```
:1s/ /+/g
```

On line 1, replace each space with a plus sign. This command leaves the cursor on line 1.

```
P
```

Paste the previously yanked lines above the current line. We now have `n-1` lines of spaces, one line of plus signs, and `n-1` more lines of spaces.

```
:%s/.*/&+&
```

Replace each line with itself followed by a plus sign followed by itself again.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyke](https://github.com/muddyfish/PYKE), 14 bytes

```
t.\+s FQt*\++s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/pyke#@1@iF6NdrOAWWKIVo61d/P@/EQA)

Answer (score 1):

### [J](http://www.jsoftware.com/), 21 bytes

```
' +'{~+./~(0=}.,])i.n
```

Answer (score 1):

## 8086 machine code, 57 bytes

```
00000000  a0 82 00 24 cf 98 48 89  c1 b4 4c e3 20 bf 39 01  |...$..H...L. .9.|
00000010  57 51 5a 52 51 b0 20 89  d1 f3 aa b8 2b 0a ab 59  |WQZRQ. .....+..Y|
00000020  e2 f2 c6 05 24 59 01 c9  b4 09 5a cd 21 41 b0 2b  |....$Y....Z.!A.+|
00000030  cd 29 e2 fa 4a cd 21 c3  0a                       |.)..J.!..|
00000039
```

Takes a number (one digit...) as command line argument.
How it works:

```
            |   use16
a0 82 00    |       mov al, byte [0x82]
24 cf       |       and al, not 0x30
98          |       cbw
48          |       dec ax
89 c1       |       mov cx, ax
b4 4c       |       mov ah, 0x4c
e3 20       |       jcxz a
bf 39 01    |       mov di, s+1
57          |       push di
51          |       push cx
5a          |       pop dx
52          |       push dx
51          |   @@: push cx
b0 20       |       mov al, ' '
89 d1       |       mov cx, dx
f3 aa       |       rep stosb
b8 2b 0a    |       mov ax, 0x0a2b
ab          |       stosw
59          |       pop cx
e2 f2       |       loop @b
c6 05 24    |       mov byte [di], 0x24
59          |       pop cx
01 c9       |       add cx, cx
b4 09       |       mov ah, 0x09
5a          |       pop dx
cd 21       |       int 0x21
41          |   a:  inc cx
b0 2b       |   @@: mov al, '+'
cd 29       |       int 0x29
e2 fa       |       loop @b
4a          |       dec dx
cd 21       |       int 0x21
c3          |       ret
0a          |   s db 0x0a
```

Answer (score 1):

## Rust, 89 bytes

```
|n|{for i in 1..2*n{if i==n{println!("{:+^1$}","",2*n-1)}else{println!("{:>1$}","+",n)}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
'+90Λ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9fXdvS4Nzs//@NAQ)

Comment: [4 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fXdvl3Oz//40B) (and non-competing is no longer a thing)

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 17 bytes

Anonymous tacit prefix function

```
' +'{~0=*/~@i:@<:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P83WSkFdQVu9us7AVku/ziHTysHG6n9qcka@QppCamJyhoKhgpGC8X8A)

For example for `3`:

`<:` decrement; `2`

`i:` steps; `[-2,-1,0,1,2]`

`*/~` times table; `[[4,2,0,-2,-4],[2,1,0,-1,-2],[0,0,0,0,0],[-2,-1,0,1,2],[-4,-2,0,2,4]]`

`0=` indicate where zero; `[[0,0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,0,0],[1,1,1,1,1],[0,0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,0,0]]`

`" +"{~` use that to index into `" +"`; `["  +  ","  +  ","+++++","  +  ","  +  "]`

Answer (score 1):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), <s>39</s> 37 bytes

```
;(:|:⑬*,\+,
,):⑨⑵;`+`*,
,(:|:⑬*,\+,
,
```

*-2 bytes using built-ins*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N///fWsOqxurRxDVaOjHaOlw6mkD2ikcTt1onaCdoAfmosv//GwMA)

This attempt prints the isolated +s first, then the big row of +s then the final isolated +s.

Answer (score 1):

## [Wren](https://github.com/munificent/wren), 67 bytes

```
Fn.new{|n|(1...2*n).map{|i|i==n?"+"*(n+~-n):" "*~-n+"+"}.join("
")}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky9KzftfllikkFaal6xgq/DfLU8vL7W8uiavRsNQT0/PSCtPUy83saC6JrMm09Y2z15JW0lLI0@7TjdP00pJQUkLyNAGitXqZeVn5mkocSlp1v4PriwuSc3VKy/KLEnVABmsl5yYk6NhpKn5HwA)

### Explanation

```
Fn.new{|n|                                                      // New anonymous function with parameter n
          (1...2*n).map{|i|                                     // Foreach 1 -> 2n-1:
                           i==n?                                // If i equals n:
                                "+"*(n+~-n)                     // Return "+" 2n-1 times
                                           :" "*~-n             // Otherwise return space n-1 times
                                                   +"+"         // Add a trailing "+"
                                                       }.join("
")}                                                             // Join with newline
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 47 bytes

```powershell
param($n)($x=,(' '*--$n+'+')*$n)
'+'+'++'*$n
$x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkqZgq1D9vyCxKDFXQyVPU0OlwlZHQ11BXUtXVyVPW11bXVMLKMylDmJqa6sDOVwqFf9rubjUgFoNudTVwQwjGMP4PwA)

This one is shorter than [48](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/116215/80745) [bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/116117/80745) `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `C`, 12 bytes

```
\+*÷:?d›*Wøm
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=C&code=%5C%2B*%C3%B7%3A%3Fd%E2%80%BA*W%C3%B8m&inputs=3&header=&footer=)

-2 thanks to @astonearachnid.
-1 thanks to lyxal.

Comment: 13 bytes: [Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=C&code=%28%5C%2B%29%E2%81%B0d%E2%80%BA%5C%2B*W%C3%B8m&inputs=3&header=&footer=)

Comment: [12 bytes](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=C&code=%5C%2B*%C3%B7%3A%3Fd%E2%80%BA*W%C3%B8m&inputs=3&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 1):

## [Regenerate](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Regenerate) `-a`, 38 bytes

```
(({2,$~1} |\+|{2,$~1} )$2{$~1-2}!)\+$1
```

Takes input as a command-line argument. [Try it here!](https://replit.com/@dloscutoff/regenerate)

#### Explanation

Here, we're going to (ab)use Regenerate's backtracking algorithm. The regex describes several possibilities for a single line, and the `-a` flag instructs Regenerate to output all possible matches. I'm going to start with a slightly different version that doesn't work for input \$n=1\$, and then discuss how to deal with that corner case afterwards.

Space is represented by underscore for better visibility.

```
(({2,$~1} |\+|{2,$~1} )$2{$~1-2})\+$1
(                               )      Group 1: the part before the central + character:
                                       either n-1 spaces or n-1 + characters
 (                    )                 Group 2: which character to use
                                         Option 1:
  {2,$~1}                                 Repeat empty string between 2 and n times
                                          (this causes the backtracker to try n-1 different
                                          options, all of them equal to empty string)
         _                                followed by space
          |                              Option 2:
           \+                             + character
             |                           Option 3:
              {2,$~1}_                    Same deal as option 1
                       $2               Group 2 again...
                         {$~1-2}        ... repeated n-2 times, for a total of n-1
                                 \+    The central + character
                                   $1  followed by group 1 again
```

When backtracking over group 2, Regenerate will try space \$n-1\$ times, then `+`, then space another \$n-1\$ times. So the list of all possible matches will be \$n-1\$ lines of spaces with a `+` in the middle, one line of `+` characters with a + in the middle, and \$n-1\$ more lines of spaces with a `+` in the middle--exactly the output we want.

There is a problem with \$n=1\$, however. We want group 1 to match the empty string, so that the only possible match for the full regex is `+`. However, with input of \$1\$, group 1 *fails* to match. The culprit is `$2{$~1-2}`, "repeat group 2's contents \$n-2\$ times." It's not possible to repeat something \$-1\$ times, so the whole group fails.

We can get around this failure by providing empty string as another alternative inside group 1. However, using `|` here raises another issue: we don't want the empty string to be tried if the first alternative succeeded, only if it failed. (Since we're asking for *all* possible matches, we would get a stray `+` at the end of the output for \$n>1\$.)

The solution is to use `!`, a greedy version of `|`. If its left side matches at all, it takes the left side's match(es) and never tries the right side. It only tries the right side if its left side fails entirely. Thus, our final solution is:

```
((...)$2{$~1-2}!)\+$1
(               )      Group 1: the part before the central + character
 (...)                  Group 2: same options as before
      $2{$~1-2}         Repeat group 2 again n-2 times
               !        Or, iff that fails because n-2 < 0...
                        Empty string
                 \+    The central + character
                   $1  followed by group 1 again
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>26</s> 25 bytes

```
ＮηＡ⁻η¹η××η²+Ｐ+Ｍη↙Ｇ↑⁺¹×η²+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/charcoal#@/9@z7pz29/vWfiocfe57Yd2ntt@ePrh6UDWJu33ezYA8dpz2x@1zXy/Z/mjtomPGncd2gmV/f/fGAA)

**Explanation:**

```
Ｎη                   // Take the size as input.
Ａ⁻η¹η                // Set η to η-1.
××η²+                // Print '+' η*2 times.
Ｐ+                   // Print '+'
Ｍη↙                 // Move η steps down to the left.
Ｇ↑⁺¹×η²+            // Print '+' η*2+1 times upwards from current position.
```

Answer (score 0):

## Common Lisp, SBCL, 69 bytes

```
(format t"~@?~@?~@?+
~@*~@?""~v@{~:*~v@t+
~}"(1-(read))"~1@*~v@{+~}")
```

#### Explanation

```
format        ;printing function
~@?           ;execute current argument as format string 
~@*           ;go to first argument in list, to reuse "~v@{~:*~v@t+
              ;~}"
~v@{~}        ;loop n times, where n is current argument
~:*           ;go back one argument - to reuse (1-(read))
~v@t          ;add n spaces where n is current argument
              ;if we were sure that we start on new line we could
              ;use ~vt, which moves to nth column
(1-(read))    ;take input and subtract 1 from it
~1@*          ;move to second argument, to reuse (1-(read))

"~@?~@?~@?+   ;main format string - calls others
~@*~@?"       ;prints one "+" and one newline
"~v@{~:*~v@t+ ;outputting input-1 lines of "+"s
~}"           ;preceded by correct amount of spaces
"~1@*~v@{+~}" ;outputting input-1 pluses. We do it two times
              ;and then add one + at the end. This way there
              ;is no need for argument like: (1-(* 2 INPUT))
              ;which would make me need a variable keeping INPUT
```

Ideas for improvement are welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 24 bytes

```
+J*+++K*dQ\+Kb/Q2*\+hyQJ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/X9tLS1tb21srJTBG2ztJP9BIK0Y7ozLQ6/9/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 43 + 1 (-n) = 44 bytes

```perl
$,="+
";say@q=($"x--$_)x$_,'+'x(2*$_),@q,''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19Fx1ZJm0vJujix0qHQVkNFqUJXVyVes0IlXkddW71Cw0gLyNNxKNRRV///3@RffkFJZn5e8X9dX1M9A0OD/7p5AA)

Independently came up with pretty much the same method as @Dada, but got it down by 1 byte.

Answer (score 0):

## Excel, 86 bytes

```
=REPT(REPT(" ",A1-1)&"+
",A1-1)&REPT("+",2*A1-1)&"
"&REPT(REPT(" ",A1-1)&"+
",A1-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-R`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 12 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Look, Ma, no `+`!

```
çÄ ê
¬hNÉU û
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI&code=58Qg6gqsaE7JVSD7&input=OA)

Answer (score 0):

**APL (NARS2000), 25 characters:**

```
{' +'[1+∨/¨⍵=∘.,⍨⍳⍵+⍵-1]}
```

<strike>**APL (NARS2000), 26 characters:**</strike>

```
{' +'[1+∨/¨⍵=∘.,⍨⍳¯1+2×⍵]}
```

**Examples:**

```
      {' +'[1+∨/¨⍵=∘.,⍨⍳⍵+⍵-1]} 1
+
      {' +'[1+∨/¨⍵=∘.,⍨⍳⍵+⍵-1]} 2
 + 
+++
 + 
      {' +'[1+∨/¨⍵=∘.,⍨⍳⍵+⍵-1]} 3
  +  
  +  
+++++
  +  
  +  
      {' +'[1+∨/¨⍵=∘.,⍨⍳⍵+⍵-1]} 4
   +   
   +   
   +   
+++++++
   +   
   +   
   +
```

**Rationale:**

Take `n = 4` as example. Objective is to generate an integer matrix as below:

```
1 1 1 2 1 1 1
1 1 1 2 1 1 1
1 1 1 2 1 1 1
2 2 2 2 2 2 2
1 1 1 2 1 1 1
1 1 1 2 1 1 1
1 1 1 2 1 1 1
```

Expression `⍵=∘.,⍨⍳⍵+⍵-1`, when given `⍵ = 4`, generates matrix of 2-tuple from integer vector `1..7`:

```
 0 0  0 0  0 0  0 1  0 0  0 0  0 0 
 0 0  0 0  0 0  0 1  0 0  0 0  0 0 
 0 0  0 0  0 0  0 1  0 0  0 0  0 0 
 1 0  1 0  1 0  1 1  1 0  1 0  1 0 
 0 0  0 0  0 0  0 1  0 0  0 0  0 0 
 0 0  0 0  0 0  0 1  0 0  0 0  0 0 
 0 0  0 0  0 0  0 1  0 0  0 0  0 0
```

Each cell is reduced by logical-or `∨/¨` to give boolean matrix:

```
0 0 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 0
```

Add 1 to this matrix and we have the desired array-indexing matrix.

Answer (score 0):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), <sup><s>8</s></sup> 7 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
+×：⤢ｎ！┼
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=KyVENyV1RkYxQSV1MjkyMiV1RkY0RSV1RkYwMSV1MjUzQw__,i=NQ__,v=8)

-1 byte from hakr14.

Comment: You can replace `；+＊` with `：⤢` to save a byte. Also, how did I not know about `ｎ`?

Comment: @hakr14 I realized `n`'s existence after a long time as well :) Talking with dzaima helps

Answer (score 0):

## Batch 97 bytes

**requires windows 10 with virtual terminal support**

```bat
Set x=%~1&cls&@Set/a c=x*2-1
@For /L %%i in (1 1 %c%)Do @Echo(ESC[%%i;%x%H+ESC[%x%;%%iH+ESC[%x%BESC[1G
```

`ESC` is the ANSI escape character, [which doesn't paste well but can be copied from the raw paste data here](https://pastebin.com/fQze86jM).
Or it can be generated by opening the command prompt and typing `>"%TEMP%\escape.chr" Echo(`<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>027</kbd> then pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, or output using a for loop with `Echo off`:

```bat
(For /F "skip=4 DELIMS=" %a in ('Echo(prompt $E^|cmd')Do Echo(%a) >"%TEMP%\escape.chr"
```

**How:**
Iterates over the width of the string `c` and outputs c`+` along the the `x` (y and x) intersection using virtual terminal sequences to move the cursor to the relevant coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

## [Regenerate](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Regenerate), 38 bytes

```
(( {$~1-1}\+\n){$~1-1})\+{$~1*2-1}\n$1
```

Takes input as a command-line argument. [Try it here!](https://replit.com/@dloscutoff/regenerate)

#### Explanation

Space is represented by underscore for better visibility.

```
(( {$~1-1}\+\n){$~1-1})\+{$~1*2-1}\n$1
(                     )                 Group 1: the section above the center line
 (            )                          Group 2: one line of that section
  _{$~1-1}                                n-1 spaces
          \+\n                            followed by + and newline
               {$~1-1}                   Repeat n-1 times
                       \+{$~1*2-1}      n*2-1 + characters
                                  \n    followed by newline
                                    $1  Contents of group 1 again
```

Answer (score 0):

## [><> (Fish)](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 94 bytes

```
1-:?!/:::?v"+"o~ \
 84*o1-70.\
>.!07$&:&v!?:-1oa/
/+1 *2:~ /
 /ao~";"93p10.
<\!?:-1o"+"
 ;"+"\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/31DXyl5R38rKyr5MSVspv04hhkvBwkQr31DX3EAvhstOT9HAXEXNSq1M0d5K1zA/UZ9LX9tQQcvIqk5Bn0tBPzG/TslaydK4wNBAj8smBqIIaBCXgjWQjPn//79u2X9jAA) [Animated Version](https://mousetail.github.io/Fish/#%7B%22text%22%3A%221-%3A%3F!%2F%3A%3A%3A%3Fv%5C%22%2B%5C%22o%7E%20%5C%5C%5Cn%2084*o1-70.%5C%5C%5Cn%3E.!07%24%26%3A%26v!%3F%3A-1oa%2F%5Cn%2F%2B1%20*2%3A%7E%20%2F%5Cn%20%2Fao%7E%5C%22%3B%5C%2293p10.%5Cn%3C%5C%5C!%3F%3A-1o%5C%22%2B%5C%22%5Cn%20%3B%5C%22%2B%5C%22%5C%5C%22%2C%22input%22%3A%22%22%2C%22stack%22%3A%223%22%2C%22mode%22%3A%22numbers%22%7D)

### Explanation

[image]

The yellow loop special cases the 1 cross variant to print a `+` and exit.

The blue loop is the loops over each line. The green loop prints N spaces and the blue loop then prints a "+" at the end of each line.

The orange bypass calculates the length of the row which will have only + signs (2n + 1). Then it will enter the blue-purple loop.

The blue-purple loop prints the plus signs in the middle row. Once the count reaches 0 the mirror isn't skipped anymore so the pink segment is entered.

The pink segment replaces the mirror at 9,3 with a ;. This is the red highlighted semicolon in the picture. Then jumps back to the blue loop. However, this time instead of printing the row of `+` signs it will exit. (`;` means exit program in fish)