# #OctothorpeAsciiArt

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art

An [Octothorpe, (also called number sign, hash or hashtag, or pound sign)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_sign) is the following ASCII character:

```
#
```

Isn't that a fun shape? Lets make bigger versions of it! So here is your challenge:

> Given a positive integer **N**, output an ASCII hashtag of size **N**.

For example, an ASCII hashtag of size **1** looks like this:

```
 # # 
#####
 # # 
#####
 # #
```

Trailing whitespace on each line is allowed, but not required.

The input will *always* be a valid positive integer, so you don't have to handle non-numbers, negative, or 0. Your output can be in any reasonable format, so outputting to STDOUT, returning a list of strings, or string with newlines, a 2D matrix of characters, writing to a file, etc. are all fine.

### Test cases

```
2:
  ##  ##
  ##  ##
##########
##########
  ##  ##
  ##  ##
##########
##########
  ##  ##
  ##  ##

3:
   ###   ###   
   ###   ###   
   ###   ###   
###############
###############
###############
   ###   ###   
   ###   ###   
   ###   ###   
###############
###############
###############
   ###   ###   
   ###   ###   
   ###   ###   

4:
    ####    ####    
    ####    ####    
    ####    ####    
    ####    ####    
####################
####################
####################
####################
    ####    ####    
    ####    ####    
    ####    ####    
    ####    ####    
####################
####################
####################
####################
    ####    ####    
    ####    ####    
    ####    ####    
    ####    ####    

5:
     #####     #####     
     #####     #####     
     #####     #####     
     #####     #####     
     #####     #####     
#########################
#########################
#########################
#########################
#########################
     #####     #####     
     #####     #####     
     #####     #####     
     #####     #####     
     #####     #####     
#########################
#########################
#########################
#########################
#########################
     #####     #####     
     #####     #####     
     #####     #####     
     #####     #####     
     #####     #####
```

Since this is a code-golf, try to write the shortest possible solution you can, and above all else, have fun!

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/116110/this-challenge-uses-the-character)

Answer (score 22):

## [MATL](https://matl.suever.net/), <s>20</s> <s>16</s> <s>12</s> 11 bytes

3 bytes thanks to DJMcMayhem.

1 byte thanks to Luis Mendo.

```
21BwY"&*~Zc
```

[Try it online!](https://matl.suever.net/?code=21BwY%22%26%2a~Zc&inputs=3&version=20.4.0)

### Explanation

```
    % stack starts with input e.g. 2
21  % push 21 to stack             2 21
B   % convert to binary            2 [1 0 1 0 1]
w   % swap                         [1 0 1 0 1] 2
Y"  % repeat                       [1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1]
&*  % one-input multiplication    [[1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1]
                                   [1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1]
                                   [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
                                   [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
                                   [1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1]
                                   [1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1]
                                   [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
                                   [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
                                   [1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1]
                                   [1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1]]
~   % complement                  [[0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0]
                                   [0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0]
                                   [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
                                   [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
                                   [0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0]
                                   [0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0]
                                   [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
                                   [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
                                   [0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0]
                                   [0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0]]
Zc  % convert 0 to spaces            ##  ##  
      1 to octothorpes               ##  ##  
      and join by newline          ##########
                                   ##########
                                     ##  ##  
                                     ##  ##  
                                   ##########
                                   ##########
                                     ##  ##  
                                     ##  ##
```

Comment: You can use `Zc` instead of `35*c` and `~` (logical NOT) instead of `0=`

Comment: @DJMcMayhem @_@ why is that a built-in

Comment: Actually, the reason that's a builtin is really interesting. I could be wrong, but I think conor suggested it, and Suever wrote a script that looks at all the MATL answers to see what functions are more common for future improvements. Zc was [just added](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39450878#39450878)

Comment: Also, since each cell just has to be non-zero, you could do `Q` instead of `2<`

Comment: @DJMcMayhem sorry I changed the algorithm removing that need.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Yes, that's how it happened. Actually `*` was slightly more common, but I liked `#` better :-)

Comment: @LeakyNun You can change `!t*` to `&*`. The latter means "one-input multiplication", which multiplies (element-wise) the input by its transpose

Answer (score 15):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 420 bytes

```
(()()()){({}<(({})){({}<<>(<>({})<>){({}<((((()()()()){}){}()){}())>[(
)])}{}(<>({})<>){({}<((((()()()()){}){}){})>[()])}{}(<>({})<>){({}<(((
(()()()()){}){}()){}())>[()])}{}(<>({})<>){({}<((((()()()()){}){}){})>
[()])}{}((()()()()()){})<>>[()])}{}((({}))<(({})(({}){}){})>){({}<<>(<
>({})<>){({}<((((()()()()){}){}()){}())>[()])}{}((()()()()()){})<>>[()
])}{}{}>[()])}{}({}<>)(({})((({({})({}[()])}{})){}){}{}){({}<{}>[()])}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pU/LCoBACPwdPXTovgh9R3TYDkEUHbqK32662eMSBbEyusyMMv2ax6Ua5jypAqA/ZGBJYBBjIrCyb6KDg9C6WqxKN6AWsEOx@c3h9V39d/9J7nSiO@VB97wFwvsj@/M1lktlywjjLHDpLAcbux1cePpUa62aDQ)

No, the score of 420 was not intentional. I promise. Readable version:

```
# 3 Times...
(()()())
{
({}<

    #Duplicate the input
    (({}))

    #Input times...
    {
        ({}<

        #Switch to the main stack
        <>

        #Grab the duplicate of the input
        (<>({})<>)

        #That many times...
        {({}<

            # Push a hash
            ((((()()()()){}){}()){}())

        >[()])}{}

        #Grab the duplicate of the input
        (<>({})<>)

        #That many times...
        {({}<

            #Push a space
            ((((()()()()){}){}){})

        >[()])}{}

        #Grab the duplicate of the input
        (<>({})<>)

        #That many times...
        {({}<

            # Push a hash
            ((((()()()()){}){}()){}())

        >[()])}{}

        #Grab the duplicate of the input
        (<>({})<>)

        #That many times...
        {({}<

            #Push a space
            ((((()()()()){}){}){})

        >[()])}{}

        #Push a newline
        ((()()()()()){})

        #Toggle back to the alternate stack
        <>

        #Decrement the (second) loop counter
        >[()])

    #Endwhile
    }

    #Pop the now zeroed loop counter
    {}

    #Turn [a] into [a, a*5, a]
    ((({}))<(({})(({}){}){})>)

    #A times....
    {
        ({}<

        #Toggle back over
        <>

        #Grab a*5
        (<>({})<>)

        #That many times...
        {({}<

            #Push a space
            ((((()()()()){}){}()){}())

        >[()])}{}

        #Push a newline
        ((()()()()()){})

        #Toggle back
        <>

        #Decrement the (second) loop counter
        >[()])

    }

    #Pop the loop counter and the a*5
    {}{}

#Decrement the outer loop counter
>[()])
}

#Pop the zeroed loop counter
{}

#Pop a over
({}<>)

#Pushes (a**2) * 5 + a
(({})((({({})({}[()])}{})){}){}{})

#That many times...
{({}<

    #Pop a character off the output stack
    {}

>[()])}
```

Answer (score 14):

## [6502 machine code](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/6502_Assembly) (C64), <strike>59</strike> 56 bytes

```
00 C0 20 9B B7 A9 06 85 FC 86 FE A6 FE 86 FD A9 03 4D 1F C0 8D 1F C0 C6 FC D0
01 60 A9 23 A0 05 49 00 20 D2 FF CA D0 FA A6 FE 88 D0 F3 A9 0D 20 D2 FF C6 FD
D0 E6 F0 D3
```

#### [Online demo](https://vice.janicek.co/c64/#%7B"controlPort2":"joystick","primaryControlPort":2,"keys":%7B"SPACE":"","RETURN":"","F1":"","F3":"","F5":"","F7":""%7D,"files":%7B"hash.prg":"data:;base64,AMAgm7epBoX8hv6m/ob9qQNNH8CNH8DG/NABYKkjoAVJACDS/8rQ+qb+iNDzqQ0g0v/G/dDm8NM="%7D,"vice":%7B"-autostart":"hash.prg"%7D%7D)

Usage: `SYS49152,N` where N is a number between 1 and 255.

<sub>(values greater than 4 will already be too large for the C64 screen, starting from 8, the output is even too wide)</sub>

**Explanation**:

```
         00 C0       .WORD $C000    ; load address

.C:c000  20 9B B7    JSR $B79B      ; read N into X
.C:c003  A9 06       LDA #$06       ; number of "logical" lines plus 1 for hash
.C:c005  85 FC       STA $FC        ; store in counter variable for lines
.C:c007  86 FE       STX $FE        ; store N in counter variable for char repetitions
.C:c009  A6 FE       LDX $FE        ; load repetition counter
.C:c00b  86 FD       STX $FD        ; store in counter variable for line repetitions
.C:c00d  A9 03       LDA #$03       ; value to toggle the character toggle
.C:c00f  4D 1F C0    EOR $C01F      ; xor character bit toggle
.C:c012  8D 1F C0    STA $C01F      ; store character bit toggle
.C:c015  C6 FC       DEC $FC        ; decrement "logical" lines
.C:c017  D0 01       BNE $C01A      ; not 0 -> continue
.C:c019  60          RTS            ; program done
.C:c01a  A9 23       LDA #$23       ; load hash character
.C:c01c  A0 05       LDY #$05       ; load "logical" columns for hash
.C:c01e  49 00       EOR #$00       ; in each odd "logical" line, toggle character
.C:c020  20 D2 FF    JSR $FFD2      ; output one character
.C:c023  CA          DEX            ; decrement character repetition
.C:c024  D0 FA       BNE $C020      ; not 0 -> back to output
.C:c026  A6 FE       LDX $FE        ; reload character repetition
.C:c028  88          DEY            ; decrement "logical" columns
.C:c029  D0 F3       BNE $C01E      ; not 0 -> back to character toggle
.C:c02b  A9 0D       LDA #$0D       ; line done, load newline character
.C:c02d  20 D2 FF    JSR $FFD2      ; and output
.C:c030  C6 FD       DEC $FD        ; decrement line repetitions
.C:c032  D0 E6       BNE $C01A      ; not 0 -> back to character init
.C:c034  F0 D3       BEQ $C009      ; else back to main loop (toggle char toggling)
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: +1 for nostalgia (6502 assembly on a c64 was my first programming experience...)

Answer (score 10):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 43 bytes

```hs
l%n=l!!1:l++l<*[1..n]
f n=["##"%n,"# "%n]%n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P0c1zzZHUdHQKkdbO8dGK9pQTy8vlitNIc82WklZWUk1T0dJWQFIxarm/c9NzMxTsFXITSzwVSgoLQkuKfLJU1BRSFMw@Q8A)

Outputs a list of strings.

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 55 bytes

```python
def f(n):p=[(" "*n+"#"*n)*2]*n;print(p+["#"*n*5]*n)*2+p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/PyU1TSFNI0/TqsA2WkNJQUkrT1tJGUhqahnFauVZFxRl5pVoFGhHgwW1TGPBMtoF/9PyixQyFTLzFIoS89JTNQx1zDSt0jQyNSE6/gMA)

This returns a 2D list of characters.

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 65 bytes

```python
def f(n):p=((" "*n+"#"*n)*2+"\n")*n;print(p+("#"*n*5+"\n")*n)*2+p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYu7DoAgDAB/palLCy6S6IDxT1xMBGUpDXHx6/EVl1vuTs9jz@JqXUOESMJeJyIENGKxucnGWZwF2cioJclBauk1pv/F02iNuUCCJFAW2QJ17cA@UuJvqxc)

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 66 bytes

```python
def f(n):p=[(" "*n+"#"*n)*2]*n;print'\n'.join((p+["#"*n*5]*n)*2+p)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/PyU1TSFNI0/TqsA2WkNJQUkrT1tJGUhqahnFauVZFxRl5pWox@Sp62XlZ@ZpaBRoR4OltUxjwWq0CzT/p@UXKWQqZOYpFCXmpadqGOqYaVqlaWRqQjT/BwA)

Comment: Wat witchkraft is yer footer

Comment: @LeakyNun A for loop :)

Comment: No, I'm talking about the `f(i);` storing the result in a temp and `print` accessing it.

Comment: @LeakyNun Ya misunderstood: `f(i)` prints and `print` in Python **2** adds a newline :P

Comment: Oh, how stupid of me.

Comment: But you only used `k` and `o` once...

Comment: @LeakyNun I was getting rid of that right when you commented

Comment: Sad that string multiplication and addition isn't distributive...

Answer (score 8):

### [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>12</s> 10 bytes

```
´Ṫ▲Ṙ" # #
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9CWhztXPZq26eHOGUoKykD4//9/YwA)
Note the trailing space.

### Explanation

```
´Ṫ▲Ṙ" # #   Implicit input, e.g. n=2.
   Ṙ" # #   Repeat each character of the string n times: "  ##  ##  "
´Ṫ          Outer product with itself by
  ▲         maximum: ["  ##  ##  ","  ##  ##  ","##########","##########","  ##  ##  ","  ##  ##  ","##########","##########","  ##  ##  ","  ##  ##  "]
            Print implicitly, separated by newlines.
```

Answer (score 7):

## CJam, <s>27</s> <s>26</s> 25 bytes

```
{_[{S3*'#*'#5*}3*;]fe*e*}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP2fqqwQlJqYopCYp5CZV5KanlqkkFaUn6sQHOLi6cdVlPm/Oj66OthYS10ZiEy1ao21rGPTUrVStWrBWkvzFEoyUhWScvKTs4FmpCik5RflJpaABYtSi0tzSoq56hT8tP6bAAA)

Fun fact: This originally started at 29 bytes, and bytes have been removed one-by-one ever since, alternating between block and full-program mode.

### Explanation:

```
{                          e# Stack:               | 2
 _                         e# Duplicate:           | 2 2
  [                        e# Begin array:         | 2 2 [
   {                       e# Do the following 3 times:
    S                      e#   Push a space       | 2 2 [" "
     3*                    e#   Repeat it 3 times: | 2 2 ["   "
       '#*                 e#   Join with '#':     | 2 2 [" # # "
          '#               e#   Push '#':          | 2 2 [" # # " '#
            5*             e#   Repeat it 5 times: | 2 2 [" # # " "#####"
              }3*          e# End:                 | 2 2 [" # # " "#####" " # # " "#####" " # # " "#####"
                 ;         e# Delete top of stack: | 2 2 [" # # " "#####" " # # " "#####" " # # "
                  ]        e# End array:           | 2 2 [" # # " "#####" " # # " "#####" " # # "]
                   fe*     e# Repeat characters:   | 2 ["  ##  ##  " "##########" "  ##  ##  " "##########" "  ##  ##  "]
                      e*   e# Repeat strings:      | ["  ##  ##  " "  ##  ##  " "##########" "##########" "  ##  ##  " "  ##  ##  " "##########" "##########" "  ##  ##  " "  ##  ##  "]
                        }  e# End
e# Result:
e# ["  ##  ##  "
e#  "  ##  ##  "
e#  "##########"
e#  "##########"
e#  "  ##  ##  "
e#  "  ##  ##  "
e#  "##########"
e#  "##########"
e#  "  ##  ##  "
e#  "  ##  ##  "]
```

Comment: Someone was prepared for this challenge :P

Comment: @ETHproductions It was a CMC and moved to main...

Comment: @ETHproductions Can't really blame him for that...

Answer (score 7):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 49 + 1 (-p) = 50 bytes

```perl
$_=' # # 
'=~s/./$&x$_/gre x$_;$_.=(y/ /#/r.$_)x2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3lZdQRkIudRt64r19fRV1CpU4vXTi1IVgLS1SryerUalvoK@sn6Rnkq8ZoXR//8m//ILSjLz84r/6/qa6hkYGvzXLQAA)

**How?**

Implicitly store the input in `$_` via the `-p` flag.  Start with the most basic possible top line `" # # "` with its trailing newline.  Replicate each of those characters by the input number.  Then replicate that by the input number to form the top part of the octothorpe, storing all of that back in `$_`.  Then append the line with all characters replaced by '#' times the input number.  Then append the top section.  Do those last two sentences a total of two times.  Output of the `$_` is implicit in the `-p` flag.

Comment: I like how your answer is just as readable as mine.

Comment: They've always said that Perl is a write-only language.

Comment: This is a nice solution, don't think I can improve the approach at all! You can save a couple of bytes though, although when this was originally scored, one wouldn't have saved a byte (since it involves adding `-a`), but using `$\=` instead of `$_.=` saves a byte at least! [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3lZdQRkIudQrVOKti/X19FXUKpQc3JT001OtVWJsNSr1FfSV9Yv0VOI1K4z@/zf5l19QkpmfV/xf19dUz8DQ4L9uQSIA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 6):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <s>23</s> 19 bytes

```
' #'{~1=]+./~@#i:@2
```

Saved 4 bytes thanks to @LeakyNun.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P03B1kpBXUFZvbrO0DZWW0@/zkE508rBiIsrNTkjX0FHTyFNTc9OwVDBSMH4/38A)

### Explanation

```
' #'{~1=]+./~@#i:@2  Input: integer n
                  2  The constant 2
               i:@   Range [-2, -1, 0, 1, 2]
        ]            Get n
              #      Copy each n times
         +./~@       GCD table
      1=             Equals 1, forms the hashtag for input 1
' #'{~               Index and select the char
```

Comment: Rats! Was just about to post a (4 byte longer) solution of my own. I'm really impressed by how you're able to compose these functions without caps and with few conjunctions.

Comment: @cole Thanks. Sometimes caps can be avoided by using a noun and dyad. For example, ``[:|:f`` could be ``0|:f``

Comment: `' # '{~]#"1]#+./~@i:@2` saves a byte

Comment: repeat before multiplication gives you 19 bytes: [`f=:' #'{~1=]+./~@#i:@2`](https://tio.run/##y/r/P83WSl1BWb26ztA2VltPv85BOdPKweh/anJGvoKOnkKamp6dgqGCkYLxfwA)

Comment: `i:@2` throws a domain error for me in JVERSION `j805/j64/darwin`

Comment: @hoosierEE It's a new feature coming in J 8.06. You can try the beta http://www.jsoftware.com/download/j806/install/

Comment: @miles how did you come up with the idea for using a GCD table?  beyond sheer genius?

Answer (score 6):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 21 bytes

```
ＮθＵＯ×²θ#ＵＯθ Ｆ²⟲ＯＯ²⁴⁶θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/98zr6C0xK80Nym1SKNQ05rLPyknPy9dIyQzN7VYw0hHoVBTR0FJWQkhUwjkK4D4aflFChpGmgpB@SWJJan@ZalFOYkFUErDyMQMpNf6/3/T/7pl/3WLcwA) Link is to verbose version of code. I'd originally tried a cute bitmap approach:

```
Ｆ⁵Ｆ⁵Ｆ＆｜ικ¹«Ｊ×ιＩθ×κＩθＵＯθ#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8tv0hBw1RTAYV2yiwpzyxOdcxLgTH9izQydRSyNXUUDDU1Faq5OL1KcwtC8jVCMnNTi0FSzonFJRqFmkAFEKFshJCmNRenf1JOfl66RqGOgpKykiZX7f//pv91y/7rFucAAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Works by considering the `#` as an array of 5×5 squares. The squares that are in odd rows or columns need to be filled in.

Comment: does charcoal really not have a hashtag shape built-in?

Comment: Did I tie charcoal O_O?

Comment: [yay](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8tv0hBw1RTAUZnpilo@Bdp@OanlObka2TqKBhp6ihAedkgnqamQjUXp1dpbkFIvkZIZm5qMUiVc2JxiUahJlAtRCgbIaRpzcXpn5STn5euUaijoKSspMlV@/@/6X/dsv@6xTkA) (hmm looks like I need to fix that a bit)

Comment: @ASCII-only What needs fixing?

Comment: Oblong shouldn't be printing the steps for the polygon it uses internally lol

Comment: Oh I meant the thing I linked lol

Comment: Yes it is, I guess it's not that important but it's still broken

Comment: Well the debug shows polygon drawing but that should be hidden as an implementation detail behind the oblong drawing

Comment: Oh oops sorry copied wrong link lol :/

Answer (score 6):

## J, 22 bytes

```
#('# '{~#:5$21,0)#~"1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P03B1kpBWUNdWUG9uk7ZylTFyFDHQFO5TskwlosrNTkjXyFNTc9OwVDBSMGYy89JTwHEKy1OTVEoyVdIyq9QKMlIVcgvLSkoLSn@/x8A)

A lot of similarity to the other J answer, though I don't understand trains with lots of nouns well, so my answer has three potential bytes to cut off (two parens and a reflexive-`~`).

## Explanation

#### Generating the octothorpe

The octothorpe is made by everything in the parenthetical, reproduced below for convenience.

```
'# '{~#:5$21,0
```

A lot of the way I make the octothorpe is abuse of the way that J pads its arrays when they aren't long enough.

`21,0` simply creates the array `21 0`.

`5$` reshapes that array into a 5-atom array: `21 0 21 0 21`.

`#:` converts each atom into a binary number. Since `#:` operates on each atom, the output is a matrix. Each `21` is replaced by `1 0 1 0 1` as expected, but each `0` is replaced by `0 0 0 0 0`! This is because J pads arrays not long enough to match the shape of the resulting 2D array which is forced to be `5 5` because of the `1 0 1 0 1` rows. Fortunately, for numbers it pads with `0`, so we get the resulting matrix

```
1 0 1 0 1
0 0 0 0 0
1 0 1 0 1
0 0 0 0 0
1 0 1 0 1
```

`'# '{~` converts each `1` to a space and `0` to `#`. `{` means "take" and `~` means "switch the dyadic arguments, so J looks to each element in the matrix as indices for the string `'# '` meaning each `0` becomes the zeroth element, `#` and each `1` becomes the first element, a space. This yields the size one octothorpe.

#### Resizing the octothorpe

This is simply a matter of copying `n` times along each axis, done using

the first `#` (which is part of a hook) and `#~"1]`. `#` copies along the horizontal axis and `#"1` copies along the vertical axis.

Comment: `##"1&('# '{~#:5$21,0)` saves a byte.

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>14</s> <s>13</s> 11 bytes

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to @JonathanAllen*

```
5ẋ€Ẏ&þ`ị⁾ #
```

A monadic link returning a list of lines. Note the trailing space.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASQA2/9qZWxsef//NeG6i@KCrOG6jibDvmDhu4vigb4gI//Dh1n//zg)

#### How it works

```
5ẋ€Ẏ&þ`ị⁾ #    Main link. Arguments: n (integer)            1
5              Yield 5.
 ẋ€            Create a range and repeat each item n times. [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]]
   Ẏ           Tighten; dump all sublists into the main list.
                                                            [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
     þ         Create a table of                            [[1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
    &          bitwise ANDs,                                 [0, 2, 2, 0, 0],
      `        reusing this list.                            [1, 2, 3, 0, 1],
                                                             [0, 0, 0, 4, 4],
                                                             [1, 0, 1, 4, 5]]
       ị⁾ #    Index into the string " #".                   [" # # ",
               0 -> "#", 1 -> " ", 2 -> "#", etc.             "#####",
                                                              " # # ",
                                                              "#####",
                                                              " # # "]
```

Comment: Nice observation regarding bitwise or - save two bytes by switching from or to and - removing the need to lower, allowing an implicit range and removing the need for `µ` (or the `⁸` you could have had there instead)... ``5ẋ€Ẏ&þ`ị⁾ #``

Comment: @JonathanAllan Interesting--why does `5Ḷẋ€` require the `µ`, but not `5ẋ€`?

Comment: I thought the need was just to stop `Ẏ` acting on `n` and then passing it to the right of `ẋ€`, since with a nilad-dyad leading chain being called monadically it's not necessary. I'm not quite sure, however, how `\`` seems to then place 5 (or maybe the list of that length) on the right of the tabled `&` though.

Answer (score 4):

## Game Maker Language, <s>138</s> 108 bytes

```
n=argument0 s=''for(j=0;j<5*n;j+=1){for(l=0;l<5*n;l+=1)if(j div n|l div n)&1s+='#'else s+=' 's+='
'}return s
```

Intended as a script (Game Maker's name for user-defined functions), thus the `n=argument0` and `return s`. 20 bytes could be shaved by taking `n` directly from the current instance and using `s` as the result. (The instance gets these variables anyway because they weren't declared with `var`).

Beware of course that `#` is used by Game Maker's graphics stuff as an alternative newline character, so you might want to prefix it with `\` if you want to output to the screen ;)

Also note that I'm using Game Maker 8.0's version of GML here; modern GML versions might have features that could save additional bytes.

Some ideas courtesy of friends wareya and chordbug.

Comment: I think this is the first GML answer i've ever seen

Comment: @TimothyGroote It's a shame it isn't used more, its optional brackets and semicolons are great for golfing :)

Answer (score 4):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), <s>338</s> 332 bytes

6 bytes thanks to Riley.

```
(({}<>)<(())>)(()()()()()){({}<(<>)<>{({}<<>({}<(((((()()()()())){})){}{}{})<>([({})]()){(<{}({}<((((({}))){}){}{}){({}<<>(({}))<>>[()])}{}>)>)}{}(({})<{{}(<(()()()()()){({}<<>(<([{}](((((()()){}){}){}){}()){}())>)<>{({}<<>({}<(({}))>())<>>[()])}<>({}<>{})>[()])}{}>)}>{})<>((()()()()()){})>())<>>[()])}<>({}<>{}<([{}]())>)>[()])}<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dU@7DgJBCPwdKK6yJZP4HZstzsLEaCxsCd@OwHrrqXHZJzMws6fHerkv59t6dSdSE7AQMYNj34I1EUoMdRVUosabxWq5MoJILTjcq1rUZkGSklm0rVtlBWjEnQNAGIij8qJxkR87USXU1Pq0MbqOWa/6x5flFALtxAaAyO/UDeMPH6r2p/BlI8Um5H7w5fgE)

### More "readable" version

```
(({}<>)<(())>)(()()()()())
{({}<(<>)<>{({}<<>({}<(((((()()()()())){})){}{}{})<>
  ([({})]()){(<{}({}<
    ((((({}))){}){}{}){({}<<>(({}))<>>[()])}{}
  >)>)}{}(({})<{{}(<
    (()()()()()){({}<<>(<([{}](((((()()){}){}){}){}()){}())>)<>{({}<<>({}<(({}))>())<>>[()])}<>({}<>{})>[()])}{}
  >)}>{})
<>((()()()()()){})>())<>>[()])}<>({}<>{}<([{}]())>)>[()])}<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dU8xDsIwDNz7io720InVssQ7ogxlQEIgBlbLbw9nh7QFiSStnLuz73J5rbfncn2s99aIzEVZiJiV8R@bJwuKgtQsRRPItcvYPL7YEE7zTAUyrqCMxDx6gAKPFeLoSPmYmqioFuLKICBXhEGVlBiKMWM3Ht1Cxbxusfr0fvKWD/t5QhgqHUw7ocC/U3hAU2Q8Ovuf5k@UMNyo1k5tOb8B)

Comment: `(({})<>)(())<>({}<>)` at the beginning can be replaced with `(({}<>)<(())>)`

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>25</s> <s>22</s> 21 bytes

```
•LQ•bûε×}5ôεS„# èJ¹F=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//UcMin0AgkXR497mth6fXmh7ecm5r8KOGecoKh1d4HdrpZvv/v5EBAA)

---

***-1 because Emigna hates transliterate and, thankfully, reminds me I should too :P.***

---

Gotta be a better way than bitmapping it... Still working.

Comment: Reflection... is not the answer in 05AB1E, though it seems like it could be...

Comment: `5ôεS„# èJ¹F=` saves a byte.

Comment: @Emigna would canvas be good for this?

Comment: Possibly. I haven't tried the canvas yet so I'm not really sure of its capabilities. Seems like something it's made for.

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES6), 79 bytes

```js
f=
n=>[...Array(n*5)].map((_,i,a)=>a.map((_,j)=>` #`[(i/n|j/n)&1]).join``).join`
`
```

```html
<input type=number oninput=o.textContent=f(this.value)><pre id=o>
```

Port of the bitmap approach that I'd used for my original Charcoal attempt.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>124</s>, <s>116</s>, <s>113</s>, <s>112</s>, <s>98</s>, <s>96</s> 66 bytes

New (Credit: HyperNeutrino):

```python
def f(a):i='print(" "*a+"#"*a)*2;'*a;exec(i+'print"#"*a*5;'*a)*2+i
```

Old:

```python
a=input();b,c="# "
for i in"012":
	exec'print c*a+b*a+c*a+b*a;'*a
	if i<"2":exec'print b*a*5;'*a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9E2M6@gtERD0zpJJ9lWSVlBiSstv0ghUyEzT8nA0EjJiosztSI1Wb2gKDOvRCFZK1E7CYihtLW6ViIXZ2aaQqaNElApkkKgpJYpSPr/f2MA)

Obviously not the shortest solution, but I think it's decent. Any feedback would be appreciated!

Comment: `a,b,c=input()," #"` should save some bytes.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem That gave me an error. Did you mean `a,b,c=input(),"#"," "`? Which isn't any shorter...I appreciate the help!

Comment: Oh, sorry. I assumed that worked because `a,b="# "` works.

Comment: `a=input();b,c="# "` will work and save bytes

Comment: You can also get get rid of the parens in `(i==2)` and add a space to the beginning.

Comment: @WheatWizard Fantastic! Thanks for your help. Down to 112.

Comment: [110 bytes](https://tio.run/##VYtBDkAwEADvfcWGQymn4kL6mG1TbCSraSrh9cWNw2QuM@FK6846ZzTE4UhVPdnWmaKEQsx7BAJiiMiLr7p6FOBP72SIxAmcwsY@fDxJhQJoBjJGjzZ63H7Lk6nhjXLubw "Python 2 – Try It Online") by removing the parens around the print statements

Comment: [102 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9E2M6@gtERD0zpJJ9lWSVlBiSstv0ghUyEzT6EoMS89VcNY04pLIbUiNVm9oCgzr0QhWStROwmIkWhrda1ELoXMNIVMGyMrJKVAaS1TkOT//yYA "Python 2 – Try It Online") since `2` is the last iteration of `range`, so we can just only do the last exec if `i < 2`

Comment: [96 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9E2M6@gtERD0zpJJ9lWSVlBiSstv0ghUyEzT8nA0EjJikshtSI1Wb2gKDOvRCFZK1E7CYihtLW6ViKXQmaaQqaNElApkkKgpJYpSPr/fxMA "Python 2 – Try It Online") by taking out `range`

Comment: @StepHen Those are fantastic. I also got rid of some excess chars in the 1st print. The last spaces. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @BraedenSmith yep, you bet! You might need to change `i<2` to `i<"2"` for it to work. Otherwise, welcome to PPCG, golfing is fun :)

Comment: [76 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9E2M6@gtERD0zpJJ9lWSVlBiSvTVr2gKDOvRCFZK1E7CYihtLW6ViJXakVqskamNlQFUFTLFCSuqWWknfn/vzEA)

Comment: [71 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9E2M6@gtERD0zpJJ9lWSVlBiSvTVr2gKDOvRCNZK1E7SStRU8vIWl0rkSu1IjVZI1MbIqkAlNAyBYkDpbUz//83BgA)

Comment: [67 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9E2M6@gtERDkyvTVr2gKDOvRENJQUkrUVtJGUhqahlZq2slcqVWpCZrZGpDFIBltExBEkB57cz//40B)

Comment: [66 bytes as a function](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/PyU1TSFNI1HTKtNWvaAoM69EQ0lBSStRW0kZSGpqGVmrayVap1akJmtkakMUgGW0TEESQHntzP9pGpl5BaUlGpqa/40B)

Comment: @HyperNeutrino. Wow! That's great golfing :). I added it to the original.

Answer (score 3):

## [Befunge](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93), <s>105</s> 103 bytes

```
p9p&5*08p>08g-   v
>,g1+:00p^v0:/5g8_p9g1+:09p08g-#v_@
gvg90\/\g0< # # ##### 0:/5g8,+55<
^>\/2%5*+92++2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYpBCoQwDADvfUVA3INRmgRzUKTsQ4rCgpvbkov9fpfqzG2Yz/m9fnbW6uwvHUg8kdgEACVAMsaVyPdCa1STw/ku7O3pyvEOMBamHLPRBl2zAc8@ouoWbE@Wo/Q64CKIUuv8Bw)

Comment: Could you add a link to an online interpreter? https://tio.run/#befunge is a good one AFAIK.

Answer (score 3):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/tio-transpilers), 224 bytes

```
,[->+>>>>+<<<<<]>>>+>+++++[-<<<[->+>>>>>+>+++++[-<<<[->+<<<[->>>>>>+<<[->>>+>---<<<<]<<<<]>>>>>>[-<<<<<<+>>>>>>]>[-<<<+>>>]+++++[->+++++++<]>.[-]<<<<<<]>[-<+>]>[-<->]<+[->+<]>>]<<++++++++++.[-]<<<<<]>[-<+>]>[-<->]<+[->+<]>>]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY5LCoAwDAUXHucZT1BykZKFCoIILgTPH/Np3YizaT4vQ5dr3s/tXg/VsRKDDRRHvGI4lazv288wH26XUYKJKCTdZMSBkRaWHHgnTZhiwC6mSlLaPyyHjBNLiZw7bY@XN/8fVx0e)

### Making-of

I tried to build this code by hand and spent quite a few hours, so I decided to make a transpiler in Python.

Here is the code I entered to make this code:

```
read(0)
copy(0,(1,1),(5,1))
add(3,1)
add(4,5)
loop(4)
loop(1)
add(2,1)

add(7,1)
add(8,5)
loop(8)
loop(5)
add(6,1)

loop(3)
add(9,1)
loop(7)
add(10,1)
add(11,-3)
end(7)
end(3)
copy(9,(3,1))
copy(10,(7,1))
add(10,5)
copy(10,(11,7))
write(11)
clear(11)

end(5)
copy(6,(5,1))
copy(7,(6,-1))
add(6,1)
copy(6,(7,1))
end(8)
add(6,10)
write(6)
clear(6)

end(1)
copy(2,(1,1))
copy(3,(2,-1))
add(2,1)
copy(2,(3,1))
end(4)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZPBboMwDIbPzVNEnEibTFAKtFXbF5l6YAM6JpREgDT16ZljJ4hduktj@//92QmqfU5fRmezNeM1YeM1iljdtPxhJhNbcWabR28@qp6DLke26VpubxCf@bi7RrdoG1sFqSDlsigXp5hRWVAc2iK1quvYSr3CAtKPQoK@JdS/i7aaKhdfUUBUWiBnaKr6z3ZrjDNLusXP0E3NS@MbGXtj7EvfuyJjo18PvpPt09gn3HRbOauHs01rBt7Jb95pPpphauoYdPcmUASZ2NTfN9Xwz0L3aMZ3SATDcYmMU5kKGefwK5jjZhBhcJC5YLjHwZ9e2DsHRmXwHhfv0Z85CQV6sZJR5eQqWCipkCaBkqZSgcvdqaQj83ueJO7lM@jA0Ut/vhIAUoJCnzEFMr2LixAZvEW4NGalhIIKSNw6uGiSaz0uahIGFIFfeHxo3NPL@iyTUFjwe7lyZQv@IGY7dHqKRwkp/KvE/As)

Answer (score 3):

## [MAWP 2.0](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MAWP), 46 bytes

```
@!!!"#"*/" "*\+2*"
"+*!:/!5*"#"*"
"+*!:\!:/:/:
```

[Try it!](https://8dion8.github.io/MAWP/v2.0?code=%40!!!%22%23%22*%2F%22%20%22*%5C%2B2*%22%0A%22%2B*!%3A%2F!5*%22%23%22*%22%0A%22%2B*!%3A%5C!%3A%2F%3A%2F%3A&input=3)

Answer (score 2):

## [SOGL (SOGLOnline commit 2940dbe)](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGLOnline/tree/2940dbe13bc955f6456c1d3a737b40e255a1d103), 15 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
ø─Ζ┘Χ⁴‘5n{.∙.*T
```

To run this, download [this](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGLOnline/archive/2940dbe13bc955f6456c1d3a737b40e255a1d103.zip) and run the code in the `index.html` file.

Uses that at that commit (and before it) `*` repeated each character, not the whole string.

Explanation:

```
ø─Ζ┘Χ⁴‘          push " # # ##### # # ##### # # "
       5n        split into lines of length 5
         {       for each line do
          .∙       multiply vertically input times
            .*     multiply horizontally input times
              T    output in a new line
```

Bonus: add 2 inputs for separate X and Y length!

Comment: "commit 2940dbe" - I like that idea. Can you explain why `ø─Ζ┘Χ⁴‘` pushes that though?

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn That's SOGLs compression, which here stores a dictionary of " " and `#` and the base-2 data required for that string.

Comment: [Neat](https://i.imgur.com/iYOXpB3.gif), is it stable enough for me to start using :)?

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Well it's pretty stable as there have been no answer-breaking changes since SOGLOnline, but whether you can use it (as in understand it) is another question. You can try though and ask question in TNB

Comment: Haha... Ill wait for documentation then. I do need coddled a little.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn there is [some documentation](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/P5ParserV0_12/data/charDefs.txt) on the characters, though I don't really know where to start for a full documentation (and is it even worth it)

Comment: You absolutely MURDER ASCII challenges, so... imho I believe SOGL would be the next Jelly in terms of some challenges if you made it accessible to new people.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>98</s> 93 bytes

5 bytes thanks to Felix Palmen.

```c
i,j;main(a){for(scanf("%d",&a);j<a*5||(j=!puts(""),++i<a*5);)putchar(i/a+1&j++/a+1&1?32:35);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9TJ8s6NzEzTyNRszotv0ijODkxL01DSTVFSUctUdM6yyZRy7SmRiPLVrGgtKRYQ0lJU0dbOxMkqmmtCRRKzkgs0sjUT9Q2VMvS1gbThvbGRlbGQPna//8tAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 9 bytes

```
 # ”ṫ&:Ṁ‡
```

Pretty much a port of [Zgarb's great answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/139584/53880)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASAA3/9nYWlh//8gIyDigJ3huasmOuG5gOKAof/ih5HhuaP/Mw) (the footer is just to pretty print, the program itself returns a 2D list of characters)

#### Explanation

```
 # ”       Push the string " # "
    ṫ      Bounce, giving " # # "
     &     Repeat each character by input
      :    Copy
       Ṁ‡  Tabled maximum with itself
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 11 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
 #¶##┼∙┼╶╶＊
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JTIwJTIzJUI2JTIzJTIzJXUyNTNDJXUyMjE5JXUyNTNDJXUyNTc2JXUyNTc2JXVGRjBB,i=Mw__,v=1)

Explanation:

```
 #¶##         push "#\n##"
     ┼        quad-palindromize with 1 overlap
      ∙┼      quad-palindromize with 1 overlap again
        ╶╶＊  expand vertically and horizontally by the input
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>72</s> <s>68</s> <s>63</s> 60 bytes

```powershell
param($a)(,($x=,((' '*$a+"#"*$a)*2)*$a)+,("#"*5*$a)*$a)*2;$x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQyVRU0NHQ6XCVkdDQ11BXUslUVtJWQlIaWoZaYIobR0NkIApWAgsbK1S8f//f2MA)

Takes input `$a`. Then, we do a bunch of <s>magic</s> string and array manipulation.

```powershell
(,($x=,((' '*$a+"#"*$a)*2)*$a)+,("#"*5*$a)*$a)*2;$x
         ' '*$a+"#"*$a                              # Construct a string of spaces and #
        (             )*2                           # Repeat it twice
      ,(                 )*$a                       # Repeat that $a times to get the top as an array
  ($x=                       )                      # Store that into $x and immediately output it
 ,                            +                     # Array concatenate that with ...
                               ,("#"*5*$a)          # another string, the middle bar ...
                                          *$a       # repeated $a times.
(                                            )*2;   # Do that twice
                                                 $x # Output $x again
```

You can peel off the parts of the explanation starting from the bottom to see how the output is constructed, so hopefully my explanation makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

## Python, <s>88</s> <s>84</s> 77 bytes

```python
lambda x:[[(' #'[i//x%2]+'#')[j//x%2]for j in range(5*x)]for i in range(5*x)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHCKjpaQ11BWT06U1@/QtUoVltdWV0zOgvCScsvUshSyMxTKErMS0/VMNWq0ASLZaKJ/QcJJiIJalpxcRYUZeaVaCRqwljqMXnqeln5mXkauYkFGuoQto5CGlAJEPwHAA)

Returns 2D list of characters.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), <s>28</s> 22 bytes

*-6 bytes thanks to [@LeakyNun](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/48934/leaky-nun)*

```
JsC*]S5Qjmsm@"# "*kdJJ
```

**[Test Suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=JsC%2a%5DS5Qjmsm%40%22%23+%22%2akdJJ&input=4&debug=0)**

Comment: [22 bytes](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=JsC%2a%5DS5Qjmsm%40%22%23+%22%2akdJJ&input=4&debug=0)

Comment: @LeakyNun Thanks, I didn't really golf this answer so far.

Answer (score 1):

## Dyalog APL, <s>35</s> <s>30</s> <s>28</s> 26 bytes

*2 bytes saved thanks to @ngn*

```apl
' #'[∘.{∨/2|⌊⍺⍵÷k}⍨⍳5×k←⎕]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkGIBaQVldQVo9@1DFDr/pRxwp9o5pHPV2Penc96t16eHt27aPeFY96N5senp4NVAlUH/v/vzEA)

With `⎕IO←0`.

Comment: Nice. `k÷⍨⍺ ⍵` could be `⍺⍵÷k`

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 63 bytes

```
ArrayFlatten@Array[x=#;Table[If[OddQ@-##," ","#"],x,x]&,{5,5}]&
```

#### Explanation

```
ArrayFlatten@Array[x=#;Table[If[OddQ@-##," ","#"],x,x]&,{5,5}]&  (* input N *)

                   x=#                                           (* Set x to N *)
                                                      &          (* A function that takes two inputs: *)
                             If[OddQ@-##," ","#"]                (* if both inputs are odd (1), " ". "#" otherwise *)
                       Table[                    ,x,x]           (* Make N x N array of that string *)
             Array[                                     ,{5,5}]  (* Make a 5 x 5 array, applying that function to each index *)
ArrayFlatten@                                                    (* Flatten into 2D array *)
```

<sub>(1)`-##` parses into `Times[-1, ##]`</sub>

Comment: `ArrayFlatten` is very nice.

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, 72 bytes

```
a#b=a++b++a++b++a
c%l=((c<$l)#('#'<$l))<$l
f n=(' '%[1..n])#('#'%[1..n])
```

Returns a list of strings. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P1E5yTZRWztJWxtKciWr5thqaCTbqORoKmuoK6uDGJpAgitNIc9WQ11BXTXaUE8vLxYiC@P8z03MzFOwVchNLPBVKCgtCS4p8slTUFFIUzD5DwA)

How it works:

```
a#b=a++b++a++b++a          -- concatenate the strings a and b in the given pattern
c%l=                       -- take a char c and a list l (we only use the length
                           -- of l, the actual content doesn't matter)
    c<$l                   -- make length l copies of c
         '#'<$l            -- make length l copies of '#'
        #                  -- combine them via function #
               <$l         -- and make length l copies of that string
f n=                       -- main function
              #            -- make the "a b a b a" pattern with the strings
                           -- returned by the calls to function %                                
    ' '%[1..n]             --   one time with a space 
               '#'%[1..n]  --   one time with a '#'
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 113 bytes

**As an array of strings:**

```
r=[1-1*(i%(2*n)<n)for i in range(5*n)]
print[''.join(' #'[r[k]+r[j]>0]for k in range(len(r)))for j in range(n*5)]
```

---

**As ASCII art:**

## Python 3, 115 bytes

```
r=[1-1*(i%(2*n)<n)for i in range(5*n)]
for j in range(n*5):print(*(' #'[r[k]+r[j]>0]for k in range(len(r))),sep='')
```

## Python 3, 117 bytes

```
p=range(5*n)
for i,e in enumerate([j%(2*n)>=n for j in p]for k in p):print(*[' #'[i%(2*n)>=n or k]for k in e],sep='')
```

---

<s>**As an array of booleans**</s>

## Python 2, 75 bytes

```python
p=range(5*n)
f=lambda o:o%(2*n)>=n
print[[f(j)or f(i)for j in p]for i in p]
```

Comment: Long time, no see :-)

Comment: Yes, it has! @ETHproductions

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 103 bytes

Lambda accepts `Integer` and prints the octothorpe to standard out. Cast to `Consumer<Integer>`.

```java
n->{for(int s=5*n,x=0,y;x<s;x++)for(y=0;y<s;)System.out.print((x/n%2+y++/n%2>0?'#':32)+(y<s?"":"\n"));}
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##XY8xT8MwEIXn5FdYQag2bk3UiqVu0oGJATF0BAbjusEhsSP7HCWq8tuDA0xMp7t37@l7tejFxnbK1OevuQsfjZZINsJ79Cy0Qdc06ZzuBSjkQUAU62hgAXTDLsFI0NawR2t8aJU7PBlQlXIlih4DLxIsfFrXKVTMZlNeL9bheEe@eLgz66HI1yMfDp4PlJJFG4ucj3Enp9GDapkNwH6SMB7uze2WjpQus8yPq5vVfrclFMf/Y5btszeTEcKnOeFpRP7t8UfcW31GbWyDTxDTqtd3JFzlyVIu@UfKhJSqA7wjPE2mdJq/AQ)

### Ungolfed lambda

```java
n -> {
    for (
        int
            s = 5 * n,
            x = 0,
            y
        ;
        x < s;
        x++
    )
        for (y = 0; y < s; )
            System.out.print(
                (x / n % 2 + y++ / n % 2 > 0 ? '#' : 32)
                + (y < s ? "" : "\n")
            );
}
```

The key observation here is that, on a 5 by 5 grid of *n* by *n* cells, octothorpes appear wherever the row or column number (0-based) is odd. I'm pretty sure this is the cheapest general approach, but it seems further golfable.

### Acknowledgments

- -1 byte thanks to *Kevin Cruijssen*

Comment: You can place the `int s=5*n,x=0,y` instead the for-loop to save a byte on the semicolon.

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>87</s> <s>85</s> 62 bytes

```r
m=matrix(" ",x<-scan()*5,x);m[s,]=m[,s<-rep(!1:0,e=x/5)]="#";m
```

2 bytes saved by representing c(F,T) as !1:0, thanks to LeakyNun

23 bytes saved thanks to Giuseppe

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P9c2N7GkKLNCQ0lBSafCRrc4OTFPQ1PLVKdC0zo3ulgn1jY3WqfYRrcotUBD0dDKQCfVtkLfVDPWVklZyTr3v9F/AA)

Explanation (ungolfed):

```r
x=scan()*5              # Multiply input by 5 to get the required width/height of the matrix
m=matrix(" ",x,x)       # Create a matrix of the required dimensions
s=rep(!1:0,each=x/5)    # The sequence s consists of F repeated n times, followed by T repeated n times
m[s,]="#"               # Use s as logical indices to set those rows as "#" characters.
                        # R recycles the sequence to the height of the matrix.
m[,s]="#"               # Same, with columns
write(m,"",x,,"")       # Print out across the required number of columns
```

Comment: It doesn't work on TIO because it scans the next line, which is a code.

Comment: [replace newlines with semicolons to solve the problem](https://tio.run/##K/r/P9c2N7GkKLNCQ0lBSafCRrc4OTFPQ1PLVKdC0zo3uthGtyi1QCNZw00nRFMnNTE5w7ZC31RTJ9ZWSVkJKK9TDGGVF2WWpGrk6igBzdABkpr/Tf4DAA)

Comment: [85 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/P9c2N7GkKLNCQ0lBSafCRrc4OTFPQ1PLVKdC0zo3uthGtyi1QEPR0MpAJzUxOcO2Qt9UUyfWVklZCSirUwxhlRdllqRq5OooAU3QAZKa/03@AwA)

Comment: [78 bytes](https://tio.run/##DcuxCoAgEADQX6lr0TipIJf0vkQcJBwcLkKF/HtzedvLvTNxqDk1ARNgs6rc4RFy1dikYVfQEzssVuX4ivm4dozUNi09wQLmy6lGwQij4lD2s/8 "R – Try It Online")

Comment: [67 bytes with a function](https://tio.run/##FcPBCoMwDADQe79Cs0syIljBi7RfIh5ktJBDMikVB2Pf3uGDV1ruwtDyaa8qb0Ojr0bda5EPQgdsz/lOTlfhLerKEoaSDuz9MnKKRluEBzj9tYye3FWkJsw4EQOwH6n9AQ "R – Try It Online")

Comment: @Giuseppe Good suggestions! In that last example, the savings come from  outputting a matrix rather than a single string. So can we just keep `scan()` and replace the `write` command with just `m`?

Comment: Also, a bit off-topic, but when does R allow you to abbreviate function arguments, as you did with `each`? I swear every time I try it, it fails (e.g. `cat(..., s = "")` does not work).

Comment: I don't know... I'm not 100% sure how R returns values; simply returning `m` in that case might only be a snippet unless executed in a REPL (which prints something by default). I believe R has partial matching of named arguments if there's not a `...` but I usually just try it and move on if it doesn't work, although I did know that `rep` had this behavior

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, 133 bytes

```
=REPT(REPT(REPT(REPT(" ",A1)&REPT("#",A1),2)&"
",A1)&REPT(REPT("#",5*A1)&"
",A1),2)&REPT(REPT(REPT(" ",A1)&REPT("#",A1),2)&"
",A1)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Octave, 39 bytes

```matlab
@(n)[kron(max(a=' # # ',a'),!!e(n)) '']
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f/fQSNPMzq7KD9PIzexQiPRVl1BGQjVdRLVNXUUFVOBspoK6uqx/xPzijWMNf8DAA)

Explanation:

```matlab
m = max(a=' # # ',a')  % Computes elementwise maximum of `a` and its transpose.
```

Since they have different dimensions [broadcasting](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Broadcasting.html) occurs and a `5*5` matrix (Octothorpe ASCII art of size `1`) is generated.

```matlab
One = !!e(n);          % a n*n matrix of ones
kron(m , One)          % form the Kronecker product of 'm' and 'One' 
                       % so each character converted to a n*n matrix of that character.

[  ... '']             % convert ASCII numeric values to char
```

Comment: Can you explain what this does?

Comment: @MarkS. Explanations added.

Answer (score 1):

## TeX, 240 bytes

```
\newcommand{\f}[1]{\h{\g{#1}{\h{\hphantom{\g{#1}{\#}}}{\g{#1}{\#}}\\}}{\g{#1}{\h{\g{#1}{\#}}{\g{#1}{\#}}\\}}}\newcommand{\g}[2]{\begingroup\count0=1\loop#2%
\advance\count0 by 1\ifnum\count0<#1\repeat\endgroup}\newcommand{\h}[2]{#1#2#1#2#1}
```

### Example usage

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\f}[1]{\h{\g{#1}{\h{\hphantom{\g{#1}{\#}}}{\g{#1}{\#}}\\}}{\g{#1}{\h{\g{#1}{\#}}{\g{#1}{\#}}\\}}}\newcommand{\g}[2]{\begingroup\count0=1\loop#2%
\advance\count0 by 1\ifnum\count0<#1\repeat\endgroup}\newcommand{\h}[2]{#1#2#1#2#1}

\noindent\texttt{\f{8}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 16 bytes

```apl
' #'[∘.⌈⍨⎕/5⍴⍳2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKM97b@6grJ69KOOGXqPejoe9a541DdV3/RR75ZHvZuNYkEq/iuAQRqXIReMZQRnGcNZJnCWKQA)

`' #'[`…`]` index the string with

`⍳2` first two **ɩ**ntegers; `[1,2]`

`5⍴` cyclically reshape to length five; `[1,2,1,2,1]`

`⎕/` get input (mnemonic: console) and use that to replicate, e.g. `2` → `[1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,1]`

`∘.⌈⍨` maximum table; `[[1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,1],[1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,1],[2,2,2,2,…`

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
┐/Θô¥+○╬µ^
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=bf2fe9939d2b09cee65e&i=5)

uses Zgarb's idea.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>16</s> 12 bytes

*-4 thanks to [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs)*.

```
„# 5LI×SDδ&è
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcM8ZQVTH8/D04Ndzm1RO7ziv9eh3f8NDQA) Outputs as a list of lists of characters of lines. Link includes a footer to format the output.

Comment: [12 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcM8ZQVTH8/D04Ndzm1RO7ziv9eh3f8NDQA) using `δ`.

Comment: @ovs Thanks! I knew I was underusing that

Answer (score 0):

## [Recursiva](https://github.com/officialaimm/recursiva), <s>56</s> 44 bytes

```
P+D+*aGD+*' 'a*'#'a*aG**5a'#'*aGD+*' 'a*'#'a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pNLi0qzixL/P8/QNtFWyvRHUioK6gnaqkrA4lEdy0t00QgE03i/39TAA)

Answer (score 0):

### PHP, <strike>117, 114, 112, 111</strike> 110 bytes

Php isn't optimal for short code, but it less bad than expected. Open with ?a=5 in the url

```
for(;$i++<$_GET[a];){$a.="oxox
";$b.="xxxxx
";$c.=' ';$d.='#';}echo str_replace([o,x],[$c,$d],$a.$b.$a.$b.$a);
```

---

Or a little longer, but similar

#### PHP 113 bytes

```
for(;$i++<$_GET[a];){$a.=oxoxoN;$b.=xxxxxN;$c.=' ';$d.='#';}echo str_replace([o,x,N],[$c,$d,"
"],$a.$b.$a.$b.$a);
```

Comment: With a normal PHP installation, you need <?php or at a minimum (shorttags on) <? as a preface to switch from echoing the text to running actual code. Where I commented on this elsewhere I was told there was a command-line override (which itself should mean an extra byte) but here you imply running in the normal server->browser mode with "?a=5 in the url" so it should be +2 for `<?` added at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 21 bytes

```apl
(⍴⍴'#'/⍨,)∘.⌈⍨¯1*⎕/⍳5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ooz3tv8aj3i1ApK6srv@od4WO5qOOGXqPejqA7EPrDbUe9U0FCm82BanlSvtvAgA)

Comment: Way too complicated. [See?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/140085/43319)

Comment: cool :) yours would be hard to beat

Answer (score 0):

## [Cubically [Variant]](https://github.com/TehPers/cubically-lua-variant/tree/v0.1), <s>163</s> 102 bytes

```
■f₀₂f₁₅D₁D₃B₀B₂D₁D₃B₄D₁D₃$-₀(+f₄6:7(f₅6-₀(+f₂6:7(f₃6*₅4₀+2₀@1⁶:3₁-)6:2₀-)6@₀:5₁-)6:4₀-)6
```

This is a variant of Cubically. It isn't as fun to use as the original, but it can complete certain challenges the original can't. For example, this variant has a command to set the value of each square on a face, which makes it a lot easier to store values in memory, although the number of values you can store this way is limited to the number of faces on the cube (6). You'll also see some constant values that don't need to be pulled from faces or stored in the notepad before use. For example, `₂` which passes the value `32` to the command.

<s>I don't think I'll be changing the language enough to break this code in the future</s> (`f` is changing to `ƒ` but does the same thing), but because this branch of the language is constantly changing, I've included a link to the commit this can run on in the header.

This solution creates a 5x5x5 cube and sets the left face to this:

```
01010
11111
01010
11111
01010
```

It then sets the value of face 0's squares to 32 and the value of face 1's and face 2's squares to 35, essentially creating a 1-width octothorpe on the left of the cube:

```
 # # 
#####
 # # 
#####
 # #
```

Then it goes through each square on the left face and enlarges it.

#### How it works

```
■                   Set the cube to a new 5x5x5 cube
f₀₂f₁₅             Set face 0's values to 32 and face 1's values to 35
D₁D₃B₀B₂D₁D₃B₄D₁D₃ Create an octothorpe on face 1
$                    Input a number
-₀(                 Set the notepad to -5, and loop while notepad != 0
  +                   Add 5 to the notepad
  f₄6                  Set face 4's values to the notepad
  :7(                  Set the notepad to the input, and loop while notepad != 0
    f₅6                  Set face 5's values to the notepad
    -₀(                 Set the notepad to -5, and loop while notepad != 0
      +                   Add 5 to the notepad
      f₂6                  Set face 2's values to the notepad
      :7(                  Set the notepad to the input, and loop while notepad != 0
        f₃6                  Set face 3's values to the notepad
        *₅4₀                 Set the notepad to the value of the first square on the 4th face times 5
        +2₀                  Add the value of the first square on the 2nd face
        @1⁶                  Output the character with the ASCII value equal to the square on the 1st face with index equal to the notepad
        :3₁-                Set the notepad to the first square on the 3rd face minus 1
      )6
      :2₀-                Set the notepad to the first square on the 2nd face minus 4
    )6
    @₀                  Output \n
    :5₁-              Set the notepad to the first square on the 5th face minus 1
  )6
  :4₀-              Set the notepad to the first square on the 4th face minus 4
)6
```

<s>I've actually found a way to easily create the octothorpe with only values from two faces, but I need to fix a bug in the language before that will work. It would open up the possibility of looping through the x-coordinate on the top face which would (most likely) shorten the answer.</s> Bug was fixed but it didn't affect whether that solution would work or not, so I've updated this answer.

Answer (score 0):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 29 bytes

```
5R@♀α♂i╗╜⌠╝╜⌠╛*2@%"# "E⌡MΣ⌡Mi
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8/980yOHRzIZzGx/NbMp8NHX6o6lzHvUseDR1LowxW8vIQVVJWUHJ9VHPQt9zi0Fk5v//FgA)

Comment: [28 bytes](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8/980yOHRzIZzGx/NbMp8NHX6o6lzHvUseDR1LowxW8vIQVVJWUHJ9VHPQt9zi0Hk//9GAA). You can output as a list of lines.

Comment: @Mego but it doesn't work

Comment: @LeakyNun Oh right, the space is important. Nevermind.

Answer (score 0):

## [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 36 bytes

```
/a/E #...##Sd
\i&''d?!''yy'??dS.o!@/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/18/Ud9VQVlPT09ZOTiFKyZTTV09xV5RXb2yUt3ePiVYL1/RQf//fxMA)

#### Explanation

This is a standard ordinal mode program, with two modifications:

- The `&` command is run in cardinal mode.  This allows the input to be taken as an integer.  This also forces the `&` to be run in ordinal mode later.  While `&` can be skipped with `#`, in this case I arrange for it to be a no-op.
- The end is flattened a bit to allow a space literal to be encoded in empty space, saving a byte.

The linearized program is as follows:

```
i&' d.!.'#yd?d.!a&E'#?.'#yS' ?So@

i          take input
           STACK: ["2"]
&'(space)  push " " that many times
           STACK: [" ", " "]
d          push the concatenation of the entire stack
           STACK: [" ", " ", "  "]
.!         copy this string to tape
.'#y       change all characters to #
           STACK: [" ", " ", "##"]
d          concatenate stack again
           STACK: [" ", " ", "##", "  ##"]
?d         copy string back from tape and concatenate stack again
           STACK: [" ", " ", "##", "  ##", "  ", "  ##  ##  "]
           everything below the current top of the stack is irrelevant to the rest of the program
.!         copy string to stack: this will be used to set up individual rows
a&         for every character in "\n" (all 1 of them):
  E        place that character between every pair of characters
           this will put each character on one line, to be replaced by entire rows
           STACK: [..., " \n \n#\n#\n \n \n#\n#\n \n "]
'#         push "#" on the stack
?          copy string from stack
.'#y       replace all characters with #
           STACK: [..., " \n \n#\n#\n \n \n#\n#\n \n ", "#", "##########"]
S          substitute: replace each # with a full row of #s
' ?S       replace each space with the row "  ##  ##  " created earlier
o          output
@          terminate
```

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 59 bytes

```
Table[If[OddQ@*Ceiling/@(i/#&&j/#)," ","#"],{i,5#},{j,5#}]&
```

#### Explanation

The input is `#`. Make a `Table` that's `5#`(implied multiplication) by `5#` where the variables `i` and `j` range from `1`(default) to `5#`. The entries in the table will be `" "` or `"#"` depending on `If` a condition is true.

The condition is a little complicated. Ungolfed, it's equivalent to `And[Composition[OddQ, Ceiling][i/#],Composition[OddQ, Ceiling][j/#]]`. We test if the `Ceiling` of `i/#` is odd `And` similarly for `j/#`. But this is golfed into `OddQ@*Ceiling/@(i/#&&j/#)` by:

- Using the fact that `Map` works for anything, not just lists, so we can write this as `Map[Composition[OddQ, Ceiling],And[i/#,j/#]]`
- Using the facts that `&&`, `/@`, and `@*` are infixes for `And`, `Map`, and `Composition`, respectively (adding parentheses to handle the fact that `&&` doesn't have higher precedence than `/@`).

### Try it online

You can try this in [the Wolfram Cloud Sandbox](https://sandbox.open.wolframcloud.com) by pasting code like:

```
Table[If[OddQ@*Ceiling/@(i/#&&j/#)," ","#"],{i,5#},{j,5#}]&@4//Grid
```

and pressing Shift+Enter or numpad Enter or clicking Gear>Evaluate cell.

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <strike>225</strike> <strike>192</strike> <strike>169</strike> <strike>165</strike> <strike>161</strike> <strike>160</strike> 158 bytes

```cs
using System;class P{static void Main(string[]args){for(int n=int.Parse(args[0]),d=5*n,i=0;i<d*d;)Console.Write(" ##"[i/d/n%2+i%d/n%2]+(i++%d<d-1?"":"\n"));}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYq9CsIwGABfJaQUEtM/FRfb4uAsFBwcaoeQxPJBTSBfFKT02WN1uRvuFObKeRPjC8GO5PrBYJ61miQi6WYMMoAibweaXCRYhsGvWz9IPyKfH84zsIHYdmXRSY@G/UpfDTzT7WFjM2irGhq90TU/O4tuMsXNQzCMkiShPZS6tOlOQPr3IBgIkepG59sTpUd6t5TzellijPv4BQ)

### Explanation:

Using the 1D array (representing a 2D array) row and column approach from before, I changed the area array to be the symbols to print, and as such, there are only two types of rows. The `i/d/n%2*5` selects the appropriate row in the string array, and `i%d/n` selects the column.

#### Update

I simplified the string further, as each row has repetitions, so now it only looks at the first two characters of each row. Actually, I got the string down a # and simplified the equation. I'm sure the equation and the newline calculation could be shortened.

```cs
for(int n=int.Parse(args[0]),d=5*n,i=0;i<d*d;)
{
    Console.Write(" ##"[i/d/n%2+i%d/n%2]+(i++%d<d-1?"":"\n"));
}
```

<strike>Treat the octothorpe as a 5x5 area</strike>

```cs
var x=new[]{0,1,0,1,0}
```

The areas are accessed by a 1D array, where if the index is in a given area print " " otherwise print "#". Each area is determined by row and column position, `i/d` and `i%d`, respectively, then adjusted given `n`. Using `x`, both horizontally and vertically, gives the different areas as (0,0), (0,1), (1,0), and (1,1). If the area is (0,0) it should be " ", otherwise use "#".

```cs
for(;i<d*d;)
{
    Console.Write((x[i/d/n]+x[i%d/n]<1?" ":"#")+(i++%d==d-1?"\n":""));
}
```

(First time on code-golf, so comments or suggestions appreciated)

Comment: [144 bytes](https://tio.run/##Hca9CsIwFEDhVwkphaSpbVFcrNXBWSg4ONQOIYlyod5AbhCk9Nnjz3K@Y2hlfHApmUkTsX6mqCMY9vJg2VkDCooB8DGMWs53HwRgZNh9W/U6kBN6aEZZ2m5bYAld08LeFraVlzdF96xOHslPrroGiE5wlmV8gNrWmK8V5H9HJdTvD82R8x2/IZeyXZaU0uYD "C# (.NET Core) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

### TXR Lisp, <s>158 141 133 124</s> 122 bytes

```
(do each((i #1=(range* 0(* @1 5))))(each((j #1#))(pprint[[(repeat'(" # # ""#####"))(trunc i @1)](trunc j @1)]))(put-line))
```

Uncondensed:

```
(do each ((i #1=(range* 0 (* @1 5))))
  (each ((j #1#))
    (pprint [[(repeat '(" # # " "#####")) (trunc i @1)] (trunc j @1)]))
  (put-line))
```

Simply scale the basic 5x5 "bitmap" by backwards mapping from screen character coordinates into the texture.

Run:

```
1> (do each((i #1=(range* 0(* @1 5))))(each((j #1#))(pprint[[(repeat'(" # # ""#####"))(trunc i @1)](trunc j @1)]))(put-line))
#<interpreted fun: lambda (#:arg-01-0169 . #:rest-0168)>
2> [*1 1]
 # # 
#####
 # # 
#####
 # # 
nil
3> [*1 3]
   ###   ###   
   ###   ###   
   ###   ###   
###############
###############
###############
   ###   ###   
   ###   ###   
   ###   ###   
###############
###############
###############
   ###   ###   
   ###   ###   
   ###   ###   
nil
4> [*1 4]
    ####    ####    
    ####    ####    
    ####    ####    
    ####    ####    
####################
####################
####################
####################
    ####    ####    
    ####    ####    
    ####    ####    
    ####    ####    
####################
####################
####################
####################
    ####    ####    
    ####    ####    
    ####    ####    
    ####    ####    
nil
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 28 bytes

```
ð\#3*+2/2(ƛøm;øm)ƛƛ?*;ṅ;ƛ?(,
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%C3%B0%5C%233*%2B2%2F2%28%C6%9B%C3%B8m%3B%C3%B8m%29%C6%9B%C6%9B%3F*%3B%E1%B9%85%3B%C6%9B%3F%28%2C&inputs=5&header=&footer=)

What. A. Mess.

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 bytes

```
⁾ #ŒḄ⁺xµ»þ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASIA3f9qZWxsef//4oG@ICPFkuG4hOKBunjCtcK7w77/w4dZ//8z)

Another one using Zgarb's idea.

```
   ŒḄ         Palindromize
⁾ #           " #".
     ⁺        Palindromize it again. (" # # ")
      x       Repeat that by the input,
       µ»þ    then table it with itself by maximum.
```