# ASCII Triangles

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

Your task is to write a program or a function that prints an ASCII triangle. They look like this:

```
|\
| \
|  \
----
```

Your program will take a single numeric input `n`, with the constraints `0 <= n <= 1000`. The above triangle had a value of `n=3`.

The ASCII triangle will have `n` backslashes (`\`) and vertical bars (`|`), `n+1` lines and dashes (`-`), and each line will have an amount of spaces equal to the line number (0-based, ie first line is line 0) besides the ultimate line.

### Examples:

Input:

```
4
```

Output:

```
|\
| \
|  \
|   \
-----
```

Input:

```
0
```

Output:

In this test case, the output must be empty. No whitespace.

Input:

```
1
```

Output:

```
|\
--
```

Input & output must be **exactly** how I specified.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so aim for the shortest code possible!

Comment: [related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/95780/draw-an-asterisk-triangle)

Comment: Does it need to be a program or can it be a function?

Comment: I think it would be better if case `0` can have any unexpected output since it is an edge case (especially since you requested that the number of dashes must be one more than the input number)

Comment: FYI: You can use `<pre><br></pre>` to have an empty code block (so you don't need an `(empty)`

Comment: @TuukkaX as I said, output must be exactly as specified.

Comment: @LliwTelracs you can see in the top that I said a program.

Comment: @Okx There are frequently questions where the asker says program but really meant program or function. You might want to clarify that you are asking for a FULL program

Comment: @LliwTelracs changed. Do you think I should allow functions?

Comment: @Okx I feel it is your choice but would prefer that there wasn't the additional restriction.

Comment: **I** would definitely go for both program and function. That's the default rule if nothing else is specified. I would also remove the 0-edge case since it's a direct violation of "_n+1 lines and dashes (-)_".

Comment: The challenge would be too simple without the size=0 exception. Part of the challenge is figuring out a way to account for this with the least amount of extra code.

Comment: I second @12Me12 - even if not intended, the edge case gives an... edge to the challenge. And changing challenges posted after answers are submitted is bad form.

Comment: @StewieGriffin a single dash wouldn't be a triangle, would it? :P

Comment: Is it acceptable to return the string? Or is printing mandatory? Quite a few answers here (including mine) are returning a string to save a few bytes.

Comment: @adrianmp Since people have been doing both, I'd say you can return the string

Comment: I assume that PETSCII substitutes for the ASCII characters are okay if it's for a C64/PET/VIC-20 etc...?

Comment: My original idea for suppressing output for `x = 0` was originally `x and x+1` but apparently that's not very efficient...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 14 bytes

```
’⁶x⁾|\jṄµ€Ṫ”-ṁ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#ASQA2///4oCZ4oG2eOKBvnxcauG5hMK14oKs4bmq4oCdLeG5gf///zQ)

#### How it works.

```
’⁶x⁾|\jṄµ€Ṫ”-ṁ  Main link. Argument: n

        µ       Combine the links to the left into a chain.
         €      Map the chain over [1, ..., n]; for each k:
’                 Decrement; yield k-1.
 ⁶x               Repeat the space character k-1 times, yielding a string.
   ⁾\j            Join the character array ['|', '\'], separating by those spaces.
      Ṅ           Print the result, followed by a linefeed.
         Ṫ      Tail; extract the last line.
                This will yield 0 if the array is empty.
          ⁾-ṁ   Mold the character '-' like that line (or 0), yielding a string
                of an equal amount of hyphen-minus characters.
```

Answer (score 11):

## C, 58 bytes

```
i;f(n){for(i=2*n;~i--;printf(i<n?"-":"|%*c\n",2*n-i,92));}
```

--

Thanks to @Steadybox who's comments on [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/109512/16513) helped me shave a few bytes in my above solution

Comment: I managed to reach 68, was pretty proud of myself.. and then I scrolled :( -- Well done!

Comment: Very nice! Have a +1

Comment: I have `2*n` in there twice and it bothers me, can anyone think of a clever way to shorten it somehow?

Comment: [-1 byte](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/TOk0jT7M6Lb9II9NWMc86U1vbxtZIK8@6oCgzryRNI9Muz15JV8lKqUZVKzkmT0knU8fSSFPTuvZ/bmJmnoZmNVdBaUmxhpKJkibQJBNNawgXyINKGIAlDDAlDMEShsgStf8B) and fixes bug for `n=0`

Comment: @att Nice! I knew there'd be a way, wow 3 years later too!

Answer (score 8):

### Javascript (ES6), <s>97</s> <s>85</s> <s>81</s> <s>75</s> 74 bytes

```
n=>(g=(n,s)=>n?g(--n,`|${" ".repeat(n)}\\
`+s):s)(n,"")+"-".repeat(n&&n+1)
```

Turns out I wasn't using nearly enough recursion

```js
f=n=>(g=(n,s)=>n?g(--n,`|${" ".repeat(n)}\\
`+s):s)(n,"")+"-".repeat(n&&n+1)

console.log(f(0))
console.log(f(1))
console.log(f(2))
console.log(f(3))
console.log(f(4))
```

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>16</s> <s>15</s> 16 bytes

Saved a byte thanks to *Adnan*

```
FðN×…|ÿ\}Dg'-×»?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#ARsA5P//RsOwTsOX4oCmfMO/XH1EZyctw5fCuz///zQ)

**Explanation**

```
F       }         # for N in range [0 ... input-1]
 ðN×              # push <space> repeated N times
    …|ÿ\          # to the middle of the string "|\"
         Dg       # get length of last string pushed
           '-×    # repeat "-" that many times
              »   # join strings by newline
               ?  # print without newline
```

Comment: `ð×.svy¦…|ÿ\}¹>'-×»`, guess my idea of `.s` wasn't as good as I thought. Nice use of `ÿ`, haven't seen that before.

Comment: @carusocomputing: I considered `.s` as well as starting with `<Ýð×` but ran into trouble with the special case with those methods.

Comment: `FðN×…|ÿ\}Dg'-×»` for 15 bytes

Comment: @Adnan: Nice catch with `Dg`! Thanks :)

Comment: `.s` also resulted in nested arrays and flattening which required more bytes.

Comment: Trailing newlines not allowed, sorry!

Comment: @carusocomputing: Building the list with `.p` and then flattening would have saved a byte there. Still would have been two bytes or so longer than this.

Comment: @Okx: That is now fixed.

Answer (score 5):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), <s>18</s> <s>17</s> 16 bytes

*1 byte saved thanks to @nmjcman101 for using another way of outputting nothing if the input is `0`*

```
é\é|ÀñÙá ñÒ-xÀ«D
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@394ZczhlTWHGw5vPDzz8EIFIDVJt@Jww6HVLv///zcAAA)

Hexdump:

```
00000000: e95c e97c c0f1 d9e1 20f1 d22d 78c0 ab44  .\.|.... ..-x..D
```

#### Explanation (outdated)

We first have a loop to check if the argument is `0`. If so, the code below executes (`|\` is written). Otherwise, nothing is written and the buffer is empty.

```
Àñ     ñ            " Argument times do:
  é\é|              " Write |\
      h             " Exit loop by creating a breaking error
```

Now that we got the top of the triangle, we need to create its body.

```
Àñ   ñ              " Argument times do:
  Ù                 " Duplicate line, the cursor comes down
   à<SPACE>         " Append a space
```

Now we got one extra line at the bottom of the buffer. This has to be replaced with `-`s.

```
Ó-                  " Replace every character with a -
   x                " Delete the extra '-'
```

---

This answer would be shorter if we could whatever we want for input `0`

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), <s>14</s> 13 bytes

```
é\é|ÀñÙá ñÒ-x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@394ZczhlTWHGw5vPDzz8EIFIDVJt@L///8mAA)

Comment: I should not have tried that hard for a byte [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@394ZczhlTWHGw5vPDzz8EIFIDVJt@Jww6HVLv///zcAAA "V – TIO Nexus")

Comment: @nmjcman101 Ah, `«` of course. Clever! :)

Answer (score 4):

## C#, 93 bytes

```
n=>{var s=n>0?new string('-',n+1):"";while(n-->0)s="|"+new string(' ',n)+"\\\n"+s;return s;};
```

Anonymous function which returns the ASCII triangle as a string.

Full program with ungolfed, commented function and test cases:

```
using System;

class ASCIITriangles
{
    static void Main()
    {
      Func<int, string> f =
      n =>
      {
          // creates the triangle's bottom, made of dashes
          // or an empty string if n == 0
          var s = n > 0 ? new string('-', n + 1) : "";

          // a bottom to top process
          while ( n-- > 0)
          // that creates each precedent line
            s = "|" + new string(' ', n) + "\\\n" + s;

          // and returns the resulting ASCII art
          return s;
      };

      // test cases:
      Console.WriteLine(f(4));
      Console.WriteLine(f(0));
      Console.WriteLine(f(1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), <s>51</s> 67 bytes

```powershell
param($n)if($n){1..$n|%{"|"+" "*--$_+"\"};write-host -n ('-'*++$n)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/powershell#@1@QWJSYq6GSp5mZBiKrDfX0VPJqVKuVapS0lRSUtHR1VeK1lWKUaq3LizJLUnUz8otLFHTzFDTUddW1tLWBWmr///9vAgA)

*(Byte increase to account for no trailing newline)*

Takes input `$n` and verifies it is non-zero. Then loops to construct the triangle, and finishes with a line of `-`. Implicit `Write-Output` happens at program completion.

Comment: The program prints a trailing newline but I asked output to be exactly as specified, sorry!

Comment: @Okx Changed at a cost of 16 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), <s>24</s> <s>22</s> 21 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to Martin Ender*

```
ri_{S*'|\'\N}%\_g+'-*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@1@UGV8drKVeE6Me41erGhOfrq2uq/X/vxEA)

**Explanation**

```
ri                     e# Take an integer from input
  _                    e# Duplicate it
   {                   e# Map the following to the range from 0 to input-1
    S*                 e#   Put that many spaces
      '|               e#   Put a pipe
        \              e#   Swap the spaces and the pipe
         '\            e#   Put a backslash
           N           e#   Put a newline
            }%         e# (end of map block)
              \        e# Swap the top two stack elements (bring input to the top)
               _g+     e# Add the input's signum to itself. Effectively this increments any 
                       e#  non-zero number and leaves zero as zero.
                  '-*  e# Put that many dashes
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 69 bytes

```python
lambda x:'\n'.join(['|'+' '*n+'\\'for n in range(x)]+['-'*-~x*(x>0)])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#FcpBCsIwEAXQvaeY3Z8kbangqmAvkmSRopERnZZQIQvx6pG@9cvX0F7pvdwS1QlBMTxXUfb4woFg1SEE5LWQkiiVpI87VxOdRw/b/6rlOo8mmnYcOY7o9tnZTCfaiuhOmcU0P3bn7hL/)

Comment: If you're printing it, you can save a few bytes by changing to python3, removing `"".join` and replacing it with the `*` operator and the `sep` argument in the sleep function, so `lambda x:print(*['|'+' '*n+'\\'for n in range(x)]+['-'*-~x*(x>0)],sep="\n")`

Answer (score 3):

## bash + printf, 68 bytes

```
for((;i<$1;))
{
a=$a-
printf "|%$[i++]s\\\\\n"
}
[ $a ] && echo $a-
```

Use "bash *program_name* *number*" to run. Sample run:

```
bash-4.1$ bash triangle 0
bash-4.1$ bash triangle 1
|\
--
bash-4.1$ bash triangle 2
|\
| \
---
bash-4.1$ bash triangle 3
|\
| \
|  \
----
```

Comment: Very nice. [Shaved 3 bytes](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/Py2/SEPDOtNGxdBaU9O6WiHRViVRl6ugKDOvJE1BqUZVJTpTWzu2OAYE8pSsa7miFVQSFWLV1FKTM/KBTN3///@bAgA)

Answer (score 2):

## SmileBASIC, 51 bytes

```
INPUT N
FOR I=0TO N-1?"|";" "*I;"\
NEXT?"-"*(N+!!N)
```

Answer (score 2):

### C <s>101</s> <s>93</s> 75 bytes

```
f(n){i;for(i=0;i++<n;)printf("|%*c\n",i,92);for(;n--+1;)prin‌​tf("-");}
```

Ungolfed version

```
void f(int n)
{
  int i;

  for(i=0;i++<n;)
    printf("|%*c\n",i,92);

  for(;n--+1;)
    printf("-");

}
```

@Steadybox Thanks for pointing out, makes a lot of sense.

Comment: You can shave off a few bytes by replacing character constants with their ASCII value and moving the first i++ in the loop body. And why is `printf("%c",'_');` so verbose?

Comment: @Jens stimmt, Danke sehr :) Updated

Comment: This can be cut down to 74 bytes: `i;f(n){for(i=0;i++<n;)printf("%c%*c\n",124,i,92);for(;n--+1;)printf("-");}`

Comment: To 69 bytes, actually: `i;f(n){for(i=0;i++<n;)printf("|%*c\n",i,92);for(;n--+1;)printf("-");}`

Comment: @Steadybox 68: `n--+1` can be shortened to `~n--`

Comment: @Steadybox No need for two for loops, I can get it down to 58 bytes but at that point it's a totally different answer so I've posted it here: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/109541/16513

Comment: @Steadybox Thanks for pointing out and saving 18 bytes

Answer (score 2):

## Common Lisp, <del>89</del> 86 bytes

Creates an anonymous function that takes the n input and prints the triangle to `*standard-output*` (stdout, by default).

### Golfed

```
(lambda(n)(when(< 0 n)(dotimes(i n)(format t"|~v@t\\~%"i))(format t"~v,,,'-<~>"(1+ n))))
```

### Ungolfed

```
(lambda (n)
  (when (< 0 n)
    (dotimes (i n)
      (format t "|~v@t\\~%" i))
    (format t "~v,,,'-<~>" (1+ n))))
```

I'm sure I could make this shorter somehow.

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 39 bytes

```
.*
$*
*\`(?<=(.*)).
|$.1$* \¶
1
-
-$
--
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#@6@nxaWixaUVk6Bhb2OroaelqanHVaOiZ6iipRBzaBuXIZcul64Kl67u///GAA)

Convert decimal input to unary. Replace each `1` with `|<N-1 spaces>\¶`, print, and undo replace. Replace each `1` with a hyphen, and the last hyphen with 2 hyphens. Tadaa!

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 60 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,k=0:k<n and'|'+' '*k+'\\\n'+f(n,k+1)or'-'[:n]*-~n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#@59mm5OYm5SSqJCnk21rYJVtk6eQmJeiXqOura6grpWtrR4TE5Onrp2mAZTXNtTML1LXVY@2yovV0q3L@19QlJlXopGmYaKp@R8A)

Two more solutions with the same byte count.

```python
f=lambda n,k=0:n and'|'+' '*k+'\\\n'+f(n-1,k+1)or-~k*'-'[:k]
f=lambda n,s='|':-~n*'-'[:n]if s[n:]else s+'\\\n'+f(n,s+' ')
```

Answer (score 2):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 98 bytes

```
256?dse1+d[q]st1=t^124*23562+dsaP2sk[[lkd256r^32*la+dsaPd1+skle>y]srle1<r]dsyx[45Ple1-dse0!>q]dsqx
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/dc#HYzLCoAgEAC/pWsStFt26vEL3sVAWiFQCt0O9eGdTTrOMExGOSzEDgTpaPiC6VoB@xo7OaAgtgrZax08lTCtHdbB/ppAsA9ufgyn4GBMhvi5dS9VoaYc22qOxcU7Z/keZ7PZbXcf)

#### Explanation

This takes due advantage of dc's `P` command, which utilizes conversion to base `256` on most systems. Therefore, for any input `n`, the program first raises `256` to the `n + 1`th power, multiplies the result by `124` (ASCII character `|`), and then adds `256*92+10=23562` to the product (where `92` is equivalent to the character `\` and `10` is the decimal value of the new-line (`\n`)). This results in a decimal number that when converted to base `256` with `P` results in the output `|\\n` where `\n` is the literal new-line character. A duplicate of this decimal number is also stored on top of register `a`.

Then, a "macro-loop" is invoked, as long as `n > 1`, in which a counter is incremented until `n`, beginning from `2`, and, as the 3rd through `n`th base `256` digits are unset, `256` is raised to each of those increments, a result which is then multiplied by `32` (the ASCII single space character). Then the value on top of register `a` is incremented by the resulting product, thus, on each iteration, setting each one of the unset base `256` digits in the between the `|` and the `\` characters to a single space.

Finally, after all `n-1` lines have been output, another "macro-loop" is invoked in which all the `n+1` dashes are output through the feeding of `45` to `P` on each iteration.

*Note:* The `[q]st1=t` segment makes sure that nothing is output for the input `0` by checking if the incremented input is equal to one, and if it is, simply executes the macro `[q]` which exits the program.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 15 bytes

```
Ｎβ¿β«↓β→⁺¹β↖↖β»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/charcoal#@/9@z7pzmw7tB@LVj9omn9v0qG3So8Zdh3aCWNOACCix@/9/AwA)

### Breakdown

```
Ｎβ¿β«↓β→⁺¹β↖↖β»
Ｎβ               assign input to variable β
   ¿β«         »  if β != 0:
      ↓β           draw vertical line β bars long
        →⁺¹β       draw horizontal line β+1 dashes long
            ↖      move cursor up one line and left one character
             ↖β    draw diagonal line β slashes long
```

Comment: Very late comment, but the closing `»` can be omitted.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 20 bytes

Saved 2 bytes thanks to @ETHproductions

```
o@'|+SpX +'\Ãp-pUÄ)·
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@5/voF6jHVwQoaCtHnO4@dB27SBtdd2C0MMt//@bAAA)

#### Explanation

```
o@'|+SpX +'\Ãp-pUÄ)·
o                       // Creates a range from 0 to input
 @                      // Iterate through the array
  '|+                   // "|" + 
     SpX +              // S (" ") repeated X (index) times +
          '\Ã            // "\" }
             p-pU       // "-" repeated U (input) +1 times
                 Ä)·    // Join with newlines
```

Comment: Nice one! You can save a byte by pushing the last row before joining: `o@'|+SpX +'\Ãp'-pUÄ)·` and due to a bug (really an unintentional side effect of auto-functions), you can then remove the `'` in `'-`.

Comment: Actually, it's like that with all lowercase letters, not just `p`. That's so you can do e.g. `m*2` to double each element, or `mp2` to square each

Answer (score 2):

## J, 20 bytes

*-13 bytes thanks to bob*

```
*#' \|-'{~3,~2,.=@i.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qfVqxga6VgoADE/7WU1RVianTVq@uMdeqMdPRsHTL1/mtyKekpqKfZWqkr6CjUWimkFXNxpSZn5CukKRjCGKb/AQ)

### original: 33 bytes

```
(#&'| \'@(1,1,~])"0 i.),('-'#~>:)
```

#### ungolfed

```
(#&'| \' @ (1,1,~])"0 i.) , ('-'#~>:)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P81WT0FDWU29RiFG3UHDUMdQpy5WU8lAIVNPU0dDXVdduc7OSpMrNTkjXyFNweT/fwA)

Comment: 25 bytes with `*,&'-' '|',.'\'{."0~_1-i.`

Comment: 22 bytes with `*,&'-' '|',.' \'{~=@i.`

Comment: @bob That was very clever to use identity matrix

Comment: @bob thanks for the suggestion.  i've updated the post

Answer (score 2):

## Commodore BASIC (C64/128, TheC64 & Mini, VIC-20, PET, C16/+4) - 46 BASIC Bytes

```
0inputn:ifnthenfori=1ton:?"{shift+B}{left}"spc(i)"{shift+M}":next:fori=.ton:print"-";:next
```

There is a sanity check for zero, but any other positive integer will work.

Note, a C64 has 25 rows and 40 columns text (some PETs and the C128 in VDC mode has 80 columns, the VIC-20 is 22 columns by 23 rows) so the output will be skewed if you exceed the screen limit in either direction.

I've added a screenshot so that you may see the PETSCII characters that I can't make happen in this listing.

[image: Commodore C64 Triangle challenge]

Answer (score 1):

### [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 41 bytes

```
:~a>0|[a|?@|`+space$(b-1)+@\`][a+1|Z=Z+@-
```

Explanation

```
:~a>0|  Gets a, and checks if a > 0
        If it isn't the program quits without printing anything
[a|     For b=1; b <= a; b++
?@|`+   Print "|"
space$  and a number of spaces
(b-1)   euqal to our current 1-based line - 1
+@\`    and a "\"
]       NEXT
[a+1|   FOR c=1; c <= a+1; c++
Z=Z+@-  Add a dash to Z$
        Z$ gets printed implicitly at the end of the program, if it holds anything
        The last string literal, IF and second FOR loop are closed implicitly.
```

Answer (score 1):

### Pyke, <s>18</s> 17 bytes

```
I Fd*\|R\\s)Qh\-*
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=I+Fd%2a%5C%7CR%5C%5Cs%29Qh%5C-%2a&input=4)

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 19 bytes

```
?'\|- '2GXyYc!3Yc!)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@2@vHlOjq6Bu5B5RGZmsaAzEmv//GwMA)

```
?         % Implicit input. If non-zero
  '\|- '  %   Push this string
  2       %   Push 2
  G       %   Push input
  Xy      %   Identity matrix of that size
  Yc      %   Prepend a column of 2's to that matrix
  !       %   Transpose
  3       %   Push 3
  Yc      %   Postpend a column of 3's to the matrix
  !       %   Transpose
  )       %   Index into string
          % Implicit end. Implicit display
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python2, 73 bytes

```
n=input()
w=0
exec'print"|"+" "*w+"\\\\"+("\\n"+"-"*-~n)*(w>n-2);w+=1;'*n
```

A full program. I also tried string interpolation for the last line, but it turned out be a couple bytes longer :/

```
exec'print"|%s\\\\%s"%(" "*w,("\\n"+"-"*-~n)*(w>n-2));w+=1;'*n
```

Another solution at 73 bytes:

```
n=j=input()
exec'print"|"+" "*(n-j)+"\\\\"+("\\n"+"-"*-~n)*(j<2);j-=1;'*n
```

## Test cases

```
0:

1:
|\
--

2:
|\
| \
---

3:
|\
| \
|  \
----

6:
|\
| \
|  \
|   \
|    \
|     \
-------
```

Comment: I apologise for my previous comment, functions are now allowed.

Comment: @Okx No problem. This stands as a full program. I don't think I'll look into the fashion of a function solution :)

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, <s>23</s> 18 bytes

```
VQ++\|*dN\\)IQ*\-h
```

[Test suite available online.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=VQ%2B%2B%5C%7C%2adN%5C%5C%29IQ%2a%5C-h%7C&input=1&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=4%0A0%0A1&debug=0)
Thanks to [Ven](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8328/ven) for golfing off 5 bytes.

### Explanation

```
VQ++\|*dN\\)IQ*\-h
 Q           Q    Q  [Q is implicitly appended, initializes to eval(input)]
       d             [d initializes to ' ' (space)]
VQ         )         For N in range(0, eval(input)):
      *dN             Repeat space N times
   +\|                Prepend |
  +      \\           Append \
                      Implicitly print on new line
            IQ       If (input): [0 is falsy, all other valid inputs are truthy]
                 hQ   Increment input by 1
              *\-     Repeat - that many times
                      Implicitly print on new line
```

Answer (score 1):

### R, 101 bytes

```
for(i in 1:(n=scan())){stopifnot(n>0);cat("|",rep(" ",i-1),"\\\n",sep="")};cat("-",rep("-",n),sep="")
```

This code complies with the `n=0` test-case if you only consider `STDOUT` !
Indeed, the `stopifnot(n>0)` part stops the script execution, displays nothing to `STDOUT` but writes `Error: n > 0 is not TRUE` to `SDTERR`.

**Ungolfed :**

```
for(i in 1:(n=scan()))
    {
    stopifnot(n>0)
    cat("|", rep(" ", i-1), "\\\n", sep = "")
    }

cat("-", rep("-", n), sep = "")
```

Comment: Might want to fix the spelling of ungolfed

Answer (score 1):

## Befunge-98, 68 bytes

```
&:!#@_000pv<
:kg00 ',|'<|`g00:p00+1g00,a,\'$,kg00
00:k+1g00-'<@,k+1g
```

Comment: This looks like a very nice first answer, but when I try it online, [I get the wrong results](https://tio.run/nexus/befunge-98#@69mYGBQYFfGZWVgkJ5QY6deo6OuAGRmg/jZOirqMTqJOkCmoTZQGZcCCNip64IFwEqAlI7D//8mAA). Any idea what's wrong there?

Comment: @DJMcMayhem I checked it, the TIO gives `k` instruction one more execution (executes `pop()+1` times). Bug in their implementation.

Comment: @UrielEli which interpreter are you using? According to a github issue there is one weird (cfunge) that does this,like you, but all the others, including TIO work as intended (see here https://github.com/catseye/FBBI/issues/1#issuecomment-272643932)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 62 bytes

```python
n=input();s='\\'
exec"print'|'+s;s=' '+s;"*n
if n:print'-'*-~n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@59nm5lXUFqioWldbKseE6POlVqRmqxUUJSZV6Jeo65dDBJWANFKWnlcmWkKeVYQOV11Ld26vP//TQA)

Prints line by line, each time adding another space before the backslash. If a function that doesn't print would be allowed, that would likely be shorter.

Comment: Apparently, functions do not have to print.

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), 71 bytes

```js
f=
n=>console.log(' '.repeat(n).replace(/./g,'|$`\\\n')+'-'.repeat(n+!!n))
```

```html
<form onsubmit=f(+i.value);return!true><input id=i type=number><input type=submit value=Go!>
```

Outputs to the console. Save 6 bytes if printing to the SpiderMonkey JavaScript shell is acceptable. Save 13 bytes if returning the output is acceptable.

Comment: That regex is ingenious. I first tried something along those lines. I din't know about the `$\`` pattern, but don't know if I still would've thought of it. Nice.

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>82</s> 65 bytes

```hs
g 0=""
g n=((take n$iterate(' ':)"\\\n")>>=('|':))++([0..n]>>"-")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#@5@uYGCrpMSVrpBnq6FRkpidqpCnklmSWpRYkqqhrqBupakUExOTp6RpZ2eroV4D5Gtqa2tEG@jp5cXa2SnpKmn@z03MzFOwVShKTUzxyVMAqlMoKC0JLilS0FNI/28BAA) Usage:

```hs
Prelude> g 4
"|\\\n| \\\n|  \\\n|   \\\n-----"
```

Or more nicely:

```hs
Prelude> putStr $ g 4
|\
| \
|  \
|   \
-----
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 67 bytes

Another function in Python 2, using `rjust`.

```python
lambda n:('|'.join(map('\\\n'.rjust,range(n+2)))+'-'*-~n)[4:]*(n>0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#DcIxDoMwDADAva/wZhsCohVTJPgIYQiiqYyKiULYqn497enC4Mrb78vqQS3hB9vtEKXdR0LnnGKbtuvMJnl9PUnrBzPX2GDVfJWn3s4V6dhxCUcCAdH/eGVie4OYRDMEEi5TZ@6mn38)

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, 63 bytes

```
$n=shift;print'|',$"x--$_,"\\\n"for 1..$n;print'-'x++$n,$/if$n
```

Ungolfed:

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse triangle.pl
$n = shift @ARGV;
print '|', $" x --$_, "\\\n" foreach (1 .. $n);
print '-' x ++$n, $/ if $n;
```

`$"` is the list separator, which defaults to " ".  `$/` is the output record separator, which defaults to "\n".  `$_` is the implicit loop variable.

Comment: probably could save some by reading the input off of stdin?`$n=<>`?

Answer (score 1):

## bash + Unix utilities, 71 bytes

```
(($1))&&(echo '|\';(($1-1))&&$0 $[$1-1]|sed 's/|/| /;s/-/--/'||echo --)
```

Test program:

```
for n in 0 1 2 3 4 5; do echo $n; ./triangle $n; echo; done
```

Test output:

```
0

1
|\
--

2
|\
| \
---

3
|\
| \
|  \
----

4
|\
| \
|  \
|   \
-----

5
|\
| \
|  \
|   \
|    \
------
```

Answer (score 1):

## [brainf**k](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck), 256 bytes

```
[-]>[-]+[[-]>[-],[+[-----------[>[-]++++++[<------>-]<--<<[->>++++++++++<<]>>[-<<+>>]<+>]]]<]<>++++++++++[>+>+++>++++>+++++++++>++++++++++++<<<<<-]>>++>+++++>++>++++<<<<<<[>[-]+>>>>>.>[>+<<<<<.>>>>-]>[-<+>]<<<.>>+<<<<<.<<-]>>>>>>>[<<<.>>>-]<<<<<<[>>>.<<<-]
```

[Try it online!](https://copy.sh/brainfuck/?c=Wy1dPlstXStbWy1dPlstXSxbK1stLS0tLS0tLS0tLVs-Wy1dKysrKysrWzwtLS0tLS0-LV08LS08PFstPj4rKysrKysrKysrPDxdPj5bLTw8Kz4-XTwrPl1dXTxdPD4rKysrKysrKysrWz4rPisrKz4rKysrPisrKysrKysrKz4rKysrKysrKysrKys8PDw8PC1dPj4rKz4rKysrKz4rKz4rKysrPDw8PDw8Wz5bLV0rPj4-Pj4uPls-Kzw8PDw8Lj4-Pj4tXT5bLTwrPl08PDwuPj4rPDw8PDwuPDwtXT4-Pj4-Pj5bPDw8Lj4-Pi1dPDw8PDw8Wz4-Pi48PDwtXQ$$)

### How it works

```
# Read input and convert to number (https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck_algorithms#Input_a_decimal_number)
[-]>[-]+[[-]>[-],[+[-----------[>[-]++++++[<------>-]<--<<[->>++++++++++<<]>>[-<<+>>]<+>]]]<]<

# We need the characters {LF} (10); {space} (32); {minus} (45); \(92) | (120)

P1 > ++++++++++
   [
p0  < 
P1  >
P2  >  +                     
P3  >  +++
P4  >  ++++
P5  >  +++++++++
P6  >  ++++++++++++
P5  <
P4  <
P3  <
P2  <
P1  < -
   ]
P0 <           # Contains n
P1 >           # is zero
P2 >           # is {LF}
P3 > ++        # is {space}
P4 > +++++     # is {minus}
P5 > ++        # is \
P6 > ++++      # is |
p5 <
p4 <
p3 <
p2 <
p1 <
p0 <
   [           # Loop through n
P1 >[-]+       # p1 will be 1 if input was not 0; used to output the additional {minus}
p2 >
p3 >
p4 >
p5 >
p6 > .
## output p7 spaces; copy p7 to p8
p7 >
   [
p8 > +
p7 < 
p6 <
p5 <
p4 <
p3 < .  # output {space}
p4 >
p5 >
p6 >
p7 > -
   ]
## copy p8 back to p7
p8 >
   [
   -
p7 < +   
p8 >
   ]      
p7 <
p6 <
p5 < . # output \
p6 >
p7 > + # increase number of spaces
p6 <
p5 <
p4 <
p3 <
p2 < . # output {LF}
p1 <
p0 < -
   ]
p1 >
p2 >
p3 >
p4 >
p5 >
p6 >
## output p7 minuses
p7 >
   [
p6 <
p5 <
p4 < .
p5 >
p6 >
p7 > -
   ]
p6 <
p5 <
p4 <
p3 <
p2 <
## output additional minus
p1 <
  [
p2 >  
p3 >
p4 > .
p3 <
p2 <
p1 < -
  ]
```

This is my first contribution and I'm not sure whether it is allowed to re-use code from others. My code above uses the code published [in the Wiki](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck_algorithms#Input_a_decimal_number) to read the input characters and convert them into a number. Hope that's okay.

Comment: Welcome to the site! It is ok to use code that is freely available here.  However I will say that we do usually allow brainfuck to take input by character code.  It does depend on the challenge a bit, because character codes are usually limited to 255, but with the right interpreter or compiler this bound is often optional.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>72</s> 71 bytes

```python
x=int(input())
for i in range(x):print('|'+' '*i+'\\')
print('-'*(x+1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v8I2M69EIzOvoLREQ1OTKy2/SCFTITNPoSgxLz1Vo0LTqqAIpEC9Rl1bXUFdK1NbPSZGXZMLKqqrrqVRoW2oqfn/vwkA)

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 62 bytes

```python
x=input()
for i in range(x):print'|'+' '*i+'\\'
print'-'*(x+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v8I2M6@gtERDkystv0ghUyEzT6EoMS89VaNC06qgKDOvRL1GXVtdQV0rU1s9JkadCyKmq66lUaFtqPn/vwkA)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! You can remove three of your spaces to save 3 bytes.

Comment: @Stephen, thanks! One question since im new, how do you cross out the previous score in the title?

Comment: You can use a <s> tag, so like `<s>72</s>`.

Comment: You can actually remove all the spaces so that the for loop is on one line. Additionally, the last line of dashes should be one longer

Answer (score 1):

## C, <s>115</s> 112 bytes

```c
i,n,w;f(){if(n){for(i=n;i--;){w=n-i;printf("|");for(;0<--w;)printf(" ");puts("\\");}for(i=n;~i--;)printf("-");}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NU5LCsIwEL2KRIQM7UhduJrGk2QjqdEJOi390EWsV6@Nkt3j/R3enVv3LO45Nbd6GBtuj4/LyqWUM3kNkb0WiL7tNRshRiSIsxFk6nqW0Wv1VkBJp6pGnAkyv9v4bhoHrazd4JI7Pr@S7MIkLWug15VF/5eCqSjUpzOFooCYnVYOjRVVBiAxIZ1LwS8)

## x86-32 machine code, 87 bytes

```
bd00 8089 ecbb 0400 83fb 0074 fe89 d989
d829 c850 b40e b07c cd10 5851 89c1 4183
f901 7502 7408 50b4 0eb0 20cd 1058 90e2
ee50 b40e b05c cd10 5850 b40e b00a cd10
b00d cd10 5859 e2c7 89d9 4150 b40e b02d
cd10 58e2 f6eb fe
```

**To boot, pad it to 510 bytes with zeros and add `55aa` at the end!**
**This means "add `times 510 - ($-$$) db 0` and `db 0xaa55` to the ungolfed assembly code".**

Ungolfed (compilable, compile using `nasm -fbin -o triangles triangles.asm`):

````
[org 0x7c00]
[bits 16]

    mov bp, 8000h ; set up stack
    mov sp, bp

    mov bx, 4 ; N

    ; cx = i, bx = n, ax = w
    cmp bx, 0 ; if n == 0, don't print anything
    je $
    mov cx, bx ; i = n
    l1: ; first for
        mov ax, bx
        sub ax, cx ; w = n - i
        push ax
        mov ah, 0eh
        mov al, '|'
        int 10h ; print |
        pop ax
        push cx
        mov cx, ax
        inc cx
        l2: ; second for (prints whitespaces)
            cmp cx, 1 ; if (i != 1) print " "; - there was a bug with first \ printing far right from the triangle
            jne l2_1
            je l2_2
            l2_1:
                push ax
                mov ah, 0eh
                mov al, ' '
                int 10h
                pop ax
            l2_2:
                nop
        loop l2 ; while i < 0 l2(); i--;
        push ax
        mov ah, 0eh
        mov al, '\'
        int 10h ; print backslash
        pop ax
        push ax
        mov ah, 0eh
        mov al, 0ah
        int 10h
        mov al, 0dh
        int 10h ; print newline
        pop ax
        pop cx
    loop l1 ; while i < 0 l1(); i--;
    mov cx, bx ; i = n
    inc cx ; i++
    l3: ; third for (prints dashes)
        push ax
        mov ah, 0eh
        mov al, '-'
        int 10h
        pop ax
    loop l3 ; while i < 0 l3(); i--;

    jmp $ ; hang forever
```
````

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <sup><s>41</s></sup> 33 bytes

```apl
{×⍵:↑({'\',⍨⍵↑'|'}¨⍳⍵),⊂'-'⍴⍨⍵+1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v/rw9Ee9W60etU3UqFaPUdd51LsCyAdy1WvUaw8B2ZuBXE2dR11N6rrqj3q3QOS1DWv/pz1qm/Cot@9RV/Oj3jVAmUPrjYHaHvVNDQ5yBpIhHp7B/9MUDLjSFAyB2AiIjYHYBIhNAQ)

-7 bytes from Adám.

-1 byte using signum function.

#### Explanation

```apl
{×⍵:↑({'\',⍨⍵↑'|'}¨⍳⍵),⊂'-'⍴⍨⍵+1} ⍝ ⍵=n
 ×⍵:                              ⍝ If sign(n)
                        '-'⍴⍨⍵+1  ⍝ Repeat '-' n+1 times
                       ⊂          ⍝ Enclose it to a single string
                      ,           ⍝ Join with
                 }¨⍳⍵             ⍝ for each x in range 1..n
            ⍵↑'|'                 ⍝ Inner fn: take x characters from '|' appending spaces
      '\',⍨                       ⍝ Reverse join with '\'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v9rA5lHvVqvqR31TH7VNADJrD63QqNYAMh61TVSvUdfUUY9RB4o96t0MFNPUedTVBJLUNtR81LtFXVe99n8aWF/fo67mR71rgIKH1hsDtQLNCw5yBpIhHp7B/9MUDLjSFAyB2AiIjYHYBIhNAQ)

Comment: [34](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v9rA5lHvVqtHbRM1qtVj1HUe9a4A8oFc9Rr12kNA9mYgV1PnUVeTuq76o94tEHltw9r/aY/aJjzq7XvU1fyodw1Q5tB6Y6C2R31Tg4OcgWSIh2fw/zQFA640BUMgNgJiYyA2AWJTAA "APL (Dyalog Unicode) – Try It Online")

Comment: @Adám leaving it unmixed gives an interesting pattern.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-n`, 21 bytes

```
IaO['|.sX,a.'\'-Xa+1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P/fM9E/Wr1GrzhCJ1FPPUZdNyJR2zD2////unn/DQE)

#### Explanation

```
IaO['|.sX,a.'\'-Xa+1]
                       s is space; a is 1st command-line arg (implicit)
Ia                     If a is nonzero:
  O                     Output this expression without a trailing newline:
   [                ]    A list containing these two items:
       sX,a               A list of increasing runs of spaces
    '|.                    with a pipe character concatenated to the front of each run
           .'\             and a slash concatenated to the back
              '-Xa+1      A string of a+1 hyphens
```

For example: with an input of 3, the list will be `[["|\"; "| \"; "|  \"]; "----"]`. The -n flag separates all items of a list with newlines when it is printed, so we get

```
|\
| \
|  \
----
```

The if statement means the program does nothing if the input `a` is 0, as required.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `Ṁosr`, 12 bytes

```
⟑I‛|\j…;tƛ\-
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyLhuYBvc3IiLCIiLCLin5FJ4oCbfFxcauKApjt0xptcXC0iLCIiLCI0Il0=)

Flags FTW

```
⟑I‛|\j…;tƛ\-
⟑             # Over each in [0, n) (not [1, n] thanks to Ṁ flag)
 I            # Push n spaces
  ‛|\j        # Join ['|', '\'] by that (r flag makes the arguments reversed)
      …       # Print it with a trailing newline (without popping)
       ;      # Close loop
        t     # Get the last element
         ƛ\-  # Replace each with a hyphen
              # o flag - force implicit output
              # s flag - join this list of hyphens to a single string
```

Answer (score 0):

### Javascript 101(Full Program), 94(Function Output), 79(Return) bytes

Full Program

Will not run in Chrome (as process doesn't exist apparently)
Will not run in TIO (as prompt apparently isn't allowed)

```javascript
x=prompt();s='';for(i=0;i<x;i++)s+='|'+' '.repeat(i)+`\\
`;process.stdout.write(s+'-'.repeat(x&&x+1))
```

Function with EXACT print

```javascript
x=>{s='';for(i=0;i<x;)s+='|'+' '.repeat(i++)+`\\
`;process.stdout.write(s+'-'.repeat(x&&x+1))}
```

[Try it Online](https://tio.run/#MSOAv)

Function with return string

```javascript
x=>{s='';for(i=0;i<x;)s+='|'+' '.repeat(i++)+`\\
`;return s+'-'.repeat(x&&x+1)}
```

[Try it Online](https://tio.run/#6phGd)

Repeating characters in Javascript is dumb and so is suppressing newlines on output

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 82 bytes

```python
def f(i,c=0):
 if c<i:print'|'+' '*c+'\\';f(i,c+1)
 print'-'*((c+1,c)[c<1]);exit()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@5@SmqaQppGpk2xroGnFpZCZppBsk2lVUJSZV6Jeo66trqCulaytHhOjbg1WpW2oyaUAkdVV19LQAAroJGtGJ9sYxmpap1Zklmho/k/TsND8DwA)

Longer that the other Python answers but a recursive function just to be different.

It feels wasteful using two `print` statements but I can't find a shorter way round it. Also the `exit()` wastes 7 to stop it printing decreasing number of `-` under the triangle.

Comment: You can do `-~c*(c>0)` on the last line to save 3 bytes :)

Comment: Or better yet: `c and-~c`.

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript (ES6), 84 bytes

Creates an anonymous function that presents the result on an alert box. No output is present if 0.

```
i=>{for(X=i,a='';i--;)a='|'+(' '.repeat(i))+'\\\n'+a;X&&alert(a+('-'.repeat(++X)))}
```

---

If printing is really required (137 bytes):

```
i=>for(X=i,d=document.body;i--;)d.innerHTML='|'+('&nbsp;'.repeat(i))+'\\<br>'+d.innerHTML;X&&window.print(d.innerHTML+=('-'.repeat(++X)))
```

Changes the HTML code and prints the page into a paper sheet.
The page stays white if 0.

Comment: @LliwTelracs Should work now. If it is required to show the alert when it is 0, I can do it without increasing the size again.

Answer (score 0):

## Clojure, 104 bytes

```clj
(fn[h](let[r #(apply str(repeat % %2))](doseq[n(range h)](println(str\|(r n\ )\\)))(print(r(inc h)\-))))
```

At least I should have lots of room to golf from here!

Loops over the range from `0` to `h-1`, printing a `\|`, then `h`-many spaces, then a `\\`. Finally, at the end, it prints `h+1` many dashes.

```clj
(defn triangle [hypot-n]
  (let [r #(apply str (repeat % %2))] ; Create a shortcut string repeat function, since I need it twice.
    (doseq [line-n (range hypot-n)] ; Loop over the range 0 to hypot...
      (println (str \| (r line-n \ ) \\))) ; Printing a bar, then line-n many spaces, then a slash
    (print (r (inc hypot-n) \-)))) ; Then print the trailing dashes
```

Answer (score 0):

### Batch, 110 bytes

```
@set s=
@for /l %%i in (1,1,%1)do @call:c
@if %1 gtr 0 echo -%s: =-%
@exit/b
:c
@echo ^|%s%\
@set s= %s%
```

Special-casing 0 is no hardship as `%s: =-%` would fail anyway.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 66 bytes

```
f=(x,i=0)=>i<x?`|${" ".repeat(i)}\\\n`+f(x,i+1):"-".repeat(x&&i+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 57 bytes

```
Array[{"|"," "~Table~#,"\\
"}&,#,0]<>Table["-",#+Sign@#]&
```

Unnamed function taking a nonnegative integer as input and returning a string-with-newlines. It deals with the special case of input `0` by noting that the number of dashes is equal to the input plus the sign of the input.

Answer (score 0):

## [Underload](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Underload), <s>58</s> 39 bytes

```
:()~(|)~(~!((-):S~^S)~:S( )*(\
)S)~^^!^
```

Assumes the input is a Church numeral on the stack.

### Explanation

```
          stack (assume input N = 2):
            (:*)
:         keep a copy of the input on the bottom
            (:*)(:*)
()~       insert the finalization snippet
            (:*)()(:*)
(|)~      insert the accumulator
            (:*)()(|)(:*)
(...)~^^  run (...) N times:


    ~!(...)~  set finalization snippet
                (:*)((-):S~^S)(|)
    :S        output copy of accumulator
                (:*)((-):S~^S)(|)           output = |
    ( )*      append space to accumulator
                (:*)((-):S~^S)(| )          output = |
    (\;)S     output backslash and newline
               (:*)((-):S~^S)(| )          output = |\;


    ~!(...)~  set finalization snippet
                (:*)((-):S~^S)(| )
    :S        output copy of accumulator
                (:*)((-):S~^S)(| )          output = |\;| 
    ( )*      append space to accumulator
                (:*)((-):S~^S)(|  )         output = |\;| 
    (\;)S     output backslash and newline
                (:*)((-):S~^S)(|  )         output = |\;| \;

!         delete accumulator
            (:*)((-):S~^S)                  output = |\;| \;
^         execute finalization snippet:
            (:*)                            output = |\;| \;

    (-)       push hyphen
                (:*)(-)                     output = |\;| \;
    :S        output hyphen
                (:*)(-)                     output = |\;| \;-
    ~^        repeat N times
                (--)                        output = |\;| \;-
    S         print
                                            output = |\;| \;---
```

Answer (score 0):

## [8th](http://8th-dev.com/), <s>94</s> 89 bytes

**Code**

```
: f 0; dup ( "|" . ( " " . ) swap times "\\" . cr ) 0 rot n:1- loop n:1+ "-" swap s:* . ;
```

**Explanation**

The word `f` requires an integer input

```
: f \ n -- 
   0;                      \ Exit if input equals to 0
   dup                     \ Duplicate input on the stack
   ( "|" .                 \ Print a piece of the vertical side
   ( " " . ) swap times    \ Print space between sides
   "\\" . cr )             \ Print a piece of the slanted side
   0 rot n:1- loop         \ Repeat the above operation for the size required 
   n:1+ "-" swap s:* .     \ Print the bottom side
;
```

**Usage**

```
ok> 4 f
|\
| \
|  \
|   \
-----
```

Answer (score 0):

### Ruby, 48 bytes

```
->n{puts ?-*(n.times{|x|puts ?|+' '*x+?\\}+(n<=>0))}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 19 bytes

```
Ḷ×⁶j@€⁾|\;‘×”-$$YxṠ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/9wx7bD0x81bstyeNS05lHjvpoY60cNM4BCDXN1VVQiKx7uXPD//39zSwA)

Explanation:

```
Ḷ×⁶j@€⁾|\;‘×”-$$YxṠ Link 0. Arguments: z.
Ḷ                   Range from 0 to z - 1. [arg-z]
  ⁶                 Space (' ').
 ×                  Product of x and y. [multi-char-string-warning]
      ⁾|\           Two char string ("|\").
   j                Join x on y.
    @               Reverse arguments.
     €              Convert this link to a map on the left argument.
          ‘         Increment z. [arg-z]
            ”-      Character ('-').
           ×        Product of x and y. [multi-char-string-warning]
              $     Merge last two links to a monadic link.
               $    Merge last two links to a monadic link.
         ;          Concatenate x and y.
                Y   Join z on newlines ('\n').
                  Ṡ Sign of z. [arg-z]
                 x  Repeat x y times.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 75 bytes

```python
def x(n):
 if n:
  for i in range(n):print('|'+' '*i+'\\')
  print('-'*-~n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#LYoxCsAgEAT7vGK78xTLNHmLTSAarrmIGLAI@bpRSLXMzPYjJjSjvC2QBB2DdBUIRFF2PeNsuYhWQw85AllxFALxeP7ek/Wvcm9momi@q2Hmvn4)

Here's my Python 3 answer, and it's pretty long. I wonder how I can shorten it...

Thanks to Eric The Outgolfer for helping in the comments...

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 75 bytes

(70 bytes if I used extended ascii)

```
for($p=str_pad;+$i<$argv[1];)echo$p("|",++$i),"\\
";echo$p("",$i+!!$i,"-");
```

takes input from command line argument. Run with `-nr`.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3 96 bytes**

```
var a=5,b="";for c in 0..<a{var d="|";for _ in 0..<c{d+=" "};print(d+"\\");b+="-"};print(b+"-")
```

Comment: Can you do `var a=5,b="";` in Swift?

Comment: Yes its possible

Comment: Also can't you do `print(b+"-")` instead of `b+="-";print(b)`?

Comment: I guess now its perfect

Comment: Also `var a=5,b="",d;for c in 0..<a{d="|"` instead of the beginning of the loop if it works

Comment: No that will increase 1 byte as the code will become  var a=5,b="",d="";for c in 0..<a{d="|";for _ in 0..<c{d+=" "};print(d+"\\");b+="-"};print(b+"-")

Comment: In Swift either you need to initialize a variable with any value or with the type. So it's better to initialize with the value

Comment: Ah sorry, I don't know Swift

Comment: And by the way, welcome to PPCG!

Answer (score 0):

**VBA Excel, <s>68</s> 65 bytes**

Using Immediate Window and [a1] as input

```
for x=0to[a1]-1:?"|"string(x,32)"\":next:if x then?string(x+1,45)
```

Comment: You can drop this down to 65 bytes `For i=0To[A1-1]:?"|"String(i,32)"\":Next:If i Then?String(i+1,45)`

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 61 bytes

```python
n=5
q="".join(map(lambda x:"|%s\\\n"%(x*" "),range(n)))+"-"*n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@59nm5lXUFqioWldbKseE6POlVqRmqxUUJSZV6Jeo65dDBJWANFKWnlcmWkKeVYQOV11Ld26vP//TQA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 50 +2 (-ap) = 52 bytes

```perl
$_&&='|\\';say,s/\\/ $&/ while$F[0]--;s/./-/g;chop
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lXk3NVr0mJkbdujixUqdYPyZGX0FFTV@hPCMzJ1XFLdogVlfXulhfT19XP906OSO/4P9/w3/5BSWZ@XnF/3V9TfUMDA3@6yYWAAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [*Acc!!*](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Acc!!), 179 bytes

```
N
Count d while _%60-10 {
(_/60*10+_%60-48)*60+N
}
_/60
Count r while _-r {
Write 124
Count s while r-s {
Write 32
}
Write 92
Write 10
}
Count h while _+3*_/(3*_-1)-h {
Write 45
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xOTkr6/9@Pyzm/NK9EIUWhPCMzJ1UhXtXMQNfQQKGaSyNe38xAy9BAGyxkYqGpZWag7cdVywUSh@oqgunSLQLqCC/KLElVMDQygcoWQ2WLdIvhssZGQBMgTEsjmA4DoBhESwbMQG1jrXh9DSCha6ipmwHXbmLKVfv/v6ERAA)

### Explanation

Load a number into the accumulator, print that many rows of `| ... \`, and print that many (plus 1) hyphens. Unless the number is 0, in which case print 0 hyphens. No trailing newline in any case.

Most of the code is quite straightforward (handy loop variable mnemonics: `d`igit, `r`ow, `s`pace, and `h`yphen). The two interesting parts are inputting a multi-digit number and handling the 0 case.

#### Inputting a number

```
N
Count d while _%60-10 {
(_/60*10+_%60-48)*60+N
}
_/60
```

We divide the accumulator into two sections: `_%60` stores the ASCII code of the character we just read, and `_/60` stores the number we're constructing. We loop until `_%60` is `10`--that is, when we encounter a newline. Inside the loop, `_%60` is the ASCII code of the new least-significant digit. `_%60-48` is the digit itself. `_/60` is the previous value of the number, so we multiply that by 10 and add the new digit to get the new value of the number: `_/60*10+_%60-48`. Multiply that quantity by `60` and add the next input character `N`, and we're ready to loop. After the loop finishes, we set the accumulator to `_/60`, the stored number itself.

#### Handling the 0 case

```
Count h while _+3*_/(3*_-1)-h {
```

My original loop condition was `_+1-h`: loop (accumulator + 1) times. But if the accumulator is 0, we want to loop 0 times, not 1. So instead of adding 1, we add `3*_/(3*_-1)`. When `_` is 0, this quantity is 0. When `_` is greater than 0, this quantity is 1 (since `3*_` is less than twice `3*_-1`).

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, 109 bytes

```java
n->{String r="|\\\n";int i=0;for(;++i<n;r+=r.format("|%"+i+"s\\%n",""));for(;i-->=0;r+="-");return n<1?"":r;}
```

Can most likely be golfed some more.

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##nY/BasMwEETv@YplISChyiS0pypOv6C59Fj1oCpKUGqvjSQHSuJvd@Xax/Zi2D3szgy8uZirkU3r6HL8GmxlYoRX4@m2AvCUXDgZ6@AwngBvKXg6g2VZAeIqP/u8eWIyyVs4AEEJA8n9bfaGEu9aa0I1Zny5UacmMCWE35EKogxFvmuTGN7XKLzAqPWa8AGR88nqpdznWPaiRK6CS10goN32BfE5qH5QE0LbfVYZYSa5Nv4IdS7CJpD3DzB8bvEdk6uLpktFm6VUEaPCsg3/LfSn/r8yJreLk4@Lk0/Laeei/aoffgA)

```java
n->{                 // Method with integer parameter and String return-type
  String r="|\\\n";  //  Result-string, starting at "|\" + new-line
  int i=0;           //  Index-integer, starting at 0
  for(;++i<n;        //  Loop (1) from 1 to `n` (exclusive)
    r+=              //   Append to the result-String:
       r.format("|   //    A literal "|"
        %"+i+"s      //    + `i` amount of spaces
        \\           //    + a literal "\"
        %n","")      //    + a new-line
  );                 //  End of loop (1)
  for(;i-->=0;       //  Loop (2) from `n` down to 0 (inclusive)
    r+="-"           //   Append that many literal "-" to the result-String
  );                 //  End of loop (2)
  return n<1?        //  If the input was 0:
    ""               //   Return an empty String
   :                 //  Else:
    r;               //   Return the result-String
}                    // End of method
```

Answer (score 0):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 98 bytes

```
	N =INPUT
T	OUTPUT =LT(X,N) '|' DUPL(' ',X) '\'	:F(E)
	X =X + 1	:(T)
E	OUTPUT =DUPL('-',X + 1)
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/n9NPwdbTLyA0hCuE0z80BMhQsPUJ0YjQ8dNUUK9RV3AJDfDRUFdQ14kA8mPUOa3cNFw1uTgjFGwjFLQVDDmtNEI0uVzhWiHKdYHKQbJAGT@X//9NAQ)

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-R`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 14 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
°Æ'\i|úXÄÃpUç-
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI&code=sMYnXGl8%2bljEw3BV5y0&input=Mw)

```
°Æ'\i|úXÄÃpUç-     :Implicit input of integer U
°                  :Postfix increment U
 Æ                 :Map each X in the range [0,U)
  '\               :  Literal "\"
    i              :  Prepend
     |ú            :    "|" right padded with spaces to length
       XÄ          :   X+1
         Ã         :End map
          p        :Push
           Uç-     :  "-" repeated U (now incremented) times
                   :Implicit output, joined with newlines
```

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Babel Node)](https://babeljs.io/), 65 bytes

```javascript
f=(n,s=`\\
`,l)=>n?'|'+s+f(n-1,' '+s,l||'-'.repeat(n&&n+1)):l||''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FchLDoMgFADAvadgYeQRn6T2s2mDPUhtBC00GgpGTDfq2andTWZQXxW6qR/nolWttoXzLx2jEeAwCFnXiUTLROXudKV5yA24okRKdqNdV1pQPulRqxlclrm8ZOz6bxo774K3mlv/hscBSYnkiOSE5Izk8uQfNUJDREWkgXRpNpaki4GGbYlkfPC9A7mL3eIP)

Comment: Hello and welcome to PPCG; nice first answer.

Answer (score 0):

## [Haxe 4](https://haxe.org) (161 bytes)

```
class T{static function main()trace((x->x==0?"":[for(i in 0...x+1)i==x?[for(i in 0...x+2)""].join("-"):"|"+[for(i in -1...i)""].join(" ")+"\\"].join("\n"))(3));}
```

[Try Online](http://try-haxe.mrcdk.com/#0582E) (slightly bigger there since playground requires class to be called "Test")

#### Test

Save as *T.hx*, compile and run interpreted mode `haxe --run T`

### How it works

```
class T {
    static function main()
        trace(
            (x -> 
                x == 0 
                        ? "" 
                        : [for (i in 0...x + 1) 
                                i == x
                                        ? [for (i in 0...x + 2) ""].join("-") 
                                        : "|" + [for (i in -1...i) ""].join(" ") + "\\"
                ].join("\n")
            )(3)
        );
}
```

- A class and entrypoint (static function called `main`) are required in Haxe.
- `(3)` is the input
- The snippet compiles to of all [Haxe compiler targets](https://haxe.org/documentation/introduction/compiler-targets.html) (C++, JavaScript, PHP, Python, Lua, JVM, Java, etc)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 15 bytes

```
F'|NúR'\J,}ƒ'-?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fTb3G7/CuIPUYL53aY5PUde3//zc0AAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Zsh](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/), 60 bytes

```bash
for ((;i<$1;))printf "|%$[i++]s\\\\\n"&&a=$a-
(($1))&&<<<$a-
```

[Try it Online](https://tio.run/##qyrO@F@aV5xaopCokPk/Lb9IQUPDOtNGxdBaU7OgKDOvJE1BqUZVJTpTWzu2OAYE8pTU1BJtVRJ1uTQ0VAw1NdXUbGxsgNz///8bAAA). Credit to the [bash solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/110049/15940).

Answer (score 0):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 86 bytes

```
:?!;01.
!0:@>"|"o>:?va"\"oo~:&$1+:&(?!v
   "-"v>-^ ;8>1-:?!;53!.|     >
 o"-"o<^1o*4<^
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/38pe0drAUI9L0cDKwU6pRinfzsq@LFEpRik/v85KTcVQ20pNw16xjEtBQUFJV6nMTjdOwdrCzlAXpM/UWFGvRgEE7LgU8oHS@TZxhvlaJjZx////1y1TMDQAAA) - [Animated](https://mousetail.github.io/Fish/#%7B%22text%22%3A%22%3A%3F!%3B01.%5Cn!0%3A%40%3E%5C%22%7C%5C%22o%3E%3A%3Fva%5C%22%5C%5C%5C%22oo%7E%3A%26%241%2B%3A%26%28%3F!v%5Cn%20%20%20%5C%22-%5C%22v%3E-%5E%20%3B8%3E1-%3A%3F!%3B53!.%7C%20%20%20%20%20%3E%5Cn%20o%5C%22-%5C%22o%3C%5E1o*4%3C%5E%22%2C%22input%22%3A%22%22%2C%22stack%22%3A%223%22%2C%22mode%22%3A%22numbers%22%7D)

Good luck figuring this out