# Triangular Numbers

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, number

*(no, not [those ones](https://oeis.org/A000217))*

### The Challenge

You'll be given two inputs. The first is a positive integer `n > 0`, which is used to output an `n x n` right triangle of the numbers `1, 2, 3, ... n`. This triangle starts in a corner and increases horizontally and vertically by one and diagonally by two. See examples below for clarification. Keep one space between columns and keep all numbers right-aligned in their particular columns. (This is [ascii-art](/questions/tagged/ascii-art) after all).

The second input, `x`, is one of four distinct single ASCII characters of your choice that determines the triangle's starting corner (and hence orientation). For example, you could use `1,2,3,4` or `a,b,c,d` or `#,*,!,)`, etc. Please specify in your answer how the orientation works.

For clarification in this challenge, I will use `1,2,3,4` which will correspond to `1` for the upper-left, `2` for the upper-right, and so on clockwise.

### The Examples

For example, for `n = 5`, `x = 1` output the following:

```
1 2 3 4 5
2 3 4 5
3 4 5
4 5
5
```

For input `n = 11`, `x = 1` output the following (note the extra spaces so the single digits are right-aligned):

```
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
 2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
 3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
 4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
 5  6  7  8  9 10 11
 6  7  8  9 10 11
 7  8  9 10 11
 8  9 10 11
 9 10 11
10 11
11
```

With input `n=6` and `x=2` output:

```
6 5 4 3 2 1
  6 5 4 3 2
    6 5 4 3
      6 5 4
        6 5
          6
```

With input `n = 3` and `x = 4`, output:

```
3
2 3
1 2 3
```

With input `n = 1` and any `x`, output:

```
1
```

### The Rules

- Leading/trailing newlines or other whitespace are optional, provided that the numbers line up appropriately. (For example, trailing whitespace to make a square output is acceptable).
- Either a full program or a function are acceptable. If a function, you can return the output rather than printing it.
- Output can be to the console, saved as an image, returned as a list of strings, etc. [Any convenient and allowed format](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/42963).
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/42963) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so all usual golfing rules apply, and the shortest code (in bytes) wins.

Comment: This question is just [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/12377/generate-a-right-triangle) + [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/47657/print-number-triangle?rq=1).  I don't know yet but I feel like this is a dupe of one of them.

Comment: @WheatWizard I don't think answers from either of those challenges can be trivially modified to be competitive here.

Comment: To be honest I know a lot of people say thats what makes a duplicate, but as far as I can tell its not a rule.  To me a duplicate is a question that offers nothing in terms of challenge that's not provided by existing questions.

Comment: @WheatWizard [Meta consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1876/42963).

Comment: I've read that answer.  Its a recommendation in a more specific context not a universal ruling.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 bytes

```
Rṫ`z⁶ṚH}¡U⁹¡G
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASUA2v9qZWxsef//UuG5q2B64oG24bmaSH3CoVXigbnCoUf///8xMf8w)

Left argument: `n`
Right argument: `x` (`0` = top-left, `1` = top-right, `2` = bottom-left, `3` = bottom-right)

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 29 bytes

```apl
{' '@(=∘0)⌽∘⍉⍣⍺⊢↑⌽(⍳+⍵-⊢)¨⍳⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24RqdQV1Bw3bRx0zDDQf9ewF0o96Ox/1Ln7Uu@tR16JHbROBghqPejdrP@rdqgsU0Ty0AsgDcmr//9cw1H3UC@KaaCoANeqlKYBUmmoCAA)

**How?**

`¨⍳⍵` - for each `i` in range of `n`

`(⍳+⍵-⊢)` - produce range of `i` with vectorized addition of `n - i`

`↑⌽` - reverse and flatten

`⌽∘⍉` - rotate right

`⍣⍺⊢` - `x` times

`' '@(=∘0)` - remove zeros

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 18 bytes

```
:&YhiX!VZ{' 0'2:YX
```

First input is `n`.  Second input is `x`, which can be:

- `0`: top left
- `1`: bottom left
- `2`: bottom right
- `3`: top right

(Or it can be any other integer, which is interpreted modulo 4).

Try it at [**MATL Online!**](http://matl.io/?code=%3A%26YhiX%21VZ%7B%27+0%272%3AYX&inputs=11%0A0&version=20.4.2)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript <strike>130</strike> <strike>128</strike> <strike>154</strike> <strike>142</strike> <strike>138</strike> <strike>135</strike> 133 bytes

*fixed padding issues

```js
A=(n,x)=>(j=>{for(;n--;s=x<3?S+`
`+s:s+S+`
`)
for(S=O,i=j;i;S=i-->n^~-x%3?X+S:S+X)
X=(i>n?i+O:O).padStart(j.length+1)})(n+=s=O="")||s

console.log(A(6,1))
console.log(A(6,2))
console.log(A(6,3))
console.log(A(6,4))

console.log(A(12,1))
console.log(A(12,2))
console.log(A(12,3))
console.log(A(12,4))

/* 154 solution
A=(n,x)=>{s=""
for(j=n;n--;s=x<3?S+`
`+s:s+S+`
`)
for(S="",i=j;i;S=i-->n?~-x%3?S+X:X+S:~-x%3?X+S:S+X)
X=(i>n?i+"":"").padStart((j+"").length+1)
return s
}

142 solution
A=(n,x)=>{s=""
for(j=n;n--;s=x<3?S+`
`+s:s+S+`
`)
for(S="",i=j;i;S=i-->n ^ ~-x%3?X+S:S+X)
X=(i>n?i+"":"").padStart((j+"").length+1)
return s
}

138 solution
A=(n,x)=>{s=""
for(j=n+" ";n--;s=x<3?S+`
`+s:s+S+`
`)
for(S="",i=+j;i;S=i-->n^~-x%3?X+S:S+X)
X=(i>n?i+"":"").padStart(j.length)
return s
}

135 solution
A=(n,x)=>{for(j=n+=s=O="";n--;s=x<3?S+`
`+s:s+S+`
`)
for(S=O,i=j;i;S=i-->n^~-x%3?X+S:S+X)
X=(i>n?i+O:O).padStart(j.length+1)
return s
}
*/
```

Comment: @AdmBorkBork i think i fixed it now

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>124</s> 120 bytes

```python
n,x=input()
r=range(n)
for l in zip(*[(r+[n]+['']*i)[-n:]for i in r][::1-x%4/2*2])[::1-x/3*2]:print' %%%ds'%len(`n`)*n%l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcpLCsIwFEbheVeRScijLcVUOgh0JSFQwaoXwt9wjVDdfLQ4Owe@/C6PDa5WdPtMyK@iTcMzX3BfNUxz21gkQRAfytoGzW1AbINS0ZIJPXw8BB2CY/D@1O/yPDjrovnfMP7aZyYUJaSU16eSaYVesBgLmWqduvEL) or [Try all test cases](https://tio.run/##JU5BCsMgELz3FXsRV2MImrQFS18iQgpJWiFsgs0h7eetNpfZWXZ2ZtbP9lrIpDSME0xIahf2BPEeH/QckcQJpiXCDIHgG1aUDmPlyFeOcy@DcDVZXxShKKJ31up6Z11jpPHi2Jo2c7vGQBsHxtjw5mweCXvqhSQ2p/Kfg4uDw7PSQqHW/3FRJuNVtRlb1ZVD5j43PKreDleefg)

`(r+[n]+['']*i)[-n:]` will add some empty strings to the number list, and chop to the right size, `zip` with `[::1-x%4/2*2]` and `[::1-x/3*2]` will make the rotation, and `` %%%ds'%len(`n`)*n `` will generate a string for fomating (like `' %3s %3s %3s'...`) to be used on each numbers+empty string list

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 89 bytes

```
(R=Reverse;Grid[{#&,R/@#&,R[R/@#]&,R@#&}[[#2]]@PadRight@Array[Range[#,s]&,s=#]/. 0->""])&
```

here is another solution that works in TIO

## Mathematica, 122 bytes

```
(R=Reverse;StringRiffle[""<>ToString/@#&/@({#&,R/@#&,R[R/@#]&,R@#&}[[#2]]@PadRight@Array[#~Range~s&,s=#]/. 0->" "),"\n"])&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYzRCsIgGEZfRRRkA8vYRTflsDcYf92ZF1LqhGagEkS0V7eNrs4538U3mTLayZRwM9UhgWoDAuzLpmwP55JC9BCce1iF8bG/PP8Tl4Ry2XwIZbA6A7VSL7LUVynSaS0Hc4fgxyJPKZm3IjOY6O2cKcuCaL5Fu02PEW4ZvkasW1qH5bsg6dSedbr@AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 39 bytes

```
Ｎτ≔ＥτＥτ◧×‹⁺ιλτＩ⊕⁺ιλＬθσＦＮ≔⮌ＥσＥσ§μλσＥσ⪫ι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7BDoIwEETvfkXDaZvUA2dOxBMGDTH@QIUFmpSC3YX497UoGjbZzBwm86buta9HbUMo3DTzdR4e6IFldsiJTOfgoidgJTapdFNiy3A3AxKUSASVnQmMElYqwfFPmhgKV3sc0DE2u0A8JUp0HffwXD1FTjt6AXu4lGJj33BBT/jZQN8NUXIuXIMvGP6Va03ljeNf8jwatyITkcRAFkKaHtJwXOwb) Note: Trailing space. Link is to verbose version of code. Second value is number of *anticlockwise* rotations so 0 is upper left, 1 lower left, 2 lower right, 3 upper right. Explanation:

```
Ｎτ                                      Assign the first input as an integer
   ＥτＥτ                                 Map in two dimensions
               ⊕⁺ιλ                     Sum of zero-indexed coordinates plus 1
              Ｉ                         Cast to string
         ‹⁺ιλτ                          Is this the upper left triangle?
        ×                               Repeat the string once if so
       ◧           Ｌθ                   Pad to length of first input
  ≔                  σ                  Assign to variable
                          ＥσＥσ§μλ       Transpose the array
                         ⮌              Reflect the array, giving a rotation
                        ≔        σ      Reassign to variable
                       Ｎ                Second input as an integer
                      Ｆ                 Repeat that many times
                                  Ｅσ    Map over array
                                    ⪫ι  Join with spaces and implicitly print
```

Answer (score 0):

---

### Javascript (ES6), <s>241</s> <s>222</s> 214 bytes

```js
let f = 

    (n,x)=>(L=x=>(''+x).length,M=b=>x&b?(c,i,a)=>a[n-1-i]:c=>c,Array(n).fill(b=' ').map((c,i)=>b.repeat(L(n)-L(++i))+i).map((c,i,a)=>a.map((v,j)=>j>i?b.repeat(L(n)):v)).map(M(1)).map(c=>c.map(M(2))).map(c=>c.join(b)))


function printTriangle() {  // display array of strings returned by f
    o.innerText = f(
       +Length.value, // number
       Rotate.value[0] // ASCII char
    ).join('\n');
}
```

```html
Length: <input type="text" value="11" id="Length"><br>
Rotate: <input type="text" value="0" id="Rotate"> 0,1,2,3<br>
<button type="button" onclick="printTriangle()">
  OK
</button>
<br>
<pre id="o"></pre>
```

#### Less Golfed

```
(n,x)=>(
    L= x=> (''+x).length,                // strlen(x)
    M= b=> x&b ? (c,i,a)=>a[n-1-i] : c=>c, // reverse or identity map
    Array(n).fill(b=' ')
   .map((c,i)=>b.repeat(L(n)-L(++i))+i)  // a complete line of numbers
   .map((c,i,a)=>a.map((v,j)=>j>i?b.repeat(L(n)):v)) // to 2-d array
                                         // with spaces for blank numbers
   .map(M(1))                            // flip vertically?
   .map(c=>c.map(M(2)))                  // flip horizontally?
   .map(c=>c.join(b))                    // convert lines to strings
)
```

#### Note on orientation.

The second parameter is a character from {'0', '1', '2', '3'} and automatically type converted to a number by the `&` operator. If bit 0 (lsb) of the number is set, lines are flipped vertically. If bit 1 (nlsb) is set, columns are flipped horizontally. Other decimal digit characters can be used with predictable results.

#### Trailing Spaces

Blank entries in the output string have been replaced with spaces, which means lines have trailing spaces in orientations '0' and '1'.

Answer (score 0):

## Lua, 250 bytes

```
function f(w,m)d=""for y=1,w do for x=1,w do d=string.format("%s%"..tostring(w):len().."s ",d,m<2 and(y+x-1<=w and x+y-1 or"")or(m<3 and(x>=y and w-x+y or"")or(m<4 and(y+x-1>=w and w+w-x-y+1 or"")or(y>=x and w-y+x or""))))end;d=d.."\n"end;print(d)end
```

Takes parameters [w]idth and [m]ode using 1,2,3,4 for modes as described in the example.

Answer (score 0):

## 05AB1E (61 bytes)

```
F¹N-LN+¹N-LN+Rõ¸N∍s«N>LN¹<--N>LN¹<--Rõ¸¹<N-∍s«)²èvy¹gyg-ú}ðý,
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f7dBOP10fP20oFXR466Edfo86eosPrfaz8/E7tNNGVxfOAMsCWX66EBWahzYdXlFWeWhnemW67uFdtYc3HN6r8/@/kQGXMQA)